# How do I hide some of Input

Tags: code-request

I have a project with a friend, and we make some work in Mathematica. He is not very good at Mathematica, and I have made some long necessary formulas we need. I would like to show what I've made but only show what's important. Therefore I need to hide some of the input but not all of it.

I have made some research and found this:

```
AutoCollapse[] := (If[$FrontEnd =!= $Failed,SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[], All, GeneratedCell];
 FrontEndTokenExecute["SelectionCloseUnselectedCells"]])
```

The problem with this is it hides all input when used. The example i made below, is it possible in some way, or do I have to break it up into two different inputs?

```
"In(1): 
1+1
3+3
Out(2):
1+1
2+2
3+3"
```

Comment: Can't you simply fold/close/collapse the input cells that you want to hide?

Comment: If you double click an output cell's cell bracket, the input cell grouped together with it will be hidden.  Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Have a look here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2977/131

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/14466/5

Comment: @rm-rf It is that function I need, but it must be as a formula. When I Evaluate Notebook they all gets shown again.

Comment: @JensJensen It's hard to say anything more or provide a programmatic solution unless it is clear how exactly you decide which should be hidden and which shouldn't... Are you familiar with modifying the stylesheet? I might have a way with that.

Comment: @rm-rf Unfortunately I am not familiar at all with modifying the stylesheet at all..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you double click an output cell's cell bracket, the input cell grouped together with it will be hidden.  This functionality may not be obvious, so it'l good to point out it exists.

[image]

This is the folded cell:

[image]

Comment: @Szaboics The problem is, that when you do that, you hide all Input. I only want some parts of input to be hidden. Does it make sense?

Comment: @Jens Did you put your inputs in separate cells?  This method does not hide all input.  It only hides *a single cell*.

Comment: @Szaboics I tried to do so. When I do so, the document becomes very messy because I must use % all the time. It was therefore i needed a formula for the problem - if it is possible to make of course.

Comment: @JensJensen I'm afraid any solution that you're going to get that can hide things within single cells is going to be *more* messy and detrimental to your program's reliability than splitting it into several cells.  Splitting a program is usually good practice and improves readability.  Don't use `%`.  Use variables instead.

Comment: @JensJensen If you really really want to hide things within cells, it's possible using `Interpretation`.  Look it up in the docs.