# Tokenize Mathematica input in a simple way

Tags: boxes, parsing

### Background

Usually, I give detailed descriptions when I have a question which sometimes lead to that users don't write their answers because they maybe think their answer is too simple. Therefore, I chose to just throw the direct question in the room and collect the ideas of all answers.

Although it seems, that we cannot get a simple tokenizer by using functions like `TreeForm`, `MakeBoxes`, `MakeExpression`, ... I want to give some background information now:

What really bothers me is, that we have here on Mathematica.SE a  highlighter for Mathematica code which is far away from perfect, but which does a reasonable job. If I want to include a snippet of code into a LaTeX document on the other hand, I'm totally stuck with a b/w-pdf export from Mathematica or with the Mathematica **5.2** support of the listings package.

Therefore, I hacked a simple parser of the html-output of our google-prettify plugin. This seems to work reasonable and with a little bit adjustment, one could include *styled* Mathematica-code into a LaTeX document. It should be noted, that I don't intent to export formulas or sophisticated styled code. I want to stick with good old ascii-style code which is used in most packages.

Before I used the html-output I was again having a long look at [Leonids formatter](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2810/187) but at its current state it lacks of the same issues since it relies on `MakeBoxes` as well and there are other issues. Leonid pointed out, that he want to reimplement this completely.

On the other hand, we have functions like `SyntaxLength`, `SyntaxQ`, `MakeExpression`, `MakeBoxes` (and their `To` counterparts), all kind of `Forms`, we can keep expressions unevaluated and so on. Therefore, I was asking myself whether we can do the tokenizing much easier with Mathematica that it is possible with the JavaScript from google-prettify.

### Question

Is it possible to implement a reliable tokenizer which takes a valid input-string of Mathematica code and returns a list of tokens without implementing the rules of the Mathematica-language itself?

Although tokens usually don't contain whitespace characters, for the purpose of testing it would be nice, if **all characters stay even in the tokenized version**.

Especially I want

```
input == StringJoin@@Tokenize[input]
```

to return `True`.

Take for instance this function

```
Tokenize[str_String /; SyntaxQ[str]] := 
  With[{expr = MakeExpression[str, StandardForm]},
   Most[Drop[Flatten[MakeBoxes[expr] /. {
        RowBox -> List, SuperscriptBox[a_, b_] :> {a, "^", b}, 
        "\[Rule]" :> "->"}], 2]]
];

Tokenize[
"Plot3D[{x^2+y^2,-x^2-y^2},{x,-2,2},{y,-2,2},RegionFunction->Function[{x,y,z},x^2+y^2<=4]]"
]
(*
 {"Plot3D", "[", "{", "x", "^", "2", "+", "y", "^", "2", ",", 
 "-", "x", "^", "2", "-", "y", "^", "2", "}", ",", "{", "x", 
 ",", "-", "2", ",", "2", "}", ",", "{", "y", ",", "-", "2", 
 ",", "2", "}", ",", "RegionFunction", "->", 
 "Function", "[", "{", "x", ",", "y", ",", "z", "}", ",", "x", 
 "^", "2", "+", "y", "^", "2", "<=", "4", "]", "]"}
*)
```

Although the output looks good here, inside Mathematica we have `\[LessEqual]` instead of `<=` (due to the `StandardForm` I assume). Furthermore, all different kind boxes need to be handled and I'm afraid many more things.

Is there any chance to get this working really correctly?

**Test examples:**

In some of these cases I'm not sure whether my given output is the correct one. E.g. the handling of linebreaks may be system-dependent, `a_` seems to stay together in the box-representation (which would be ok), ...

```
"a\nb" (* {"a","\n","b"} *)
"a_:>a/2<=3" (* {"a_",":>","a","/","2","<=","3"} *)
"1`3+1.00`3" (* I'm not sure how this should be tokenized but my intention should be clear *)
```

Comment: What can you say about the input? What if it has string representation of boxes, how would you want the output?

Comment: @Rojo I updated my question with additional information. You can assume that the code I want to tokenize is simple ascii-code like it is used on our site here.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
tokenize[str_] := Module[{exp,
   nb = CreateDocument[{ExpressionCell@
       InputForm@MakeExpression[str, StandardForm]}, 
     Visible -> False]},
  SelectionMove[nb, Next, Cell];
  exp = Flatten[
    NotebookRead[nb][[1, 1]] /. {RowBox -> List, 
      i_String /; StringMatchQ[i, Whitespace ..] :> Sequence[]}];
  NotebookClose[nb];
  exp[[3 ;;-2]]
  ]
```

Haven't tested this much. Does this give the output you expect?

```
tokenize["Plot3D[{x^2+y^2,-x^2-y^2},{x,-2,2},{y,-2,2},\
RegionFunction->Function[{x,y,z},x^2+y^2<=4]]"]

(*{"Plot3D","[","{","x","^","2","+","y","^","2",",","-","x","^","2","-\
","y","^","2","}",",","{","x",",","-","2",",","2","}",",","{","y",",",\
"-","2",",","2","}",",","RegionFunction","->","Function","[","{","x",\
",","y",",","z","}",",","x","^","2","+","y","^","2","<=","4","]","]",\
"]"}*)
```

**EDIT**

Thanks to @JohnFultz's recent introduction of the following front end undocumented function, this becomes straightforward

```
 fultzTokenize[t_String]:=Cases[MathLink`CallFrontEnd[
   FrontEnd`UndocumentedTestFEParserPacket[t, False]], _String, Infinity]
```

Comment: The idea is good! Don't remove whitespace, because I want `input == StringJoin@@tokenize[input]` to return true; see my update. Your function adds a `]` to the tokens at the end: `tokenize["a+b"]`

Comment: @halirutan, with this approach you could only make input==StringJoin... if you can offer certain guarantees on the input's format. Otherwise, a manual approach, working on the strings, splitting them, is probably the only way I guess. Fixed the extra "]", thanks

Comment: aah! You beat me to stealing the Futz!

Comment: @rm-rf mua ha ha ha

Comment: @Rojo, Shame on you both. You could have at least noticed, that his name is **Fultz** when you are stealing his code ;-)

Comment: Well, if you're going to steal from "the Futz" (my new nickname?), you could at least tighten up the code.  Instead of the `DeleteCases` you have, how about `Cases[#,_String,Infinity]&`?  And...the question was specified (in boldface, even) as wanting whitespace *not* to be stripped.  In which case the second argument to `UndocumentedTestFEParserPacket` should be `False`, not `True`.

Comment: @JohnFultz that's why I misquoted your name, such bad coding shouldn't be attributed to you

Comment: @JohnFultz IMO, Futz is a great nickname. Go with it.

Answer (score 13):

I am a developer at Wolfram Research and I am trying to share some of the work I have been doing with parsing WL code.

I have written a package for parsing WL code and retaining interesting metadata, such as file and line information.

I also expose a tokenization function.

The paclet is available on the public paclet server:

```
In[1]:= PacletUpdate["AST","Site"->"http://pacletserver.wolfram.com","UpdateSites"->True]
Out[1]= Paclet[AST,0.8.1,<>]
```

Load the AST package:

```
Needs["AST`"]
```

The AST package has a function `TokenizeString` that returns a list of tokens when it is given WL input:

```
In[2]:= TokenizeString["Plot3D[{x^2+y^2,-x^2-y^2},{x,-2,2},{y,-2,2},RegionFunction->Function[{x,y,z},x^2+y^2<=4]]"]
Out[2]= {Token[Token`Symbol,Plot3D,<|Source->{{1,1},{1,6}}|>],
Token[Token`Operator`OpenSquare,[,<|Source->{{1,7},{1,7}}|>],
Token[Token`Operator`OpenCurly,{,<|Source->{{1,8},{1,8}}|>],
Token[Token`Symbol,x,<|Source->{{1,9},{1,9}}|>],
Token[Token`Operator`Caret,^,<|Source->{{1,10},{1,10}}|>],
Token[Token`Number,2,<|Source->{{1,11},{1,11}}|>],
Token[Token`Operator`Plus,+,<|Source->{{1,12},{1,12}}|>],
Token[Token`Symbol,y,<|Source->{{1,13},{1,13}}|>],
Token[Token`Operator`Caret,^,<|Source->{{1,14},{1,14}}|>],
Token[Token`Number,2,<|Source->{{1,15},{1,15}}|>],
Token[Token`Operator`Comma,,,<|Source->{{1,16},{1,16}}|>],
Token[Token`Operator`Minus,-,<|Source->{{1,17},{1,17}}|>],
Token[Token`Symbol,x,<|Source->{{1,18},{1,18}}|>],
Token[Token`Operator`Caret,^,<|Source->{{1,19},{1,19}}|>],
Token[Token`Number,2,<|Source->{{1,20},{1,20}}|>],
Token[Token`Operator`Minus,-,<|Source->{{1,21},{1,21}}|>],
Token[Token`Symbol,y,<|Source->{{1,22},{1,22}}|>],
Token[Token`Operator`Caret,^,<|Source->{{1,23},{1,23}}|>],
Token[Token`Number,2,<|Source->{{1,24},{1,24}}|>],
Token[Token`Operator`CloseCurly,},<|Source->{{1,25},{1,25}}|>],
Token[Token`Operator`Comma,,,<|Source->{{1,26},{1,26}}|>],
Token[Token`Operator`OpenCurly,{,<|Source->{{1,27},{1,27}}|>],
Token[Token`Symbol,x,<|Source->{{1,28},{1,28}}|>],
Token[Token`Operator`Comma,,,<|Source->{{1,29},{1,29}}|>],
Token[Token`Operator`Minus,-,<|Source->{{1,30},{1,30}}|>],
Token[Token`Number,2,<|Source->{{1,31},{1,31}}|>],
Token[Token`Operator`Comma,,,<|Source->{{1,32},{1,32}}|>],
Token[Token`Number,2,<|Source->{{1,33},{1,33}}|>],
Token[Token`Operator`CloseCurly,},<|Source->{{1,34},{1,34}}|>],
Token[Token`Operator`Comma,,,<|Source->{{1,35},{1,35}}|>],
Token[Token`Operator`OpenCurly,{,<|Source->{{1,36},{1,36}}|>],
Token[Token`Symbol,y,<|Source->{{1,37},{1,37}}|>],
Token[Token`Operator`Comma,,,<|Source->{{1,38},{1,38}}|>],
Token[Token`Operator`Minus,-,<|Source->{{1,39},{1,39}}|>],
Token[Token`Number,2,<|Source->{{1,40},{1,40}}|>],
Token[Token`Operator`Comma,,,<|Source->{{1,41},{1,41}}|>],
Token[Token`Number,2,<|Source->{{1,42},{1,42}}|>],
Token[Token`Operator`CloseCurly,},<|Source->{{1,43},{1,43}}|>],
Token[Token`Operator`Comma,,,<|Source->{{1,44},{1,44}}|>],
Token[Token`Symbol,RegionFunction,<|Source->{{1,45},{1,58}}|>],
Token[Token`Operator`MinusGreater,->,<|Source->{{1,59},{1,60}}|>],
Token[Token`Symbol,Function,<|Source->{{1,61},{1,68}}|>],
Token[Token`Operator`OpenSquare,[,<|Source->{{1,69},{1,69}}|>],
Token[Token`Operator`OpenCurly,{,<|Source->{{1,70},{1,70}}|>],
Token[Token`Symbol,x,<|Source->{{1,71},{1,71}}|>],
Token[Token`Operator`Comma,,,<|Source->{{1,72},{1,72}}|>],
Token[Token`Symbol,y,<|Source->{{1,73},{1,73}}|>],
Token[Token`Operator`Comma,,,<|Source->{{1,74},{1,74}}|>],
Token[Token`Symbol,z,<|Source->{{1,75},{1,75}}|>],
Token[Token`Operator`CloseCurly,},<|Source->{{1,76},{1,76}}|>],
Token[Token`Operator`Comma,,,<|Source->{{1,77},{1,77}}|>],
Token[Token`Symbol,x,<|Source->{{1,78},{1,78}}|>],
Token[Token`Operator`Caret,^,<|Source->{{1,79},{1,79}}|>],
Token[Token`Number,2,<|Source->{{1,80},{1,80}}|>],
Token[Token`Operator`Plus,+,<|Source->{{1,81},{1,81}}|>],
Token[Token`Symbol,y,<|Source->{{1,82},{1,82}}|>],
Token[Token`Operator`Caret,^,<|Source->{{1,83},{1,83}}|>],
Token[Token`Number,2,<|Source->{{1,84},{1,84}}|>],
Token[Token`Operator`LessEqual,<=,<|Source->{{1,85},{1,86}}|>],
Token[Token`Number,4,<|Source->{{1,87},{1,87}}|>],
Token[Token`Operator`CloseSquare,],<|Source->{{1,88},{1,88}}|>],
Token[Token`Operator`CloseSquare,],<|Source->{{1,89},{1,89}}|>],
Token[Token`EOF,,<|Source->{{2,0},{2,0}}|>]}
```

The AST paclet is under development and the format of the output may change, but hopefully this can help.

Answer (score 4):

This, with a suitable transform function to traverse the tree, would be an adequate tokenizer:

```
TreeForm[Hold[
  Plot3D[{x^2 + y^2, -x^2 - y^2}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
   RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, x^2 + y^2 <= 4]]]]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: No, I don't think the input can be reconstructed from that. Mathematica did already too much work: compare ``TreeForm[1`3]`` and ``TreeForm[1.00`3]``.

Comment: You can of course wrap some `Hold` around the numeric value, but the outcome stays the same.

Comment: @halirutan Good counter example :) Maybe this case, and perhaps others, needs the application of a pre-processor. If I've used it correctly I don't think `tokenize` from rojo's solution distinguishes between the two forms you give in your example either.

Comment: Yes, Rojos `tokenize` lacks from the same problem. I added more information to my question.