# View the FullForm of ^^

Tags: parsing, number-bases

Why am I unable to see the `FullForm` of `^^` (the shorthand notation for `BaseForm`)?

```
FullForm[HoldComplete[16 ^^ 2]]
(* HoldComplete[2] *)

FullForm[ToExpression["HoldComplete[16 ^^ 2]"]]
(* HoldComplete[2] *)

Trace[HoldComplete[16 ^^ 2],TraceInternal->True]
(* {} *)
```

My only clue is from the Possible Issues section on `HoldComplete`:

> HoldComplete affects only evaluation; input transformations are still
>   applied:

Is there a way to see the `FullForm`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, AFAIK there is no way to see the `FullForm` and I think your conclusion is correct. The `^^` is not an operator, it is a form how you can input a number. Effectively, this behavior applies to all [form of numerical input](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/InputSyntax.html#7977).

[image]

For instance this is *unholdable* too

```
HoldComplete[16*^2]
(* HoldComplete[1600] *)
```

### Advanced expanation

To give a more thorough explanation, we have to look at the way an input string is converted into a *Mathematica* expression. My explanation might not be correct in all details, because I have no insight into the internal implementation, but in general, this conversion happens in two steps:

- Lexical scanning of the input string which divides it into tokens
- parsing of the tokens with respect to the syntax of *Mathematica* and the precedence of the operators

To give an example, look at the input string `"BaseForm[33,2]"`. When it is tokenized, we see that it is split into the logical parts: identifiers, operators, braces, ..

```
"BaseForm[33,2]" // fultzTokenize // InputForm

(* {"BaseForm", "[", "33", ",", "2", "]"} *)
```

You find the tokenize implementation [in this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/13095/187). Regarding to the syntax of *Mathematica*, the `[` indicates, that it is function call where `BaseForm` is the head of the function and 33 and 2 are its arguments.

This is reflected in the final parsing tree `Hold[BaseForm[33, 2]] // TreeForm`

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Remember, that to end up as separate node in the parsing tree, the input needs to be split up into several tokens. Let's see what happens, when we tokenize (or *lexical scan*) the special input forms:

```
"16^^2" // fultzTokenize // InputForm

(* {"16^^2"} *)
```

This means, that expression like `16^^2` are not split up because here `^^` is not an operator. Those expressions are recognized directly as number. Btw, is exactly how I have implemented it in the [Mathematica plugin for IDEA](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/24556/187). There, such constructs are seen by the parser as number. And if you look at my [lexical scanner spec](https://github.com/halirutan/Mathematica-IntelliJ-Plugin/blob/develop/src/de/halirutan/mathematica/lexer/Mathematica.flex) in line 47-65 you see, that the regexp for recognizing all kinds of numbers in *Mathematica* is at least a bit complex.

Now, you might finally ask the question, when is this `16^^2` converted into its final form? To the best of my knowledge, this is done silently by the kernel. If we use a LinkSnooper to watch the traffic between Front-End and *Mathematica* Kernel, we see for the evaluation of `Hold[16^^4]`

```
FE ---> K: EnterExpressionPacket[MakeExpression[BoxData[RowBox[{"Hold", "[", "16^^4", "]"}]], StandardForm]]
FE <--- K: OutputNamePacket["Out[8]= "]
FE <--- K: ReturnExpressionPacket[BoxData[RowBox[{"Hold", "[", "4", "]"}], StandardForm]]
```

You see the `16^^2` is sent to the kernel, but back comes, ignoring the `Hold`, the evaluated number.

Comment: Very good explanation. Thank you.