# Why is ^^ff not the same as ^^ToExpression["ff"]?

Tags: syntax, expression-manipulation, parsing

I want to convert a hexadecimal string to a decimal (base 10) number:

```
16^^ff
16^^ToExpression["ff"]
```

The 1st line returns the correct answer of 255, while the 2nd line gives an error.  Why doesn't it work?

Comment: It is not correct to say (or, rather, imply) that the sigil `^^` corresponds to `BaseForm`, although I grant you that this is referenced in the `BaseForm` documentation. It is just another notation for entering numbers, like `1*^10`. These particular notations are processed by the parser, are not interpreted as functions, and require that numeric literals appear both on the left and the right. It doesn't work since `ToExpression["ff"]` is not a numeric literal. You may use e.g. `ToExpression@ToString@StringForm["16^^``", "ff"]` instead.

Comment: Oleksandr, What do the two grave accents mean in this case? I've seen them before to indicate accuracy, as in `Accuracy[1.2``20]`

Comment: @DavidCarraher It is just `StringForm`'s syntax... The second argument to `StringForm` gets inserted where ever there's a double backtick. If you have more than one argument to insert, you can indicate the order with  a number, like \`1\`.

Comment: See here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/39753/4346

Comment: Perhaps you have good reasons to use `ToExpression` but FYI the usual method to interpret a hexadecimal string is with `FromDigits`, e.g. `FromDigits["FF", 16]` gives 255

Comment: It doesn't work because `16^^ff` is interpreted as parse time.  It doesn't go like *input* -> *compound expression* -> *evaluation*. It is directly parsed into an atomic integer.  `16^ff` is just a different way to write the atomic `255`, there's no difference between the two inputs from Mathematica's point of view.  You might have been under the impression that `^^` is an operator that might correspond to some head, so you can join two arbitrary expressions using this operator.  This is not the case.  `^^` is not an operator in Mathematica, it's just part of the syntax for writing numbers ...

Comment: ... the same way as the decimal point is not an operator, just a part of writing numbers.  The same goes for the backtick, double backtick, and `*^`, which can also be used in inputting numbers.

Comment: Seems to me that comments should be converted to answers and rep awarded for this discussion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already stated in the comments the `^^` notation is handled in parsing; observe:

```
HoldComplete[16^^ff] // FullForm
```

> ```
> HoldComplete[255]
> ```

(I intend this to illustrate that this notation is "evaluated" before the main evaluator ever sees it.)

This parsing is really no different from other [numerical notation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/InputSyntax.html#7977) in *Mathematica*, for example `12.345` is directly parsed as a `Real` number, not an expression involving [`Dot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Dot.html).  Likewise `1*^6` is parsed as the `Integer` one million, with no relation to `Times` or `Power`.

As Simon Woods recommended, for programmatic input of hexadecimals use [`FromDigits`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FromDigits.html):

```
FromDigits["ff", 16]
```

> ```
> 255
> ```