# Extract all elements of an expression in order into a list

Tags: list-manipulation, expression-manipulation

I have and expression `a + b + c - d` and I would like to generate a list of `{a, +, b, +, c, -, d}`. I have tried `Head`, `FullForm` which is close but not quite what I am looking for. I have also tried `Part` and `Extract` with no luck.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: It's not clear exactly what output you want.  This is close: `First@ToBoxes[a + b + c - d, StandardForm]`, but all parts are strings.  Is that what you want?

Comment: I don't fully understand your question.  `+` is not part of that expression.  What `FullForm` shows you corresponds directly to how the expression is stored internally.  It might help if you explained your motivation behind trying to do this.

Comment: If you don't want strings then `a + b + c - d /. Plus -> List` gives `{a, b, c, -d}`

Comment: It might help if you explain why you want to do this as well.

Comment: The `a + b + c - d` that you see in an input cell in your notebook is not really a _Mathematica_ expression. It is just a human-friendly input form, syntactic sugar so to speak. What `FullForm` shows you is the ***real*** expression.  So you can't correctly say "I have an expression `a + b + c - d`", and making such an assertion makes your question ill-posed. We really need you to edit your question and express your issue with more contextual detail.

Comment: I'm afraid, that you can't really do what you ask for explicitly. One of the reasons for that is that `+` and `-` are `Infix` operators. They cannot be elements. Perhaps it would suffice to have `{a, Plus, b, Plus, c, Subtract, d}`?

Answer (score 3):

I'm certain that this will not be the solution to whatever real *problem* there is behind your question, but incidentally, you could use this function from a [former answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13094/187)

```
fultzTokenize[t_String] := 
 Cases[MathLink`CallFrontEnd[
   FrontEnd`UndocumentedTestFEParserPacket[t, False]], _String, 
  Infinity]

fultzTokenize["a+b+c-c"]
```

it gives you

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

but be aware that output and input are strings.

Comment: I can not resist and give you a fultzPoint, +1.