# Fixing links to symbol pages with special characters made with Workbench

Tags: documentation, workbench

I am writing documentation for a package using Workbench v2.0 and Mathematica v9.0.1, and certain Symbols defined by my package have special (Greek) characters characters e.g. `Unitλ`.

As I am building the documentation, I am running into problems when trying to get links to these Symbol pages.
Firstly, Workbench fails to properly recognize the symbol name from the `.m` file, and recommends that I create two distinct symbols--one for `Unit` and another for `\[Lambda]`:

[image]

Neither is acceptable, so I created a Symbol Page called "Unit[Lambda]".  In the Guide page I use the **B** button in the Documentation Tools palette to browse for the specific symbol page it is supposed to link to.

---

**Issue 1:** After Building the documentation, and Previewing the guide page, the link is simply not working.  I have checked the URI and they match.

[image]

**Solution:**  Apparently, this is solved by modifying the file `docbuild.xml` according to Simon Rochester's answer to the question: [Creating cross-version compatible documentation with Workbench](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/28316/creating-cross-version-compatible-documentation-with-workbench).

---

**Issue 2:** Furthermore, for these symbols with special characters, upon calling the usage via `? Unit\[Lambda]`, I am not getting the relevant `>>` link to the documentation center:

[image]

Is there a solution the problem of the missing `>>` link in the usage box?  I am basically looking for almost *any* solution: playing around with files after "Build"ing documentation is acceptable, as long as after it is deployed to other machines, everything works as normal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Issue 1

If you want your documentation notebook to work, without problems, in different operating systems, you should avoid special characters in file names. I'd call your documentation notebook `UnitLambda.nb`

Last element of URI should match documentation notebook file name (without `.nb`). In specific case from question URI should be `RapidSolver/ref/UnitLambda`.

Make sure that all links in source documentation notebooks point to correct URI.

You can change URI cell from `UnitLambda.nb` and all links from other source notebooks using Eclipse search/replace functionality.

#### Issue 2

Add `Resources` to `"Documentation"` `Extensions` of your `Paclet`, that will point to appropriate documentation notebook:

```
Paclet[
    (*...,*)
    Extensions -> 
        {
            {"Documentation",
                (*...,*)
                Resources -> {
                    {
                        "ReferencePages/Symbols/Unit\[Lambda]",
                        "ReferencePages/Symbols/UnitLambda.nb"
                    }
                }
            }, 
            (*...*)
        }
]
```

This method works in *Mathematica* version 9.0 and above (at time of writing tested up to version 11.0), but does not work in version 8 and earlier. If support for version 8 is needed, "hacky" solution, presented below, could be used.

#### Issue 2 (Old hacky version)

Add a small hack to your package:

```
Unprotect[Documentation`CreateMessageLink];
Documentation`CreateMessageLink["RapidSolver`", "Unit\[Lambda]", "usage", "English"] = 
    Documentation`CreateMessageLink["RapidSolver`", "UnitLambda", "usage", "English"]
Protect[Documentation`CreateMessageLink];
```

`CreateMessageLink` is a function used by `Information` to, as its name suggests, create a link at the and of a message. This hack will tell Mathematica that, when documentation page of `` RapidSolver`Unit\[Lambda] `` symbol is needed, it should really search for a page with URI ending with `UnitLambda`.

Your package will change definition of symbol from another package, which in general is a bad idea, but in this case redefinition affects only situations in which `CreateMessageLink` is called with context of your package as first argument, so it should be harmless.

You can put this code anywhere inside package file. Only relevant thing is that it gets executed when package is loaded.

Tested on Linux with *Mathematica* versions 8.0.0, 9.0.1 and 10.0.0.

Comment: This worked perfectly on my machine (Mac OSX, Mathematica v9.0.1).  But for some reason, the hack doesn't work another test machine which runs Windows Server.  I have already made sure none of my file names contain special characters.  I will need to test on other machines and see if I can pin-point the problem...

Comment: @QuantumDot Currently I don't have access to MMA on Windows, so I'm not sure I can help with this. But just to clarify the problem: Which MMA version is on your Windows Server? What precisely doesn't work? Link in usage message doesn't show up? Do links from other pages pointing to `Unitλ` page work? Can you access `Unitλ` page by pressing `F1` with cursor on `Unitλ` symbol?

Comment: I have tried MMA v9.0.1 and v10.0.1 on Windows Server.  Link in usage message of `Unitλ` doesn't show up.  But links within other symbol/guide pages pointing to `Unitλ` all work fine (corrected by Issue1).  Pressing `F1` has never gone directly to the relevant page (neither on MacOS or Windows) for *any* of my symbols; it has always gone to the Search results page which displays the relevant page as one of the top hits.  Interestingly, even after implementing your hack, the link in the *Search* page pointing to `Unitλ` does not work (goes to blank page) on both my Mac and Windows machine.

Comment: @QuantumDot Behavior I'm getting on Linux: in v10 pressing `F1` leads directly to symbol page (with additional link on top: `Search for all pages containing Unitλ`) in v8 and v9 `F1` leads to search results page with link to symbol page as first result, clicking on it correctly leads to `Unitλ` symbol page.

Comment: @QuantumDot Links from other documentation pages have URIs taken from `ButtonData` option of `ButtonBox`es present in source notebooks of those pages. Link on search result page is different, its URI is taken from URI cell from "Categorization" section of `Unitλ` symbol source notebook, so make sure it's correct. Problem with this cell might be "invisible" i.e. extra space or some formatting box invisible in the notebook. To be absolutely sure it's correct use `Cell > Show Expression` and check that first element of cell expression is exactly `"RapidSolver/ref/UnitLambda"` string.

Comment: I decided to delete the Symbol page `UnitLambda` and make it again from scratch, this time naming it correctly right from the start.  This solved the problem on MacOS and the link works from search pages, too.  I also finally got my hands on a Linux machine with Mathematica 8.0.4, 9.0.1 and 10.0.1.  The behavior is exactly as you describe in your comments, and all the links are working as intended.  Many thanks for your help!  [For some reason the problem still persists on Windows but I can live with that]

Comment: @QuantumDot I'm glad I could help.

Comment: How'd you find the paclet-based method? Was it just testing or are there references out there?

Comment: Thanks for the edit.  It turns out adding "Resources" to Extensions causes version 8.0 to not find any of the pages.

Comment: @QuantumDot you can try branching your `Paclet` expression with an `If[$VersionNumber` and then just maintain a `"WolframVersion"->"9+"` and `"8+"` paclet info. I checked and the `If` does seem to be respected. Ah. But the `PackPaclet` fails. Nevermind.

Comment: @b3m2a1 After [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/95790/how-to-create-a-documentation-page-for-a-given-message-issued-by-a-user-defined/95926#comment412668_95926), I searched for files containing `Messages/FullSimplify/time` in *Mathematica* directory and found `PacletDB.m` file containing this "`Resources` rewrites".

Comment: @QuantumDot Thanks for pointing this out. Unfortunately I don't know how to make `Resources` work in version 8.