# How to create a documentation page for a given message issued by a (user-defined) function?

Tags: documentation, workbench

I want to create properly linked documentation pages dedicated to specific messages issued by my own functions inside a package, similar to those for messages of built-in functions like `Integrate` below:

`Integrate[x,2]`

> Integrate::ilim :  Invalid integration variable or limit(s) in 2. >>

Here, the ">>" links not to the `Integrate` help page, but to [a page](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/message/Integrate/ilim.html) specific to the message `Integrate::ilim`:

[image]

How do I create such a page in Workbench? And how should one properly link the Messages to their appropriate pages?

Comment: Could you take a look at my comment below the accepted answer?  I'm using the new Eclipse plugin ("Workbench plugin version 10.1" according the about box).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Say you're developing `` MyPackage` `` and want to create page for `MySymbol::myMessage`. Assuming you already have created standard Application project, with documentation support, perform following steps.

1. Inside `MyProject/MyPackage/Documentation/English/ReferencePages` create `Messages` directory with `MySymbol` sub-directory.
2. Open PacletInfo editor (double click on `PacletInfo.m` file).
   Choose `Documentation` tab, there should be `ExtraReferences/Messages` position select it and click on `Add Page`. Type in `myMessage` in window that should appear and click OK. `MyProject/MyPackage/Documentation/English/ReferencePages/Messages/myMessage.nb` file should be created.
3. Manually move above file to `MySymbol` sub-directory. Its path should now be:

   ```
   MyProject/MyPackage/Documentation/English/ReferencePages/Messages/MySymbol/myMessage.nb
   ```
4. Open `myMessage.nb` file.
   In `Categorization` section, change `Entity Type` to `Message` and `URI` to `MyPackage/ref/message/MySymbol/myMessage`.

   Manually tweak contents as you like. E.g. change title from `myMessage` to `MySymbol::myMessage`, remove usage cells etc.
5. Make sure `PacletInfo.m` has [proper "Documentation" and "Kernel" `Extensions`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/28349/14303).

After standard building and deploying everything should work automatically.

Assuming that in your package there is something like:

```
MySymbol::myMessage = "This is my message."
```

then printing `MySymbol::myMessage` should give message text together with proper documentation link:

```
Needs["MyPackage`"]

Message[MySymbol::myMessage]
(* MySymbol::myMessage: This is my message. >> *)
```

Comment: I did step 1 but in step 2 I do not see `ExtraReferences/Messages`.  I have three categories: `Symbols`, `Guides`, `Tutorials`.  Did I misunderstand something?

Comment: OK, I figured it out: it seems to be necessary to run a documentation build after creating the folder in step 1.  Only then will `ExtraReferences/Messages` appear.

Comment: @Szabolcs I just tested it on fresh project. I had `PacletInfo.m` open on `Documentation` tab while manually creating directories, and `ExtraReferences/Messages` popped up instantly after creating `Messages` directory. I'm using Eclipse Mars.2 (4.5.2) with Wolfram Workbench 10.1.757 on Linux. Maybe it's some refreshing issue in specific Eclipse version. Maybe something like right-click on project, in Navigator, and choosing `Refresh`, or closing/reopening `PacletInfo.m` would be enough?

Comment: @Szabolcs In fact, clicking on `Add Page` with `ExtraReferences/Messages` selected creates a "Symbol" documentation page, so it has same effect as clicking on `Add Page` with `Symbols` selected, you'll just need move notebook file from different directory.

Comment: Do you know how to make messages for several symbols point to the same page?  Like how error messages `FullSimplify::time` and `Simplify::time` work?

Comment: @QuantumDot in `<Path/To/Mathematica>/Documentation/English/PacletDB.m` you can find `Paclet[..., "Extensions"->{{"Documentation", ..., "Resources"->{
    {"ReferencePages/Messages/FullSimplify/time", "System/ReferencePages/Messages/FullSimplify/time.nb"},
    {"ReferencePages/Messages/Simplify/time", "System/ReferencePages/Messages/FullSimplify/time.nb"}
   }}}]`. I didn't test it, but maybe adding similar `"Resources"` to `"Documentation"` `"Extensions"`, of your paclet, will do.

Comment: Yes it worked!  Do you believe modifying `PacletInfo.m` would also work for [this problem](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/66907/fixing-links-to-symbol-pages-with-special-characters-made-with-workbench) I asked a long while back?

Comment: @QuantumDot Yes, it seems to work also for that problem. I've added it to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Nice question!
I do not have MMA with me now, but I think you could do as follows:
1- Create a doc page titled with the name of the message.
2 create a message text which includes a link to the above mentioned page.

If you have any doubts as to how to make the link, examine the inner "guts" of the Integrate::illim cell, using ctrl-shift-E and try to reproduce the same pattern in your own message text.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you need it's an example.
You need to style the output cell!

```
CellPrint[
 Cell["abc", 18 , Background -> LightYellow, 
  CellFrame -> {{2, 0}, {0, 0}}, CellFrameColor -> Yellow]]
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood me. I am looking to create a documentation file with Workbench, and have messages link to the appropriate page.  Formatting a cell is not what I need.

Comment: See also [How do I add my own help pages to the in-built Wolfram documentation?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/86137/how-do-i-add-my-own-help-pages-to-the-in-built-wolfram-documentation) and [Integrating notebooks to Mathematica's documentation center](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6574710/integrating-notebooks-to-mathematicas-documentation-center) as well [How to write documentation in Wolfram Style?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/47602/how-to-write-documentation-in-wolfram-style)