# What do the contents of Index and SpellIndex folders do in applications?

Tags: documentation, workbench

In the built documentation folder of an application with Wolfram Workbench, there are two folders `/Documentation/English/Index` and `/Documentation/English/SpellIndex` which both contain three files: `_g.cfs`, `segments_z` and `segments.gen`.

For what purpose are these files included?  Can they be modified an any meaningful way?  What if they are removed?

Applications seem to continue to work like normal when the files are edited.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6574919/695132) seems to contain info on how to generate these. If you can separate that information out from that long post and summarize it in a self-answer, that would be quite useful. You can also try to spelunk the functions that create them.

Comment: Unrelated: You create packages, so you may be interested in [the IntelliJ plugin](http://wlplugin.halirutan.de/) and [giving feedback on how to develop it](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8636/intellijidea-plugin-for-mathematica).

Comment: @Szabolcs I checked it out at one point, but thought that it wouldn't work for me since I write packages that extensively use greek characters `α`, `β`, `γ`.   I need the *Mathematica* front-end `.m` editor to render these correctly since I don't think I would like to use `\[Alpha]`, `\[Beta]`, `\[Gamma]` ... .  I figured that it would be far too much effort to add this as a new feature, so I didn't bother requesting it.

Comment: I thought this created search indexes, to be used when searching the docs. Greek letters in formulas should make no difference.  Do you write in ελληνικά?

Comment: No, what I mean is that some of my package function names are `Kramersβ` and `RegularizedRiemannζ`, and I have algebraic symbols like `α`, `β`, `γ`.  I assumed they would be rendered in the plugin like `Kramers\[Beta]`, *etc*, (just like in Workbench), so it wouldn't work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe these files are created by the Workbench (using the DocumentationSearch package) and contain search indices for a package's documentation.

I think `Index` is for the search indices, and `SpellIndex` for the "did you mean" feature:

[image]

---

There is information on creating these indices manually in the following QAs:

- [Creating cross-version compatible documentation with Workbench](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/28316/12)
- [How to create search indices for custom documentation pages?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/155932/12)

---

[Since M11.2, a different system is used](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/155717/12) which creates a directory called `TextSearchIndex`.