# Can Save[] produce a .nb file instead of a text file?

Tags: export, notebooks, data-format, save

(I use *Mathematica* 9.0.1 on OS X 10.10.2.)

Suppose I have a notebook in which I make some definitions and assignments.

```
a = 108
b[x_] := 4x + 8
c = Interpolation[{15, 16, 23, 42}]
```

Then it is straightforward to save these definitions to a text file:

```
Save["filename.txt", {a, b, c}]
```

produces a text file `filename.txt` containing

> a = 4
>
> b[x_] := 8*x
>
> c = InterpolatingFunction[{{1, 4}}, {4, 3, 0, {4}, {4}, 0, 0, 0, 0,
>             Automatic}, {{1, 2, 3, 4}}, {{15}, {16}, {23}, {42}}, {Automatic}]

But is there a way to produce exactly the above content, **not in a text file, but in an ".nb" file?**

(Note that the obvious first guess, just changing the extension of the filename I specify in the `Save` command from ".txt" to ".nb", does not seem to work. Mathematica still treats the file as a text file, rather than a notebook file, it just now has a deceptive file extension.)

Answer (score 3):

```
a = 108
b::usage = "test usage msg"
b[x_] := 4 x + 8
c = Interpolation[{15, 16, 23, 42}]
```

As pointed by OP, the direct usage of `FullDefinition` produces boxes that are not realy useful. I don't know how to convert them easily without this tiny undocumented function [[1]](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/29913/5478), [[2]](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/13371/5478):

```
Save["test.m", {a, b, c}]

CreateDocument @ Cell[#, "Input"] &@
 First @ FrontEndExecute @ 
   UndocumentedTestFEParserPacket[Import["test.m", "Text"], False]
```

[image]

---

Old answer, not so handy, in edit history.

Comment: Try evaluating the cell, saving and closing the file, and reopening it.

Comment: @thecommexokid again good point, sorry for not being focused enough :) is my edit ok? :)

Comment: Yes, it is, thanks. It's really weird to me that `Save["test.m"]` produces a proper `.m` file, but `Save["test.nb"]` just produces a text file with a misleading `.nb` extension.

Comment: By the way, not sure why you deleted all your previous comments! I don't think that was really necessary...

Comment: @thecommexokid mods don't linke too long discussions in comments :) moreover I thought it is not really useful fo future visitors.

Comment: `FrontEndObject::notavail: A front end is not available; certain operations require a front end.`

Comment: @thecommexokid Makes sense. How are you calling this?

Comment: Without a front end, alas. I am running a script on a remote server.

Comment: @thecommexokid Try to wrap it with `UsingFrontEnd`. I will be afk for 1h now.