# How can I use L.Shifrin s code formatter package better

Tags: functions, evaluation

---

in the document of HoldAllComplete, it says: `Evaluate` cannot be used to override `HoldAllComplete.`.

for example, when I'm trying L.Shifrin's [package](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2809/programmatic-formatting-for-mathematica-code-possible),

CodeFormatterMakeBoxes has the `HoldAllComplete` Attribute, how can I use it for `CellExpression`?

For example, I want to make `CodeFormatterMakeBoxes[f@CellPrint@(
 cells[1]=Cell[BoxData[
   RowBox[{"Plot", "[", 
     RowBox[{"x", ",", 
       RowBox[{"{", RowBox[{"x", ",", "0", ",", "10"}], "}"}]}], 
     "]"}]], "Input"]])` generate the output like `CodeFormatter[MakeBoxes[Plot[x,{x,0,10}]]]=RowBox[{"Plot", "[", 
  RowBox[{"x", ",", 
    RowBox[{"{", RowBox[{"x", ",", "0", ",", "10"}], "}"}]}], "]"}]`?

CodeFormatterMakeBoxes // Definition

```
(*
    Attributes[CodeFormatterMakeBoxes]={HoldAllComplete} CodeFormatterMakeBoxes[CodeFormatter`
Private`args__]:=CodeFormatter`Private`makeBoxes[CodeFormatter`Private`args]
*)
```

A complex usage version :

```
First[FrontEndExecute[FrontEnd`ExportPacket[Cell[BoxData@FullCodeFormat@CodeFormatterMakeBoxes[#]&@ToExpression[First[FrontEndExecute[FrontEnd`ExportPacket[cellExpression,"InputText"]]],StandardForm,Hold],"Input"],"InputText"]]]
```

bad thing is `x^2` becomes `Power[x,2]`, and actually I want to put `FullCodeFormat` here:

```
First[FrontEndExecute[FrontEnd`ExportPacket[FullCodeFormat@cellExpression,"InputText"]]
```

Comment: not sure what is the question, something like this: `f[#]&@MakeBoxes[expr]` fits your needs?

Comment: @Kuba hi, see my update