# How to do this type of percentual stacked plot in Mathematica?

Tags: plotting

I have data of letter occurrences in different positions. I want to plot the frequency of each letter in each position.

The type of plot I have in mind is as follows:

[image: sample image]

How can I do this in Mathematica?

Comment: What have you tried? Take a look at the documentation for `BarChart`: there is a `ChartLayout` called "Stacked"... Have you searched this site? Quite a few results pop up for "stacked barchart".

Comment: I think both `BarChart` and `Histogram` support this type of data visualization.

Comment: `Table[BarChart[RandomReal[1, {5, 5}], 
  ChartLayout -> l], {l, {"Stacked", "Percentile"}}]`

Comment: @belisarius Thanks. I did not find the option `"Percentile"` (which is what I want) in the Options section of the documentation, under `ChartLayout`, where I would expect to find it. Can you post an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @MarcoB `Stacked` is not what I want. `Percentile` is more like it, but that's not in the documentation.

Comment: @becko It certainly is. Look towards the bottom of the "Details and Options" section of the `BarChart` documentation. It says: *Possible settings for ChartLayout include "Grouped", "Stacked", "Stepped", and "Percentile"*.

Comment: @MarcoB Sorry I missed that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This does what you want:

```
BarChart[RandomReal[1, {5, 5}], ChartLayout -> "Percentile"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 11):

A bit more detail than in belisarius' answer:

```
BarChart[RandomReal[1, {21, 26}], 
 ChartLayout -> "Percentile", 
 ChartLegends -> RandomSample[CharacterRange["A", "Z"], 26], 
 ChartLabels -> {Rotate[#, 90 Degree] & /@ Range[105, 125], None}, 
 ChartStyle -> ColorData[54], 
 AxesLabel -> {Placed[
    Text[Style["aa position", 14, Bold, 
      FontFamily -> Helvetica]], {13, -12}], 
    Text[Style["Frequency", 14, Bold, FontFamily -> Helvetica]]}, 
 PlotLabel -> Text[Style["Young", 16, Bold, FontFamily -> Helvetica]],
 ImageSize -> 700]
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

I've been reading a few books on visualisation theory recently and wanted to add my two English pennies - the ordering of data in stacked bar charts matters. Particularly the variance of the lower elements.

To demonstrate this, here's a function that re-orders data according to the `Variance` or `Mean` of the datasets (EDIT: Changed to `Transpose` on Belisarius' recommendation and used https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2810/1952 for code formatting):

```
sortedStackedBarChart[data_List, "Sorting" -> method_, 
  "StackLayout" -> stacking_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] :=
With[{orderedData = Switch[method,
     "Variance",
     data[[All, Ordering[Variance /@ Transpose[data]]]],
     "Mean",
     data[[All, Reverse[Ordering[Mean /@ Transpose[data]]]]]
     ]},
  BarChart[orderedData, ChartLayout -> stacking, 
   FilterRules[{opts}, Options[BarChart]]]]
```

Generate some data, of course I've selected some of my datasets to have lower variances than others:

```
SeedRandom[1111987]; allRandomData = 
 Table[{RandomReal[{1.9, 2.1}], RandomReal[{0.5, 1}], 
   RandomReal[{0.2, 6}], RandomReal[{0.2, 4}], 
   RandomReal[{4, 5}]}, {10}];
```

Comparing the "Mean" stack ordering and "Variance" stack ordering, it's easier to understand the relative differences between each stack with `Variance` ordering:

```
Grid[{{sortedStackedBarChart[allRandomData, "Sorting" -> "Mean", 
    "StackLayout" -> "Percentile", ImageSize -> 300], 
   sortedStackedBarChart[allRandomData, "Sorting" -> "Mean", 
    "StackLayout" -> "Stacked", ImageSize -> 300]}}]
```

[image]

```
Grid[{{sortedStackedBarChart[allRandomData, "Sorting" -> "Variance", 
    "StackLayout" -> "Percentile", ImageSize -> 300], 
   sortedStackedBarChart[allRandomData, "Sorting" -> "Variance", 
    "StackLayout" -> "Stacked", ImageSize -> 300]}}]
```

[image]

Comment: really impressive +1

Comment: Instead of `Table[Variance[data[[All, i]]], {i, dims[[2]]}]` you can use `Variance /@ Transpose@data`. The same with `Mean`

Comment: @belisarius eurgh, how embarrassing. Thanks for suggestion, allows the removal of the `Module[{..},With[...]]` mess. Cheers

Comment: Glad to help :)