# Code formatting

Tags: programming, notebooks, formatting

This question is a follow up from [Formatting notebook files](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/127143/formatting-notebook-files)

In [Programmatic formatting for Mathematica code - possible?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2809/programmatic-formatting-for-mathematica-code-possible) masterxilo proposed to use `` <<GeneralUtilities` `` then `` GeneralUtilities`PrintDefinitions@f `` whereby `f` is some mathematica code to get a pretty-printed, formatted version of `??f`.

Leonid Shifrin wrote a very nice software which is aimed to format mathematica code: https://github.com/lshifr/CodeFormatter

Concerning `GeneralUtilities` Leonid Shifrin wrote to masterxilo:

"I have to admit that the formatter implemented in `GeneralUtilities` impressed me a lot ...".

I used Leonid Shifrins code as well tried to use `GeneralUtilities` as masterxilo proposed with the following one-liner:

```
Do[x = i; Do[y = j; Do[z = k;, {k, 1, 3}];, {j, 1, 3}];, {i, 1, 3}]
```

Leonid Shifrins code gives nearly what I expect:

```
Import["https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lshifr/CodeFormatter/master/\
CodeFormatter.m"]

    Needs["CodeFormatter`"]

    prn = CellPrint[Cell[BoxData[#], "Input"]] &; prn@
     FullCodeFormat@
      CodeFormatterMakeBoxes@
       Do[x = i; Do[y = j; Do[z = k;, {k, 1, 3}];, {j, 1, 3}];, {i, 1, 3}]
```

Result:
[image]

Why does the `Null` appears?

masterxilos proposal opens up a new notebook with the information: `Attributes[Null] := {Protected};`:

```
<< GeneralUtilities` 

GeneralUtilities`PrintDefinitions@
 Do[x = i; Do[y = j; Do[z = k;, {k, 1, 3}];, {j, 1, 3}];, {i, 1, 3}]
```

[image]

What do I wrong?

Comment: For the last part: Try using `f[] := Do[x = i; Do[y = j; Do[z = k;, {k, 1, 3}];, {j, 1, 3}];, {i, 1, 3}]` with `PrintDefinitionsLocal[f]`.

Comment: @Karsten 7: This is great, I tried it with a relatively long code and the result is nearly perfect. I wonder if there are possibilities to make some adjustments in `PrintDefinitionsLocal`.

Comment: Based on `PrintDefinitionsLocal@PrintDefinitionsLocal`, there are no options settings to do adjustments. However, you can inspect it a little deeper and figure out that, e.g.,  ``Block[{GeneralUtilities`Debugging`PackagePrivate`$PrintDefinitionsBackground =
    Orange},
 PrintDefinitionsLocal[f]]`` will produce an orange background for the printed cells.

Comment: When I use `?GeneralUtilities``  `*` I do not see `Debugging` listed. How did you find it?

Comment: By clicking through the definitions. [This answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/78898/18476) contains a short description of `PrintDefinitions`.

Comment: Evaluating ``?GeneralUtilities`*`*`` also reveals that parameter.