# What is contained in a GeneralUtilities package?

Tags: packages

In [Programmatic formatting for Mathematica code - possible?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2809/programmatic-formatting-for-mathematica-code-possible) masterxilo proposed to use `` <<GeneralUtilities` `` then `` GeneralUtilities`PrintDefinitions@f `` whereby `f` is some mathematica code to get a pretty-printed, formatted version of `??f`.

How can I find out what is contained in the `GeneralUtilities` package?

Comment: These are internal functions which are not supported and most are not documented.  So you are on your own to figure out what they do, and expect things to break.  Use ``?GeneralUtilities`*`` to find what symbols exist in that context, as with any other package/context.

Comment: @Szabolcs This is a perfect answer, so why, pray tell me, why not thee put it as such?

Comment: The content of the `GeneralUtilities` package is version dependent. E.g., `AccurateTiming` (a precursor of [`RepeatedTiming`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RepeatedTiming.html)) no longer exists.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can query the context of `` GeneralUtilities` `` or any other context using

```
?GeneralUtilities`*
```

Reference: [`Information`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Information.html).

Keep in mind that this context/package contains internal functions, most of which are completely undocumented and none of which are supported.  You are on your own to figure out what these functions do, and do expect things to break.

Answer (score 4):

I just realized that we can print all symbols in `GeneralUtilities` that have a documentation string defined:

```
documentationStrings = 
  Quiet@With[{names = 
      DeleteCases[Names["GeneralUtilities`*"], "Buzz"]},
    Cases[
     MessageName[#, "usage"] & /@
      Symbol /@ 
       names[[;; 
          First@FirstPosition[names, _?(StringContainsQ["$"]), 
             Heads -> False] - 1]],
     _?StringQ
     ]];
Length@documentationStrings (* 180 *)
StringRiffle[documentationStrings, "\n\n"]
```

For 13.2, it prints 180 usage strings, starting with

[image]

See [here](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2792043?p_p_auth=OzvV2bqL) for a full list.