# Indentation is lost in Mathematica packages

Tags: packages

This might be very trivial to fix (in that case I'll just delete the question), but why when I save a Mathematica notebook as package, the indentation is completely lost and when I edit the package there's also no automatic indentation. What am I missing?

EDIT: Ah, I found this: [Editing Wolfram Language Packages and Scripts](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/132806/editing-wolfram-language-packages-and-scripts). So my question is duplicate. I shall delete it.

Comment: Alternatively, we could mark this as a duplicate to the thread you found, as your question title is quite informative and might help people find the relevant content faster...

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/208314/280