# How to set the NDSolve method to LSODA

Tags: numerical-integration, differential-equations, options

- I notice that off all the `Method` options available for `NDSolve[...]`, `LSODA` is invoked quite automatically for stiff equations when `Method -> Automatic`. Is there a way to set the `Method -> LSODA`? I ask because as `LSODA` switches between Adams' and Gear's method, it should have sub-options to it that I could set (like order etc.)?
- Under `tutorial/NDSolveStiffnessSwitching` I encountered `` Needs["DifferentialEquations`NDSolveProblems"] ``. What other example problems are available and where can I find documentation on them?

---

Edit (03/24/2011):

In light of comments made to this post, I'd also refer readers to [page 409 of "The Mathematica Guidebook for Numerics"](http://books.google.com/books?hl=en&id=xW5__5ga2IsC&pg=PA409).  Springer has this book online and can be found [here](http://www.springer.com/mathematics/computational+science+&+engineering/book/978-0-387-95011-2).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you load the package using Needs as shown in the Tutorial and then evaluate `$NDSolveProblems` you will list a list of names of all the problems included in the package.

I think I can now also answer the first part of the question. The method has to be called as

```
NDSolve`LSODA
```

rather than `LSODA` (for some reason it is in the `` NDSolve` `` context, which suggests that it is not intended for "ordinary users"). To see its options, just evaluate

```
?NDSolve`LSODA
```

The whole issue of these "hidden contexts" in Mathematica could be the topic of an interesting discussion ;-)

Comment: ?NDSolve`LSODA gives me: Options[NDSolve`LSODA]={LinearSolveMethod->Automatic,MaxDifferenceOrder->12} This is rather useful. However, what does NDSolve`LSODA do? Did it load the LSODA method for use?

Comment: It is itself the name of a method for NDSolve, that is, you use it by evaluating NDSolve[eqn,Method->NDSolve`LSODA]. Whether it will do any good depends of course on eqn.

Comment: Perhaps it's worth mentioning that the symbol ``NDSolve`LSODA`` does not get loaded (and thus cannot be queried) until `NDSolve[]` is used at least once.

Comment: A bit of [spelunking](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1742/12) shows that ``NDSolve`LSODA`` is defined like this:  http://pastebin.com/0nayVBHP   This confirm what @Andrzej said that it is just a method identifier.  You can learn about how methods work [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NDSolvePlugIns.html) (I didn't have time to read this, but it seems like a relevant resource).

Comment: @Szabolcs According to "The mathematica guidebook of numerics" (whose link I've included in the post now) says that <code>LSODA</code> can be loaded.. I am trying to figure out how and what the options are and how to set them. (Thanks to me being a beginner!)

Comment: More precisely: it can be used as NDSolve`LSODA even the first time but once NDSolve is used, you can call it just LSODA.

Comment: @AndrzejKozlowski Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 5):

Does `NDSolve[eqn, opts, Method->LSODA]` not work? It should, according to [this](http://www.wolfram.com/learningcenter/tutorialcollection/AdvancedNumericalDifferentialEquationSolvingInMathematica/AdvancedNumericalDifferentialEquationSolvingInMathematica.pdf).

The problems seem to be at

```
FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory, "AddOns", "ExtraPackages", 
  "DifferentialEquations", "NDSolveProblems.m"}]
```

Comment: I appreciate the link to the pdf. Thanks!

Comment: @acl the linked file does not exist anymore... could you update it, please?