# Setting the DifferenceOrder Option

Tags: syntax, options, differential-equations, numerical-integration

I've been playing around with `Method` in `NDSolve[...]` and can't quite seem to figure out how to force `NDSolve` to use a certain difference order with a certain method.

For instance, I am trying to validate my work against results of solving an ODE with the Backward Euler method which essentially is BDF of order 1.

Now, Mathematica does have the BDF method for solving stiff equations but when I set the following:

`Method->{"BDF", "DifferenceOrder"->1}`

I get the following error:

> NDSolve::moptx: Method option DifferenceOrder in
>   {NDSolve`BDF,{DifferenceOrder->Automatic}} is not one of
>   {ImplicitSolver,MaxDifferenceOrder,VariableStepCoefficients}. >>
>
> NDSolve::initf: The initialization of the method NDSolve`BDF failed. >>

But when I run `NDSolve` with just `Method->{"BDF"}`, lo and behold, I get my solution.

Just to make sure that `BDF` does take `DifferenceOrder` options, I checked with

`` Options[NDSolve`BDF] `` as prompted in a [previous question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3374/204).

Is this not how I should set the order for BDF? What am I missing?

#### EDIT 1:

I realized I should be using the IDA method as that apparently uses the BDF method to solve DAEs. Still trying to figure out how I might go about doing this though.

#### EDIT 2:

I think I might have figured it out. This is what I changed in `Method`

`Method -> {"IDA", "ImplicitSolver" -> "Newton", "MaxDifferenceOrder" -> 5},`

From IDA's documentation provided in [Advanced Numerical Differential Equation Solving in Mathematica](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NDSolveOverview.html), I think with `IDA` with `Newton` Implicit Solver of Order 5, I am actually using a BDF5 method.

#### EDIT 3:

Per rcollyer's comment, it should be `"MaxDifferenceOrder"` and NOT `"DifferenceOrder`" in case `BDF` is used as the `Method`

Example: `Method->{"BDF", "MaxDifferenceOrder->5"}` executes BDF5.

Any thoughts? Comments? Anything else that I might look for, for say other methods such as the `LSODA` etc?

#### EDIT 4:

As per rcollyer's comment, `BDF` with `"MaxDifferenceOrder"->5`, `NDSolve[..]` changes the order as required UP TO 5 and doesn't just use order 5.

Comment: ``Options[NDSolve`BDF]`` gives ``{"ImplicitSolver" -> NDSolve`Newton, "MaxDifferenceOrder" -> 5, 
 "VariableStepCoefficients" -> Automatic}`` for me on v8.0.4 which says that it doesn't take `"DifferenceOrder"` as an option.

Comment: @rcollyer You are right. However, is running `IDA` with `Newtons` method and `"MaxDifferenceOrder"->5` the same as running `BDF` with `"MaxDifferenceOrder"-> 5`? They both run without errors.

Comment: MaxDifferenceOrder->X mean that the maximum difference order is X. `NDSolve` may, however switch between orders up until X to get to a solution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is not an answer, but it is really too long for a comment.

I don't know if `IDA` is the same as `BDF`, I would have to look closer. However, as you wish to have explicit control over the order of the method and that is not available, it is likely that you can extract what order it does use out of the `InterpolationFunction` returned.

If you set `InterpolationOrder -> All` on `NDSolve`, it's supposed to use the underlying method's order as the interpolation order. Experimenting with

```
Interpolation[..., InterpolationOrder -> ...]
```

reveals you *may* be able to extract the order of interpolation used. For instance,

```
Interpolation[..., InterpolationOrder -> 2][[2]]
```

gives something like

> ```
> {4, 7, 0, {11}, {3}, 0, 0, 0, 0, Automatic}
> ```

The fifth term, `{3}` in this case, is always one more than the order. Using that technique on

```
sol = NDSolve[ {y''[t] + y'[t] + y[t] == 0, y'[0] == y[0] == 1}, 
               y, 
               {t, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, 
               Method -> {"BDF"}, 
               InterpolationOrder -> All
      ]
```

via `sol[[1, 1, 2, 2]]` gives

> ```
> {4, 17, 5, {119}, {4}, {InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 6.28319}}, "<>"]}, 
>    0, 0, 0, Automatic}
> ```

which implies that it uses a 3$^\text{rd}$ order method.

---

**Edit**:

As I intimated, the above method seems workable, but if the format of `InterpolatingFunction` changes, it will fail. However, there is a package specifically designed to extract this type of information from an `InterpolatingFunction`: [`` DifferentialEquations`InterpolatingFunctionAnatomy` ``](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NDSolvePackages.html).  Using `sol` from above,

```
Needs["DifferentialEquations`InterpolatingFunctionAnatomy`"];
InterpolatingFunctionInterpolationOrder @ sol[[1, 1, 2]]
```

> ```
> {3}
> ```

which confirms what the other method came up with.

**Edit 2**:

In addition to the package, above, some opaque objects like `SparseArray` and `InterpolatingFunction` can have their properties [queried](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3911/52). Thanks to [Oleksandr](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/312/oleksandr-r), for `InterpolatingFunction` these are `{"Domain", "Coordinates", "DerivativeOrder", "InterpolationOrder", "Grid", "ValuesOnGrid"}`. So, then you can determine the order used, via

```
sol[[1, 1, 2]]["InterpolationOrder"]
```

Comment: This is a really interesting comment. The reason I am interested in fixing the order to a user defined value is that it makes comparison with published data so much more easier.

Comment: @DNA I understand that. It appears, though, that the built in version of `BDF` does not let you do that, though. An option would be to build your own via the [plug-in framework](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NDSolvePlugIns.html). It isn't for the faint of heart, but may be worth your time.

Comment: I find that fixing the `"MaxDifferenceOrder"` in `BDF` does have an effect on the result. A higher order did get me closer to the solution. I hope I am not understanding that all wrong! :P

Comment: @DNA the name: `"MaxDifferenceOrder"`, implies that the method used is adaptive and changes the order based upon need, i.e. estimated error. Since I don't know the ODE that your solving, it makes comparison difficult. However, it should be noted that ``Options[NDSolve`BDF]`` reveals that `"MaxDifferenceOrder"` is set to `5` by default, and increasing it to `6` on my machine generates an error. So, you should be able to reduce it, but not increase it beyond that point.

Comment: that makes sense considering that it's called the `"MaxDifferenceOrder"`. But it is rather unfortunate that I can't quite change the order and fix it manually. That makes comparison with published results and consequently publishing my results virtually impossible.

Comment: @DNA what exactly in the published paper are you trying to compare your results with? Are you trying to exactly reproduce their info, or trying to show one method is superior to another? To help with the general question, more info is needed.

Comment: Sure thing! The results I am trying to compare with are [here](http://tinyurl.com/6sa9xvm). The authors have used a Backward Euler method for their nonlinear equation. I read from a couple of books that the Backw'd Euler method is actually the BDF method to order 1 and hence I am trying to implement the same.

Comment: @DNA Ah. I'd set `"MaxDifferenceOrder" -> 1`, then, and test the order of interpolation, like above. An idea just sprang to mind about how to get the `InterpolationOrder` in a different way. But, it may be several hours (like 12) before I can get back to it.

Comment: Yes thats exactly what I did -- set the `"MaxDifferenceOrder"->1`. I find that now, I get better convergence than the authors by decreasing the `"MaxStepFraction"`. Forgive me as I am a sophomore at mathematica and I did post a further question about `"MaxStepFraction"` [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3635/204)! :(  but I am getting closer to understanding NDSolve better.

Comment: @DNA no joy on the alternative method, but I'll keep poking at it and see if anything comes of it.

Comment: In the name of completion and all that, I was able to reproduce results in [this paper](http://pof.aip.org/resource/1/phfle6/v12/i7/p1633_s1) by increasing the `"MaxStepFraction"` to `150`. That generated a grid of `151x151` which seemed well and good for the nonlinear partial differential equation as described in the paper..

Comment: @DNA I've updated my answer with something that is supposed to work from version to version.

Comment: Thanks! I was thinking about `InterpolatingFunctionAnatomy`

Comment: @DNA With help, I came across a direct query method that does not need an additional package loaded.

Comment: I am all ears!!!!!!

Comment: @DNA already added to the answer.

Comment: @rcoyller Well, when I solve the example differential equation that you have and load the `InterpolatingFunctionAnatomy` package and ask for the order via `sol["InterpolationOrder"]`, it DOES NOT give me the order... it just pops out `{{y->InterpolatingFunction[{{0.,6.28319}},<>]}}[InterpolationOrder]`

Comment: @DNA grumble. Fixed now. The issue was `["InterpolationOrder"]` was not being applied to the `InterpolatingFunction`.

Comment: Aah! I see that! Thanks!