# What does MaxStepFraction do?

Tags: options, differential-equations, numerical-integration, warning-messages

I find that with `NDSolve[...]` while solving a partial differential equation, changing the `MaxStepFraction` from `1/10` to say `1/60`, improves convergence.

Without going into too many details about the PDE itself, is the `MaxStepFraction` the grid sized used? I generally find that when I use a large step fraction of say `1/30` instead of `1/60`, I get an error message that says:

> NDSolve::eerr: Warning: Scaled local spatial error estimate of
>   1484.278641749214`at t = 240279.84981818125` in the direction of independent variable x is much greater than prescribed error
>   tolerance. Grid spacing with 31 points may be too large to achieve the
>   desired accuracy or precision. A singularity may have formed or you
>   may want to specify a smaller grid spacing using the MaxStepSize or
>   MinPoints method options. >>

Am I to understand that for a large step fraction, my equation either get's stiff (as the step size is large/grid is too coarse)?

**EDIT 1:**

My 4th order non-linear PDE generally looks like:

`h_t + N(h[t,x],h[t,x]^2,h[t,x]^3,h[t,x]^4) = 0`

Where `N(...)` is the non-linear portion.

**EDIT 2:**

I used

```
Needs["DifferentialEquations`InterpolatingFunctionAnatomy`"];
```

and

```
hGrid = InterpolatingFunctionGrid[hSol];  
{nX, nY, nT} =Drop[Dimensions[hGrid], -1]
```

Where `hSol` is my interpolating function result that `NDSolve` provides, and found that nx,ny and nT are respectively: 41,41,298 when I used `MaxStepFraction->1/40`. So I am guessing, that `MaxStepFraction->` does define the spatial grid.

Any thoughts? Comments?

Comment: `MaximumStepFraction` is not mentioned in Mathematica’s documentation, and a Google search of the two terms together turns up your question as the only mention. Can you include some actual code, so we can see how you use it?

Comment: @F'x I apologize. I am getting careless. I meant `MaxStepFraction` and NOT `MaximumStepFraction`. I've also included some more thoughts about this option in EDIT 2.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/MaxStepFraction.html) is fairly clear on this:

> `MaxStepFraction` is an option to functions like `NDSolve` that specifies the maximum fraction of the total range to cover in a single step.

In simpler terms, you can think of `MaxStepFraction` as the inverse of the number of intervals in the total range, whereas `MaxStepSize` is the length of an interval. The following graphic should make the difference clear:

[image]

So in other words, setting `MaxStepFraction = 1/10` and setting `MaxStepSize = L/10` will give you the same result. The documentation linked above also has [an example](http://wolfram.com/xid/0dcz09m1o9eq-ecmh0h) that demonstrates this:

Comment: This makes sense, thank you.

Comment: Not that simple. `MaxStepFraction` seems to override `MaxStepSize`. Here is an example that adjusting `MaxStepSize` doesn't have effect but adjusting `MaxStepFraction` does: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/291395/1871