# Large step size for ExplicitEuler in NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

I am an educator trying to teach Euler's method to numerically approximate ODEs. I want to use *Mathematica* to generate somewhat small examples, i.e. a large step size. When I run

```
f = NDSolveValue[{y'[x] == y[x]^2, y[0] == 1}, y, {x, 0, 2},
  StartingStepSize -> .5,
  Method -> {"ExplicitEuler"},
  StepMonitor :> Print[{x, y[x]}]]
```

I get the output

```
{0.2,1.2}

{0.4,1.488}

{0.6,1.93083}

{0.8,2.67645}

{1.,4.10912}

{1.2,7.48611}

{1.4,18.6945}

{1.6,88.591}

{1.8,1658.26}

{2.,551627.}
```

In other words, *Mathematica* appears to override my intentional choice of step size `0.5` with its own step size of `0.2`. Is there any way to force *Mathematica* to use my desired step size?

By the way, when I make the step size smaller than `0.2`, it works as expected:

```
f = NDSolveValue[{y'[x] == y[x]^2, y[0] == 1}, y, {x, 0, 2},
  StartingStepSize -> .1,
  Method -> {"ExplicitEuler"},
  StepMonitor :> Print[{x, y[x]}]]
```

Gives

```
{0.1,1.1}

{0.2,1.221}

{0.3,1.37008}

{0.4,1.5578}

{0.5,1.80047}

{0.6,2.12464}

{0.7,2.57605}

{0.8,3.23965}

{0.9,4.28919}

{1.,6.1289}

{1.1,9.88524}

{1.2,19.657}

{1.3,58.2969}

{1.4,398.15}

{1.5,16250.5}

{1.6,2.64241*10^7}

{1.7,6.98233*10^13}

{1.8,4.87529*10^26}

{1.9,2.37685*10^52}

{2.,5.64941*10^103}
```

Comment: Maybe method is not stable for large step size.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I'm not sure I understand what I should look at in the [documentation of "FixedStep"](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveFixedStep.html). I see the following sentence "..."ExplicitEuler" method has no adaptive step size control. Therefore, the integration is already carried out using fixed step sizes so the specification of "FixedStep" is unnecessary..." The example it gives is  ```NDSolve[system, StartingStepSize -> 1/10, Method -> "ExplicitEuler"];``` which is what I was trying to follow.

Comment: @ can be used to notify a user that you replied. For example @xzczd .

Comment: Oh… so I didn't remember it right, sorry for that. (Close vote retracted. )

Comment: I also use the following code to plot the first-order interpolation (rather than the default 3rd order): ```f = NDSolveValue[{y'[x] == y[x]*Cos[x], y[0] == 1}, y, {x, 0, 2}, StartingStepSize -> .5, MaxStepFraction -> 1, Method -> {"ExplicitEuler"}]; data = Table[{x, f[x]}, {x, f["Coordinates"][[1]]}];
F = Interpolation[data, InterpolationOrder -> 1]; G = DSolveValue[{y'[x] == y[x]*Cos[x], y[0] == 1}, y, x];
Show[
  VectorPlot[{1, y*Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 3},
  VectorColorFunction -> None, VectorStyle -> {Black, Arrowheads[0]}
  ],
 Plot[{G[x], F[x]}, {x, 0, 2}]
 ]```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at help it seems you also need `MaxStepFraction`

```
f = NDSolveValue[{y'[x] == y[x]^2, y[0] == 1}, y, {x, 0, 2}, 
  StartingStepSize -> .5, MaxStepFraction -> 1/4, 
  Method -> {"ExplicitEuler"}, StepMonitor :> Print[{x, y[x]}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Used `1/4` since the length is `2` and you wanted each step to be `0.5`, so this means max step fraction is 1/4 of total length.

Comment: Interesting. I didn't know `MaxStepFraction` overrides `MaxStepSize` and `StartingStepSize`.

Comment: Great! As a bad hack I can also set `MaxStepFraction -> 1` and don't have to change MaxStep Fraction even to do weird step sizes.