# Getting lengths of sublists that sum to more than one

Tags: performance-tuning, idiomatic-usage

I have a long list of numbers, and I'm interested in finding the length of each sublist that totals to more than 1, so for the list

```
{0.423768, 0.157558, 0.675251, 0.685209, 0.580772, 0.0230333, 
 0.927156, 0.506085, 0.0516773, 0.485349}
```

I would get the lengths `{3, 2, 3}`, as

```
Total[{0.423768, 0.157558, 0.675251}] == 1.25658
Total[{0.685209, 0.580772}] == 1.26598
Total[{0.0230333, 0.927156, 0.506085}] == 1.45627
```

The last two numbers total to 0.537026, so we ignore them. This has an easy imperative solution:

```
thresholdFor[nums_List] :=
  Module[{i = 0, sum = 0, k = 0},
   Reap[
     For[i = 1, i <= Length@nums, ++i,
      sum += nums[[i]];
      ++k;
      If[sum > 1,
       Sow[k];
       k = 0;
       sum = 0]]][[-1, 1]]];
thresholdFor[{}] = {};
```

In addition to being kind of ugly and needing the `For`, it's also pretty slow, as functions that index into lists so often are. It takes about 0.04 seconds to process a list of 10000 random numbers (picked uniformly between 0 and 1). I futzed around with `LengthWhile`, `TakeWhile` and the like before deciding that I really needed the full generality of `Fold` to accomplish what I needed to do:

```
thresholdFold[nums_] :=
 Flatten@Last@Fold[
    With[{sum = #[[1]] + #2, length = #[[2]] + 1, acc = #[[3]]},
      If[sum > 1,
       {0, 0, {acc, length}},
       {sum, length, acc}]] &,
    {0, 0, {}},
    nums]
```

This is arguably more idiomatic, but it's even a bit slower than `thresholdFor`. I can speed `thresholdFor` up *a lot* by compilation (with a suitable adaptation to get rid of the `Reap`/`Sow` pair) and a little wrapper to handle the empty list properly:

```
compiledBody =
  Compile[{{nums, _Real, 1}},
   With[{n = Length@nums},
    Module[{result = ConstantArray[0, n], sum = 0.0, k = 0, fill = 0, i},
     For[i = 1, i <= n, ++i,
      sum += nums[[i]];
      ++k;
      If[sum > 1.0,
       result[[++fill]] = k;
       k = 0; sum = 0]];
     Take[result, fill]]]];

thresholdCompiled[nums_List] := compiledBody[nums];
thresholdCompiled[{}] = {};
```

This is dramatically faster after compilation--it runs in about 10 ms for the list of 100000 numbers, and is only about 10 times slower than `Mean` or `Total` on the same data. Still, I always think I'm going down a bit of a blind alley when I start using `Compile` to make imperative list-processing algorithms fast enough to use.

Finally, I did come up with something more Mathematica-esque, but it's actually much slower than the compiled solution (taking about 130 ms):

```
thresholdClip[nums_] :=
    Differences@Flatten@Position[
        FoldList[Clip[Plus[##], {0.0, 1.0}, {0.0, 0.0}] &, 0.0, randoms], 
        0.0]
```

I've tried a couple tweaks for speeding up `thresholdClip`, including one which replaces `Position` with `Pick` so I can compile the whole thing, but that didn't seem to do a lot of good.

Comment: The problem looks naggingly familiar. Have we had a question like this before?

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries It felt naggingly familiar to me, too, but searching didn't turn up anything helpful-looking.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Very good question / problem. Generally, this problem seems to belong to the class of problems where `Compile` is the best choice if maximum efficiency is looked for, since it is, by its nature, not a good fit for the Mathematica paradigm of working with lots of data at once. However, your last solution can be, in a somewhat modified form, brought to the same performance level while only partly compiled:

```
Clear[split, thresholdSemiCompiled];
split = Compile[{{nums, _Real, 1}}, 
   FoldList[If[# > 1, 0, #] &[#1 + #2] &, 0.0, nums], 
   CompilationTarget -> "C"];

thresholdSemiCompiled[l_List] := 
   Flatten@Differences[SparseArray[Unitize[split[l]] - 1]["NonzeroPositions"]]
```

It turns out that `Clip` was a major bottleneck in the compiled `split`, and once I replaced it with `If`, it became an order of magnitude faster. This one is on par with your fastest fully compiled solution, in terms of performance.

#### Edit (by Oleksandr R., at Leonid's request)

In version 8, provided that an integer argument is used rather than a pattern, `Position` can be compiled down into a call to a new kernel/VM function `"Position"`. This allows the above to be implemented in purely compiled code and avoids the need to use `SparseArray` in an undocumented and perhaps unintuitive way to get the positions of the zeros without unpacking the input array:

```
thresholdCompiled = Compile[{{nums, _Real, 1}},
  Flatten@Differences@Position[
    Unitize@FoldList[If[# > 1, 0, #] &[#1 + #2] &, 0.0, nums],
    0
  ], CompilationTarget -> "C"
 ];
```

The performance gained by doing this is, perhaps surprisingly, relatively minor: this version returns timings of about 7/8ths those of the semi-compiled approach, irrespective of compilation to MVM bytecode or to C, probably due to the ability to locate zeros directly rather than having to subtract 1 from the array and find nonzero elements, and by avoiding the need to return a large intermediate array. (`Unitize`, `Differences`, `Position`, and `Flatten` are all compilable, but in version 8 they are compiled into simple function calls, so the only situation in which we would expect a performance gain through compilation is when, as here, it allows a larger problem to be dealt with entirely in compiled code.)

Comment: Last question (probably), I've never encountered `SparseArray[...]["NonzeroPositions"]` before, where did you find that, and are there other methods available on it?

Comment: @rcollyer I learned this from [Oliver](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/21/ruebenko), who published some code using this a few times on Mathgroup, e.g. [here](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/browse_thread/thread/4388915c7f1ec3fb). There are also "NonzeroValues", I don't know what else. But note, all these shortcuts are not strictly necessary, just convenient. One can use the SparseArray "API" like the one I posted [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/276/efficient-way-to-combine-sparsearray-objects/287#287) to achieve the same effect.

Comment: Convenient, yes. Undocumented, definitely. They don't even show up via `SubValues[SparseArray]`. :P

Comment: @rcollyer They are probably internal `SubValues`, so they don't show on the top-level.

Comment: How then would someone determine if they exist, or not, from the top-level?

Comment: @rcollyer `SparseArray[...]["Properties"]` gives `{"AdjacencyLists", "Background", "NonzeroPositions", "NonzeroValues", "PatternArray", "Properties"}`. That's the complete list.

Comment: @rcollyer I have no idea in general (which is one reason why I don't like strings - as I noted in my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5167782/using-strings-instead-of-symbols-good-or-evil/5168288#5168288) - they are dangerously close to hard-coding stuff ). In this particular case, Oleksandr just showed how to get these (natural thing to try in retrospect, but I did not know this).

Comment: @Oleksandr Thanks, makes sense, and good to know.

Comment: @OleksandrR. I'll have to try that with more opaque objects. For example, nothing special comes from `InterpolatingFunction[...]["Properties"]=={"Properties"}`, unfortunately. It would have been nice to query the order and applicable range.

Comment: @rcollyer yes, I think the lack of sensible output for `InterpolatingFunction[...]["Properties"]` is an omission. Anyway, the list of possible properties for interpolating functions is `{"Domain", "Coordinates", "DerivativeOrder", "InterpolationOrder", "Grid", "ValuesOnGrid"}`.

Comment: @OleksandrR. probably to late to get implemented for v.9. :P

Comment: @LeonidShifrin I've never seen `"NonzeroPositions"`, et c., used with `SparseArray`s either, nor have I seen string arguments to `InterpolatingFunction`s (I always used `DifferentialEquations\`InterpolatingFunctionAnatomy` instead). I'd give your answer a +2 if I could, because of that bonus.

Comment: @Pillsy unfortunately, it doesn't work with `InterpolatingFunction` as I pointed out, which is a shame. Oleksandr was just giving a list of what would be nice to have, if it worked.

Comment: @rcollyer these string arguments do work. The problem is that this list isn't actually produced by giving an argument of `"Properties"`, so one is left guessing as to what properties exist.

Comment: @OleksandrR. ah, so it is only "Properties" itself that is broken. Cool. Thanks.

Comment: @Oleksandr R. Thanks a bunch for making that edit with your solution, good stuff!

Comment: Happy to help! Sorry for the delay in making the edit: one of my hard disks crashed...

Comment: @Oleksandr R. Nothing to be sorry about! Regarding HDD - I feel your pain,  hope you did not lose anything important on your HDD, and recovered it all right.

Comment: Fortunately it was one of a RAID5 set, so I lost only the money I had to spend on replacing it and the time needed to rebuild the array. And gained a headache in the process...

Comment: @Oleksandr R. I sympathize. But it could be worse. Good that you had an array.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin, 404 on "learned this from Oliver"

Comment: @alancalvitti Look for user21. He quit SE. Then rejoined, under the name [user21](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/18437/user21). His past contributions, however, can't be easily found systematically, since the user was deleted. You can find them here and there, e.g.  [this one](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/824).

Answer (score 7):

Possibly not fastest, but concise and using a simple iteration over the list. Or two iterations, if we do a cleanup step as in the Compile'd variants.

```
subseqlens[ll_] := Reap[Module[{n = 0, tot = 0.},
    Map[(n++; tot += #; If[tot > 1, tot = 0.; Sow[n]; n = 0]) &, 
     ll]]][[-1, 1]]

subseqlensC = Compile[{{ll, _Real, 1}}, Module[{n = 0, tot = 0., m},
    Select[
     Map[(n++; tot += #; If[tot > 1, tot = 0.; m = n; n = 0; m, 0]) &,
       ll], # != 0 &]]];

subseqlensCC = Compile[{{ll, _Real, 1}}, Module[{n = 0, tot = 0., m},
    Select[
     Map[(n++; tot += #; If[tot > 1, tot = 0.; m = n; n = 0; m, 0]) &,
       ll], # != 0 &]], CompilationTarget -> "C"];
```

Here is a fairly big example.

```
In[461]:= biglist = RandomReal[1, 10^6];
Timing[ss1 = subseqlens[biglist];]
Timing[ss2 = subseqlensC[biglist];]
Timing[ss3 = subseqlensCC[biglist];]
ss1 === ss2 === ss3

Out[462]= {2.92, Null}
Out[463]= {0.26, Null}
Out[464]= {0.04, Null}
Out[465]= True
```

Comment: "but concise" - as Fortran is to assembly language. What century are we in?

Comment: @alancalvitti Sometimes Fortran-like code is the way to proceed. I mean, if it was good enough for Michaelangelo, then who am I to snub it?

Comment: Why not assembly, or punched cards?

Comment: @alancalvitti We only developed `Compile when we started running low on punched cards.

Comment: But now you're running low on time - should develop a RTOS or RTVM running on FPGAs. You see how long it takes to dev JSF (F35) blocks?

Comment: @alancalvitti There is [this in the works](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P2tr7A1LOLA&feature=youtu.be&list=PLxn-kpJHbPx0po0k_FiuFqDuVotoZhX7_) but I'm guessing you knew that already.

Comment: I didn't know. I met Tom but we didn't discuss that. Finally, the end of Unix  . Hope to see you @next TC.

Answer (score 6):

Using `Fold` with `Reap` and `Sow` might be cleaner:

```
ClearAll[f];
f = If[Total[{##}, Infinity] > 1, Sow[Length[Flatten[{##}]]]; ## &[], {##}] &;
Fold[f, First@list, Rest@list]; // Reap // Last

(* Out[1]= {{3, 2, 3}} *)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `NestWhileList` together with `Accumulate` :

```
alist = {0.423768, 0.157558, 0.675251, 0.685209, 0.580772, 
         0.0230333, 0.927156, 0.506085, 0.0516773, 0.485349} ;
```

This will return the position where you need to split the input list :

```
NestWhileList[
 {pos = Position[Accumulate[#[[2]]], _?(# >= 1 &)][[1, 1]]; 
  pos + #[[1]],Drop[#[[2]], pos]} &, 
 {pos = Position[Accumulate[alist], _?(# >= 1 &)][[1, 1]], Drop[alist, pos]},
 (Length[#[[2]]] > 1 && Total[#[[2]]] >= 1) &
][[All, 1]]

(* {3, 5, 8} *)
```

Comment: The performance on this solution is quadratic, because you keep re-accumulating and re-searching `alist` after droping smallish chunks off the front of it each time. Also, if you're going to be tracking state in `NestWhileList` by using a list argument, you don't need to mutate a variable like `pos` as you go.