# How to set the return type of a compiled function? (Compile::noinfo warning)

Tags: compile

I have simple function I would like to compile, but I get a warning and a call to MainEvaluate. I would like to avoid both.

```
ClearAll[MakeInPeriodicCell]
On["CompilerWarnings"]
MakeInPeriodicCell = 
  Compile[{x, cellwidth}, 
   First@Sort[{x, x - cellwidth, x + cellwidth}, Abs[#1] < Abs[#2] &]];
CompiledFunctionTools`CompilePrint[MakeInPeriodicCell]  

(*Compile::noinfo: No information is available for compilation of 
Sort[{x,x cellwidth,x+cellwidth},Abs[#1]<Abs[#2]&]. 
The compiler will use an external evaluation and make assumptions about the return type.*)

(*
...
5   T(R1)2 = MainEvaluate[ Function[{x, cellwidth}, Sort[{x, x - \
cellwidth, x + cellwidth}, Abs[#1] < Abs[#2] & ]][ R0, R1]]
...
*)
```

**EDIT**

(I got the correct syntax for the subexpression from an answer that got deleted?)
I tried setting the type of a subexpression like this:

```
MakeInPeriodicCell = 
 Compile[{x, cellwidth}, 
  First@Sort[{x, x - cellwidth, x + cellwidth}, 
    Abs[#1] < Abs[#2] &], {{Sort[_,_], _Real,1}}]
```

This gets rid of the warning, but the call to MainEvaluate remains.

Can this snippet be compiled without a call to MainEvaluate?

---

**EDIT 1**

Since compile is always about speed, here is some benchmark info. (the code is [here](https://gist.github.com/2312325), as it clutters the question a bit)

```
data = RandomReal[{-100, 100}, 100000];
(*Original implementation*)
m0 = MakeInPeriodicCellOrig[data, 30]; // AbsoluteTiming (*0.8370473*)
(*my revritten*)
m1 = MakeInPeriodicCellImp[data, 30]; // AbsoluteTiming  (*0.0360021*)
(*F'x answer*)
m2 = MakeInPeriodicCellFx[data, 30]; // AbsoluteTiming   (*0.0140008*)

m0 == m1 == m2 (*True*)
```

So getting read of MainEvaluate gives you about 20x speed-up and changing to a better algorithm another 3x. I usually have a million to ten million points, so the speed-up is very welcome.

Comment: If you set `SetSystemOptions["CompileOptions" -> "CompileReportExternal" -> True]` the warning does not go away. Out of curiosity, have you read these [two](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1803/52) [questions](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1096/52)?

Comment: @rcollyer But of course I have read the two questions:)

Comment: I had to ask. :)

Comment: I did figure out what the problem is: Function[] is not in the compilable list. But I didn't notice it before, since it was hidden in the short form &. Should I post the answer or just delete the whole question?

Comment: @Ajasja one could post a workaround as an answer; I don't see why to delete the question

Comment: Well, `Function` certainly can be compiled in some cases, so this is not the right explanation. For a recent example of a case where `Function` was successfully compiled, see [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3908/getting-lengths-of-sublists-that-sum-to-more-than-one/3911#3911)

Comment: @Leonid Without a call to MainEvaluate?

Comment: Yes, sure, without a call to `MainEvaluate`. Check that answer, the compiled code there

Comment: Thanks all. Wow, the answers and comments sure are happening in real time here!:)

Comment: How do you find out whether there is a call to MainEvaluate? Would it be directly in the `FullForm` or would it be necessary to run a sort of disassembler on it?

Comment: If you call CompiledFunctionTools`CompilePrint[MakeInPeriodicCell] you will see it in the output.

Comment: @Ajasja: Thanks. Learned something new again.

Comment: I now just tried `CompiledFunctionTools`CompilePrint[Compile[{l},Sort[l]]` and it also calls `MainEvaluate`. So maybe it's `Sort` which is problematic (actually, if I wanted speed, I'd not use a `Sort` routine to get the smallest element anyways. After all, you are not interested in the order of the other two, are you?)

Comment: @celtschk No it doesn't, but you have to give it a rank one tensor. Try  CompiledFunctionTools`CompilePrint[Compile[{{l, _Real, 1}}, Sort[l]]]

Comment: Ok, learned something new *again!* (But my point about sorting not being the most efficient way of getting the smallest element should be safe, at least :-))

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think Leonid’s comment is spot on. You could work around the issue with a completely different approach:

```
MakeInPeriodicCell = Compile[{{x, _Real}, {cellwidth, _Real}},
   If[x < -(cellwidth/2.), x + cellwidth, 
    If[x > cellwidth/2., x - cellwidth, x]]
   ];
```

Comment: Could also use `Ordering` and order `Abs` of your list, and then extract elements - this way one can use default comparison function and compile.

Answer (score 3):

It appears that in this case Function[] can not be compiled without a call to MainEvaluate.

This is my workaround, but I like F'x much better:)

```
MakeInPeriodicCell = Compile[{x, cellwidth},
  With[{  l = {x, x - cellwidth, x + cellwidth}},
   Sort[Transpose[{Abs[l], l}]][[1, 2]]
   ]]
```

Comment: This is not a problem of `Function` not being compiled, this is a problem of type-inferencing inside `Sort`. I suspect that this is a flaw or limitation of how compilation of `Sort` was implemented, and has nothing to do directly with abilities of `Compile` to compile pure functions.