# Finding the exact numerical method used by mathematica to solve a differential equation

Tags: differential-equations

Let's say I have a 1st order differential equation with a known initial boundary condition. If I want to solve it in Mathematica, I know that I need to use NDSolve, for example:

```
s = NDSolve[{y'[x] == y[x] Cos[x + y[x]], y[0] == 1}, y, {x, 0, 30}]
```

However, is there any command available that will show me the exact numerical method Mathematica is using to solve the equation? Thanks in advance.

Comment: tracing shows it seems to have used **NDSolve`LSODA**.  This is described in [here](https://inis.iaea.org/search/search.aspx?orig_q=RN:41086668)  You can always ofcourse tell NDSolve which method you want it to user otherwise. see also [NDSolveDesign](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveDesign.html) and [how-to-set-the-ndsolve-method-to-lsoda](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3372/how-to-set-the-ndsolve-method-to-lsoda)  To trace NDSolve, do **Trace[NDSolve[......],TraceInternal->True]**