# Why does LogLinearPlot sample its argument outside the specified domain?

Tags: plotting, numerical-integration, bugs, interpolation, version-8

**Bug introduced in 6.0 and fixed in 9.0.0**

---

I experience a weird bug in the function `LogLinearPlot`. If the input is an interpolation function, such as the one created like this,

```
int = NDSolve[{x'[t] == 1, x[0] == 0}, x, {t, 0, 100}]
```

then when plotting it I get an error message (but the plot works fine)

```
LogLinearPlot[x[t] /. int, {t, 0.1, 100}]

InterpolatingFunction::dmval: "Input value {-2.30244} lies outside the range of data in the interpolating function. Extrapolation will be used"
```

You will not be surprised to know that `log(0.1)=-2.302`. It seems that `LogLinearPlot` tries to plug in the wrong values in the function, but the plot does look good.

**Update: This is working correctly in version 9.**

Comment: `Reap@LogLinearPlot[Sow[x], {x, 2, 10}]` will show that this evaluation happens only once.  `EvaluationMonitor` does not reveal this evaluation.  The value is not precisely the logartihm of the lower bound, it is slightly larger than that and also depends on the upper bound.

Comment: Related: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/B8tPXFaPSoc/3FTjYzHDuToJ

Comment: And *yet again*, it turns out that I have already asked the very same question on MathGroup, 3 years ago, and I have completely forgotten about it: https://groups.google.com/d/topic/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/zyWSV0Y0U_k/discussion

Comment: @Szabolcs Since this seems to be fixed in v9, I've added the tag `version-8`. What is the policy in such situations? I don't even know whether it was introduced in v8, v7 or v6.

Comment: @István [Here's the meta on that.](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/853/what-to-do-with-bugs-questions-now-that-version-9-is-released)

Comment: @Szabolcs: Thanks for the link! Pedig még fel is szavaztam annak idején... :) I've added an update to the question accordingly.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is fixed in version 9.

---

[This came up on MathGroup before.](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/zyWSV0Y0U_k/discussion)  Since it hasn't been fixed for so long, I wasn't sure if it was really a bug, so I did some spelunking (and some speculation) today to find out what's happening.  To jump to the end:  **I think it's a bug**.

---

First, let's see what arguments does `LogLinearPlot` really pass to the function:

```
Reap@LogLinearPlot[Sow[x], {x, 1, 10}]

(* ==>
   {x, 0.0000470385, 1., 1.04623, 1.09877, 1.15021, ... }
*)
```

Indeed, it does sample outside the domain (`0.000047`).  If you try the `EvaluationMonitor` option, you'll see that this strange value won't show up there.

Now let's try a plain `Plot`:

```
Reap@Plot[Sow[x], {x, 1, 2}]

(* ==>
   {1.00002, x, 1., 1.01963, 1.04091, 1.06078, ... }
*)
```

Notice a strange value at the beginning again, `1.00002`.  It seems that `Plot[f[x], {x, min, max}]` always starts by evaluating the function with a numerical value that is midway between `min` and `max`, approximately (but not always exactly) at `min + 0.00002 (max-min)`.  After this, `Plot` will evaluate the argument symbolically.

My guess is that `Plot` does this to discover some information about the function, and also to decide whether the evaluate it or not.  `Plot` is `HoldAll`, and we know that often it is necessary to use `Plot[f[x] // Evaluate, ...]`.  In my experience, `Plot` actually tries to be smart and decide whether it should do this automatically.  It also has an undocumented `Evaluated` option with the default value being `Automatic`, which I believe controls this behaviour.  You can set it to `True` or `False` and see what happens.

Now let's see what `LogLogPlot` does.  A little [spelunking](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1742/12) reveals that it calls the functions `scaledPlot2` and `scaledPlot` (in the `` Graphics`LogPlotDump` `` context), which then call `Plot` with the following `Method` options (simplified):

```
Reap@Plot[
  Sow[x], {x, Log[1], Log[10]}, 
  {Method -> {"MappingFunctions" -> {{#1, #2} &, {#1, #2} &}, 
              "DomainMappingFunctions" -> {Exp[#1] &}}}]
```

Note that the bounds have been transformed using `Log` (in `scaledPlot2`), and the `"MappingFunctions"` and `"DomainMappingFunctions"` options tell `Plot` about this transformation.

It'll evaluate the function with these arguments:

```
{0.0000470385, x, 1., 1.04623, 1.09877, 1.15021, ... }
```

Note that even though the bounds are given as `Log[1]` and `Log[10]`, `Plot` will transform these values before passing it to its argument function for all value *except the first two special ones*.

My conclusion: `Plot` fails to transform `x` using the `"DomainMappingFunction"` when passing the function the first two "discovery values".  I'd call this a bug.

It's not a serious bug though unless your function does something really bad and unexpected when called with wrong arguments (hang, crash, format your hard drive).

Comment: I'm not sure why I did this, after all it won't help anyone ... but there's no other answer in this case than "it's a bug".

Comment: It just helped me. "Plot actually tries to be smart and decide whether it should do this automatically.". It reassured me why something I had tried in another question didn't work. I assumed Plot just never evaluated, and the results proved me wrong

Comment: @Rojo I am not sure how `Plot` decides whether to evaluate or not (IIRC my experiments with the `Evaluated` option gave inconsistent results), but I'm sure that sometimes it does and sometimes it doesn't: there's some heuristic at work.

Comment: Thanks. I had to fool those heuristics by wrapping it in a function that did nothing useful. Fortunately there's EvaluationMonitor (and Heike to remind me of it)

Comment: +1 mainly because "... format your hard drive" is food for thought

Comment: It's weird that they didn't fix that. Seems like an easy thing to fix. Did you report this problem to Wolfram support?

Comment: Ouch, annoying one, I had a `Piecewise` that was `Indeterminate` at that sample point causing `LogLinearPlot` to not plot at all