# No warning when extrapolating with Plot

Tags: plotting, bugs, interpolation, warning-messages

One of the most annoying "features" of *Mathematica* is that the `Plot` family does extrapolation on `InterpolatingFunction`s without any warning. I'm sure it was discussed to hell previously, but I cannot seem to find any reference. While I know how to simply overcome the problem by defining a global variable for the domain of the interpolation, from time to time I forget to do this and then I spend days figuring out where the numerical error originates. This could be avoided if `Plot` was to give a warning.

Consider the following example. An ODE system is defined and integrated for two different time ranges:

```
odes = {
   a'[t] == -a[t] - .2 a[t]^2 + 2. b[t], 
   b'[t] == a[t] + .1 a[t]^2 - 1.1 b[t], a[0] == 1, b[0] == 1
};
sol100 = First@NDSolve[odes, {a, b}, {t, 0, 100}];
sol500 = First@NDSolve[odes, {a, b}, {t, 0, 500}];
```

Now querying the function value for a point outside of the range correctly gives a warning:

```
(a /. sol100)[500]
```

> ```
> InterpolatingFunction::dmval: Input value {500} lies outside
> the range of data in the interpolating function. Extrapolation will be used. >>
>
> 651.034
> ```

The same is not done when we use the function in `Plot`:

```
Show[
 Plot[{a[t], b[t]} /. sol100, {t, 0, 400}, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Red}],
 Plot[{a[t], b[t]} /. sol500, {t, 0, 400}, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Blue}]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I've tried to force a warning, with no avail. The following example won't give a warning.

```
On[InterpolatingFunction::dmval]
Check[Plot[{a[t], b[t]} /. sol100, {t, 0, 500}], "Error", 
 InterpolatingFunction::dmval]
```

Interestingly, one can be sure that `InterpolatingFunction::dmval` is NOT turned off at all inside the `Plot` family. In the following example, `LogLinearPlot` is able to drop a warning about sampling from below the domain (that can be ignored being unrelated, see [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5986/89), also it seems to be fixed in v9), but it does not give the same warning when sampling from **above** (> 100)!

```
LogLinearPlot[{a[t], b[t]} /. sol100, {t, 0.1, 500}]
```

> ```
> InterpolatingFunction::dmval: Input value {-2.30241} lies outside the
> range of data in the interpolating function. Extrapolation will be used. >>
> ```

It is even more disturbing to see that `Plot` checks the lower boundary but not the upper (thanks to [J.M.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/50/j-m) for the comment):

```
Plot[{a[t], b[t]} /. sol100, {t, -1, 500}]
```

> ```
> InterpolatingFunction::dmval: Input value {-0.989765} lies outside the
> range of data in the interpolating function. Extrapolation will be used. >>
> ```

As [Oleksandr](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/312/oleksandr-r) has pointed out, it is not about lower vs. upper boundaries but first point vs. the rest.

```
Plot[{a[t], b[t]} /. sol100, {t, 101, 500}]
```

> ```
> InterpolatingFunction::dmval: Input value {101.008} lies outside the
> range of data in the interpolating function. Extrapolation will be used. >>
> ```

### **Questions**

1. Why `Plot` does not give a warning when extrapolating an `InterpolatingFunction`? Is there some higher-level consideration that justifies this behaviour, or is it a bug?
2. How can one force `Plot` to give a warning? Is there any workaround that forces `InterpolatingFunction::dmval` not to be attenuated inside `Plot`?

Comment: as a remark `Plot` also ignores say complex values which is sometimes useful.

Comment: Plot[Check[{a[t], b[t]} /. sol100, "Error"], {t, 0, 500}] ?

Comment: @belisarius: It stops plotting because of `Plot::accbend` and not because of extrapolating outside of the range (`InterpolatingFunction::dmval`). It is not informative for the user, and I'm not sure they are related.

Comment: Very odd. OTOH, try `Plot[{a[t], b[t]} /. sol100, {t, -1, 500}]`.

Comment: Thanks @J.M., included, if you don't mind.

Comment: You're welcome; helping with the diagnosis is why I wrote that comment. :) If memory serves, older versions of *Mathematica* allowed `InterpolatingFunction[]` to spit out a warning when extrapolation is being done within `Plot[]`. I wonder what changed...

Comment: Strange indeed, and well spotted. Compare `Plot[{a[t], b[t]} /. sol100, {t, 400, 500}]`. It seems to be determined not by lower vs. upper bounds but rather somehow depends on the range chosen (first point vs. the rest?); apparently `InterpolatingFunction::dmval` *is* turned off, but only later in the plotting process. The strange thing is that hooking `Quiet` and `Off` show no relevant usage of the former in `Plot` and no instances at all of the latter.

Comment: @J.M. I do remember encountering this odd behaviour as early as 2007 for the first time. Before that, I never really used `NDSolve` and interpolated functions.

Comment: Furthermore, hooking `Message` shows that rather a lot of `InterpolatingFunction::dmval` messages *are* produced--they just somehow don't get out of `Plot`. Weird, and in my estimation, almost certainly a bug...

Comment: Tagging this as bug.  @Oleksandr Perhaps there's a non-selective `Quiet` somewhere inside.

Comment: @Szabolcs definitely a bug. As Mr. W's answer shows, `Quiet` isn't used; nor is `Off`. (I had hooked these two, plus `Message`, before I left my comment above. There is something going on with the internal message handling routines but I am not sure how these work and didn't have time to figure it out.)

Answer (score 8):

It seems that indeed messages are suppressed somewhere in the evaluation of `Plot`.  Interestingly this appears to happen some time after the first numeric evaluation.  If we issue this message for each (numeric) point plotted we see that it is printed only once:

```
f[x_?NumericQ] := (Message[InterpolatingFunction::"dmval", {21.06`}]; Sin[x])

Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 10}]
```

If we make `f` to [redefine itself](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2676/121) such that it only issues the message after the first point is evaluated the message is never printed:

```
f[x_?NumericQ] :=
 (
  f[y_?NumericQ] := (Message[InterpolatingFunction::"dmval", {21.06`}]; Sin[y]);
  Sin[x]
 )

Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 10}]
```

This shows that the suppression of this message is not the result of some special optimization while plotting an `InterpolatingFunction` (which might be done outside the normal evaluation chain) but rather something more general.

It should be noted that the `::dmval` message is not the only one suppressed, e.g.:

```
f[x_?NumericQ] := (Message[qrs::argx, 1, 2]; Sin[x])

Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 10}]
```

We can further demonstrate that Plot does not (appear to) use the high level function `Quiet` itself for this suppression, as this does not restore the messages:

```
Block[{Quiet = # &}, Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 10}] ]
```

One can get messages past Plot with something like this:

```
Unprotect[Message]

Message[x : InterpolatingFunction::"dmval", other___] :=
  Print @ Style[Row[{HoldForm[InterpolatingFunction::"dmval"], ":  ", 
      StringForm[x, other]}], "Message"]

f[x_?NumericQ] := (Message[InterpolatingFunction::"dmval", {21.06`}]; Sin[x])

Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 10}, PlotPoints -> 5, MaxRecursion -> 0]
```

But there is no automatic limit to the number of messages printed making this impractical to use as written.

I am continuing to explore this question.

Comment: Interesting so far! Hopefully this will be ironed out in v9, which of course won't render these discoveries useless.

Comment: @István Has anything changed in v9.0.1?

Comment: Nothing. Apart from the minor fix of `LogLinearPlot` not trying to sampling from below $x_{min}$, see my edit in my post.

Answer (score 5):

As you can see with

```
if = Interpolation[Range[10]];
With[{mess = $Messages},
      Plot[
       Block[{$Messages = mess}, if[x]], {x, 5, 20}, Evaluated -> False]
  ]~Quiet~Message::msgl
```

the problem is that `$Messages` gets blocked somehow. I have so far no good recommendations as to how to fix it properly.

Comment: Interesting find Rojo! It confirms that there is proper range-testing in `Plot` though suppressed.

Answer (score 4):

As Rojo showed, the symbol `$Messages` appears to become unset somewhere inside the `Plot` internals. I wondered if it was possible to prevent this by setting the `Protected` and `Locked` attributes for `$Messages`, but it would seem that `Plot` has magic powers:

```
SetAttributes[$Messages, {Protected, Locked}];
f = Interpolation[Range[5]];
g[x_] := (Print[Attributes[$Messages], "  ", $Messages]; f[x]);
Plot[g[x], {x, 1, 6}]
```

[image]

You can see that after the first evaluation `$Messages` loses the `Protected` attribute and its value, though curiously it remains `Locked` throughout.

Since it seems impossible to stop `$Messages` losing its value, an imperfect workaround might be to reset it whenever the `InterpolatingFunction::dmval` message is generated.

```
Quit[];

Unprotect[Message];
With[{mess = $Messages},
 m : Message[InterpolatingFunction::dmval, __] :=
  Block[{$mIFdmval = True}, $Messages = mess; m] /; !TrueQ[$mIFdmval]]
```

With this approach the automatic limit of 3 messages kicks in if the messages are generated outside of `Plot`:

```
f = Interpolation[Range[5]];
Table[f[x], {x, 1, 10}]
```

[image]

Unfortunately, the automatic limit doesn't work with `Plot` (perhaps because `Plot` messes around with `$MessageList` as well), so you still get a long list of messages.