# Quiet doesn't work with FindRoot when using Brent method

Tags: equation-solving, bugs, warning-messages, message-coding

**Bug introduced in 9.0.1 or earlier and persisting through 12.3.1 or later**

---

The following has no solution:

```
FindRoot[x == 1, {x, 0.25, 0, 0.5}]
```

And Mathematica correctly warns us:

> FindRoot::reged: The point {0.5} is at the edge of the search region {0.,0.5} in coordinate 1 and the computed search direction points outside the region.

If we use `Quiet`, we correctly suppress the message.

The following is exactly the same system, but here we ask for a specific numerical method

```
FindRoot[x == 1, {x, 0, 0.5}, Method -> "Brent"]
```

And we receive a similar warning:

> FindRoot::bbrac: Method -> Brent is only applicable to univariate real functions and requires two real starting values that bracket the root.

But this time, if we add `Quiet`, we still receive the same warning.

Why isn't `Quiet` working (is it a bug)?

Comment: I'd say it's a bug.  It's possible to shut it up by using both Check and Quiet: `Quiet@Check[FindRoot[x == 1, {x, 0.25, 0, 0.5}, Method -> "Brent"], 
  foo]`

Comment: @Szabolcs I'll use `Check` to solve my problem, and I'll wait some more comments/answers before posting it to support. Thank you.

Comment: I remember another question about `Quiet` not suppressing certain messages.  Does anyone recall which it is? EDIT: No, it was the converse syndrome: [(14140)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/14140/121)

Comment: `Quiet` and `;` together stop the message too. Could also use `Off[FindRoot::bbrac]`

Comment: I'd say it's a bug. `TracePrint` reveals *two* calls to `Message[FindRoot::bbrac]`.

Comment: @Szabolcs you mean with `Off[FindRoot::bbrac]`? Works for me. `FindRoot[x == 1, {x, 0, 0.5}, Method -> "Brent"]; // Quiet` works as well.

Comment: Yep, two calls to `Message`, and one suppressed, but only if `Quiet` is used.  Here's a way to check: `messageHandler = Print[{##}] &;
Internal`AddHandler["Message", messageHandler];`  It'll show things like `Hold[Message[FindRoot::bbrac],True]` where `True` means not suppressed using `Quiet`.

Comment: @Sjoerd Sorry, I have a problem with copying on OS X, it's very annoying.  I pasted the previous contents of the clipboard by accident.  But now I understand what you meant by `Quiet` and `;`.

Comment: @Szabolcs `FindRoot` seems to be called twice too.

Comment: Looks to me like this is figured out.  Why not write it up as an answer and get this question off the 'unanswered questions' list?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a bug: there are more than one call to `Message[FindRoot::bbrac]`, and some of them are suppressed, but only if `Quiet` is used. Here's a way to check suggested by Szabolcs:

```
messageHandler = Print[{##}] &;
Internal`AddHandler["Message", messageHandler];
Quiet@FindRoot[x == 1, {x, 0, 0.5}, Method -> "Brent"]
```

> <...>
>
> {Hold[Message[FindRoot::bbrac],False]}
>
> {Hold[Message[FindRoot::bbrac],False]}
>
> {Hold[Message[FindRoot::bbrac],True]}
>
> {Hold[Message[FindRoot::bbrac],True]}

When the last argument is `True` it means that the call was not suppressed by `Quiet`.

The suggested workarounds follow.

As already stated in the comments by Sjoerd, `Quiet` and `;` together stop the message:

```
Quiet[FindRoot[x == 1, {x, 0, 0.5}, Method -> "Brent"];]
```

Another solution is to swith `Off` this message globally:

```
Off[FindRoot::bbrac]
```

Szabolcs noticed that `Check` with `Quiet` together suppress the message too:

```
Quiet@Check[FindRoot[x == 1, {x, 0.25, 0, 0.5}, Method -> "Brent"], foo]
```