# NumberForm pesky warning from Manipulate

Tags: manipulate, output-formatting, output, number-representation, version-7

I'm using the **NumberForm** command inside a **Manipulate** environment, and in some special cases Mathematica gives a pesky and mostly useless warning message :

> NumberForm::sigz: In addition to the number of digits requested, one or more zeros will appear as placeholders.

Is there a way to tell mathematica to not give any of these useless warnings ?

I'm using **NumberForm** just to round some output numbers, with a fixed number of digits, like this : **NumberForm[x, {4, 3}]**.

Also, is there a way to round the labeled numbers which are shown next to a **Manipulate** slider ?

**Update :** Here's a MWE which replicates my problem :

```
Afunction[r_, x_, y_] := -x/r + (y^2 - 1)/(2 r^2)

Acurve[x_, y_] := Plot[{Afunction[r, x, y], (x^2 - 1)/2}, {r, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {-1.5, 1.5}}]

someInfo[x_, y_] := If[(0 < x < 1 && y > 1), Text[Style[StringJoin["Just a test :\n\n", "r = ", ToString[NumberForm[x/(1 - x^2), {5, 4}]], " km"]], {5, -1.25}], {}]

Manipulate[Show[Acurve[x, y],
PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {-1.5, 1.5}},
AspectRatio -> 1,
Frame -> True,
Epilog -> someInfo[x, y]],

Row[{
    Control[{{x, 0.8}, -1, 2, 0.001, Appearance -> {"Labeled"}}],
    Spacer[124],
    Control[{{y, 1.5}, 0, 15, Appearance -> {"Labeled"}}]
}]]
```

The code compiles fine and works as excepted.  However, open the first slider to enter a number by hand for "x", and enter something like **x = 0.9999999**.  Then you should get a warning message.

What is the problem with my code ?

Comment: you may use `Quiet` to prevent message but what is your Manipulate code? I cannot reproduce the problem.

Comment: the answer to the second part of the question is [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/30368/how-to-set-precision-and-format-labeled-slider-in-manipulate)

Comment: Thanks garej.  My manipulatye code is pretty complex, and would be hard to reduce to a MWE.  Do the Quiet command applies to ALL error messages as well ?  And where should I put that Quiet command in the code ?  Anywhere ?

Comment: no, it, like any function, applies to the expression, wrapped in it. If it is `NumberForm` poses problem than `Quiet@NumberForm[...]`. Or whatever. You may prevent all messages by `Quiet@Manipulate[...]`.

Comment: Ah, cool !  I'm learning a new Mma trick each day !  8-)  I'll try the Quiet command to manipulate to see if it solves my problem.

Comment: I just tried the Quiet at several places, and it doesn't prevent the warning messages.  I used it at the Manipulate, and seperately at all the **NumberForm** calls.  I'll try to make a MWE.

Comment: I made a MWE but I'm unable to reproduce the warnings with it.

Comment: make `Off[NumberForm::sigz]`. `Off` is another option to turn of warnings. See [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/37368/how-to-switch-off-all-messages).

Comment: I just replicated the issue with a simple MWE.  I'm updating my question.

Comment: Where and how do I use that command ?  This is new to me.

Comment: I just added that command at the start of the code, and it appears to work.  However, the number output may turn out to be in scientific notation (something like 5.00000 X 10^7), and the info is garbled on the graphic, because of the exponent.  What should I do there ?

Comment: the problem with `Quiet` might be a bug by the way - see related [post](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20099/quiet-doesnt-work-with-findroot-when-using-brent-method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To address the issue use some `Off[NumberForm::sigz]` in `Manipulate[...]`.
It is also better to use simple `Epilog` with `Text[Row[...]` (code below):

[image]

Some code picture:
[image]

Comment: Yes, the number is badly shown at bottom of the graphics.  5.0000 X 10^7 should be aligned with the = sign, and the 7 exponent should be properly placed.  I get the same with my version.

Comment: @Cham, the problem in using `ToString`. Play around with this code: `someInfo[x_, y_] := 
 If[(0 < x < 1 && y > 1), 
  Text[Row[{"Just a test :\n\n", "r = ", 
     NumberForm[x 5.00000*10^7, {5, 4}], " km"}], {5, -1.25}], {}]`

Comment: Using the combination **Manipulate[Off[NumberForm::sigz];**... and **NumberForm[x/(1 - x^2), {5, 4},ExponentFunction->(Null&)]]** appears to solve all issues.

Comment: garej, the problem with your suggestion (to use Row[{"... ) is that I need to put some parts like **Subscript[\[ScriptCapitalJ], c]**, so I need to use the **StringJoin** and **ToString** commands.  Unless there's another way that I don't know.

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot for all the help, garej, it's really appreciated !  Here's what I'm achieving with the **JoinString** command : http://postimg.org/image/xmai9uhtx/  Could you do this with the **Row** command ?

Comment: garej, one more question :  how do you change the font and size of the text, in your Row comand ?

Comment: I found it !  For **Row**, you add **BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 12, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"}** for example, as an option.  It works great, and the code is less messy that using all the **StringJoin**.  I think I'm having it right now, finally !  Geez, Mathematica isn't obvious to use...