# FindFaces: how to improve the results of the face recognition feature

Tags: image-processing

In *Mathematica 9*, the `FindFaces` command offers an easy way to detect faces. In some experiments, I've been getting reasonable results, but I'd like to know if there are ways to improve the success rate.

As with the online help example, I thought the 1927 Solvay Conference photograph was a good place to start. You can find it on the Wikimedia [here](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6e/Solvay_conference_1927.jpg), at 3000 by 2171 pixels.

```
solvay = Import["http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6e/Solvay_conference_1927.jpg"];
faces = FindFaces[solvay]
```

which returns a list of rectangles:

```
{{{81.5, 1105.5}, {262.5, 1286.5}}, {{133.5, 1038.5}, {231.5, 1136.5}}, ...
```

Using these to chop out some passport photographs:

```
passports = ImageTrim[solvay, #] & /@ faces
```

gives this:

[image: solvay faces]

I can get rid of the images that are too large by using the optional minimum and maximum sizes:

```
faces1 = FindFaces[solvay, {85, 130}];
passports1 = ImageTrim[solvay, #] & /@ faces1
```

But it's still not perfect. (The online help example seems to miss more people than I do, but there are no false positives, unlike my interesting collection of masonry people.

How would I improve these results? Is `Mathematica`'s built-in function capable of better results, or is it just, well, a toy?

Comment: I love the first one

Comment: @belisarius angry physicist? :)

Comment: The false positives appear to be very sensitive to denoising. If you run, say, a TotalVariationFilter on the image, many of the false positives go away and new false positive appear (the new ones are all different for Method -> "Gaussian", "Laplacian", or "Poisson"). The obvious solution: apply a bunch of different filters to the image, do FindFaces on the results, and keep the faces that appear in all of them. :)

Comment: Mr. Angry Physicist never goes away though. I think he looks like Freud.

Comment: For those that might enjoy it: http://i.imgur.com/M5tCc.jpg

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The built-in function is certainly capable of *different* results, using the hidden options `"TrainingFile"` and `"ScaleDecreaseFraction"`.

Under the hood, *Mathematica* uses [OpenCV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCV) for face detection. The algorithm is controlled by information contained in an XML file, the one supplied with *Mathematica* is located here:

```
FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory,
 "SystemFiles", "Data", "Haarcacades", "frontalface.xml"}]
```

You can download other "trained classifiers" from the OpenCV GitHub repository [here](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/tree/master/data/haarcascades).

As well as alternative classifiers for faces, there are also files for detecting various other features, such as eyes, ears, upperbody and so on. These files can be supplied to `FindFaces` with the `"TrainingFile"` option. Here are a couple of examples (I have copied the XML files from GitHub into my `$UserDocumentsDirectory`):

```
findfeatures[image_, file_, opts___] := Module[{features},
  features = FindFaces[image, 
    {"TrainingFile" -> FileNameJoin[{$UserDocumentsDirectory, file}], opts}];
  Show[image, Graphics[{EdgeForm[{Cyan, Thick}], Opacity[0], Rectangle @@@ features}]]]
```

Find Lena's eyes:

```
findfeatures[ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}], "haarcascade_mcs_eyepair_big.xml"]
```

[image]

Find Girl3's nose:

```
findfeatures[ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Girl3"}], "haarcascade_mcs_nose.xml"]
```

[image]

The results often include false positives, they can sometimes be improved with the `"ScaleDecreaseFraction"` option, which takes a real number between 0 and 1. Unfortunately I don't understand exactly what this option does, so it is a case of trial and error to find a good value.

For example, finding Tiffany's eyes worked well with a value of 0.7 (note that I'm using a classifier for individual eyes here, as opposed to the "eye pair" I used on Lena):

```
findfeatures[ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Tiffany"}], "haarcascade_eye.xml",
  "ScaleDecreaseFraction" -> 0.7]
```

[image]

The best I could do with the Solvay Conference image was this:

```
findfeatures[solvay, "haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml", 
  "ScaleDecreaseFraction" -> 0.2]
```

[image]

There are no false positives, but the algorithm has failed to find Lorentz (possibly because of the beard?)

I suspect, as Rahul Narain commented, to get perfect results you would have to run the algorithm several times with different parameters and/or image pre-processing, and then do some analysis of the results.

Comment: Excellent spelunking!

Comment: Fascinating! There's much functionality hidden away, for some reason.

Comment: @cormullion, yep. I'm sure WRI have their reasons for it, but it can be quite frustrating sometimes.

Comment: @SimonWoods any suggestion on how to generate these training xml files ? For example if I wanted to create a beard/moustache training set ?

Comment: @lalmei, no idea at all! Probably best to start at the OpenCV website (linked in this answer) or google "OpenCV beard detection" or similar.

Comment: Lorentz is surely contracted. +1 of course.

Comment: We need you and other experts here to give a course on Mathematica spelunking.  Nice work.  I note to other viewers, the OpenCV link referenced above no longer works.

Comment: @bobthechemist, here is the complete course: Use [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1742/862), plus trial and error ;-)

Comment: @SimonWoods Silly me for not having searched "how to spelunk" as that's the first Q&A returned.

Comment: Why I use "TraningFile",mma shut down?     FindFaces[img, 
 "TrainingFile" -> 
  "F:\\mathematica \
9\\SystemFiles\\Data\\Haarcacades\\frontalface.xml"]

Comment: @user15961, I'm not sure. Does the file exist at that location?

Comment: yes,it exist there.And it show "No more memory available...".I want use Trace to print,and I found "TrainingFile" occurs 18 times,and everytime it shows "Automatic".Have some methods to show what my mathematica use "trainingFile"->"?"  ? ps.FindFaces[img] works well

Comment: Yes,it works well only use FindFaces[img].Maybe my English is incomprehensible...may be my English is poor

Comment: @user15961, what does this give? ``Cases[DownValues @ Image`PatternRecognitionDump`ffOpenCV, _FileNameJoin, -1]``

Comment: @user15961, it's very strange. I'm sorry but I have no clue what could be causing it! There should be no difference between using the Automatic option and explicitly specifying the same file.

Comment: it gives                                 {"F:\\mathematica 9\\SystemFiles\\Data\\Haarcacades\\frontalface.xml"};but if a use FindFaces[i, 
 "TrainingFile" -> 
  "F:\\mathematica \
9\\SystemFiles\\Data\\Haarcacades\\frontalface.xml"] mma shut down.So is it a bug?

Comment: I try this method on my classmate's computer.successful! But in mine,it shut down