# Kernel shut down when use FindFaces with LBP Cascades

Tags: bugs, image-processing, machine-learning

I found Mathematica can use OpenCV to improve face recognition in [FindFaces: how to improve the results of the face recognition feature](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16686/findfaces-how-to-improve-the-results-of-the-face-recognition-feature).

But I tried this way and the kernel crashed.

```
URLDownload["https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nagadomi/lbpcascade_animeface/master/lbpcascade_animeface.xml","lbpcascade_animeface.xml"];
FindFaces[img,"Image","TrainingFile" ->"lbpcascade_animeface.xml"]
```

Then I found that even using the files in the distribution will still cause kernel shut down.

[image]

Notice that the number disappears, the code highlight disappears, the calculation does not continue, the kernel has stopped working at this time.

Can someone else reproduce this situation, is this a bug?

Comment: I observe the same behaviour ("11.3.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (March 7, 2018)")

Comment: Same on 11.3.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (March 7, 2018)

Comment: This should be reported to Wolfram Support, please share then the case number so other people get a chance to follow up when new versions are released.

Comment: @rhermans Re: [CASE:4169085] I was able to reproduce the crash, however TrainingFile is not documented and not supported.

Comment: Seems undocumented functions cannot get support.

Comment: Wolfram didn't care about a crash just because the function was not documented?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed in Version 12.

[image]

```
animeface = FindFaces[#,
    "Method" -> "LocalBinaryPatterns",
    "TrainingFile" -> "lbpcascade_animeface.xml",
    AcceptanceThreshold -> 0.1,
    "ScaleDecreaseFraction" -> 1
]&;
HighlightImage[img, {"Boundary", Green, animeface[#]&}]
```

Remark:

- `Method` must be set
- `` Image`HumanDump`FindFacesHiddenOptions ``

Comment: That's very interesting. Is there a repository somewhere for LBP xml files like the one you used?

Comment: @CarlLange, [OpenCV](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/tree/master/data/lbpcascades) maintained some. Or search `lbpcascade` in google or github.

Answer (score 4):

I launch Mathematica from a bash shell under linux and get the following error message when the kernel crashes:

```
OpenCV Error: Unspecified error (The node does not represent a user object (unknown type?)) in cvRead, file /home/usr0/matthias/tmp/opencv/opencv-3.1.0/modules/core/src/persistence.cpp, line 4976
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
what():  /home/usr0/matthias/tmp/opencv/opencv-3.1.0/modules/core/src/persistence.cpp:4976: error: (-2) The node does not represent a user object (unknown type?) in function cvRead
```

I guess that you have triggered an error in OpenCV.

Comment: Nice find. Still, Mathematica should be resilient to errors in external calls. This should be reported to Wolfram Support.