# How can I access the internal function that plots a molecule from a formatted XYZ file?

Tags: graphics3d, chemistry

*Mathematica* has the ability to plot a molecule using the data contained in an [XYZ file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XYZ_file_format).  This is a simple text file, of which [this](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8fde18207e8abc7b770c) is an example.

The molecule is plotted using the `Import` command.  Entering this:

```
Import["https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8fde18207e8abc7b770c/raw/8491d99e7fec7cc989fe38548319e09d6910ba02/form_MO_28", "XYZ"]
```

gives this as the output:

[image: a molecule]

I've been able to put this together with orbital plots, with results like this:

[image: molecule + orbital plot]

But I can only show other plots alongside the molecule plot, I can't modify the molecule.  For example, I'd like to make the tubes forming the bonds smaller in diameter.  As it is, the plots don't show if there is a single, double, or triple bond.

Somewhere in *Mathematica*, there must be a function which takes as its argument the XYZ text and returns the molecule plot.  If I could see that function, I could modify it accordingly.

Any clue on how to access this function?  The documentation for this feature is minimal.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To answer the question about accessing the function that does the plotting: the hints are [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/DevelopingAnImportConverter.html) and in the `SystemFiles/Formats/XYZ` directory.

```
In[20]:= stream = OpenRead["ExampleData/caffeine.xyz"]

Out[20]= InputStream["ExampleData/caffeine.xyz", 194]

In[22]:= data = System`Convert`XYZDump`ImportXYZ[stream]

Out[22]= {"VertexTypes" -> {"H", "N", "C", "N", "C", "C", "C", "N", 
   "O", "C", "O", "H", "C", "H", "H", "H", "H", "H", "C", "C", "N", 
   "H", "H", "H"}, 
 "VertexCoordinates" -> {{-338.041, -112.724, 
    57.3304}, {96.683, -107.374, -81.9823}, {5.67293, 85.2719, 
    39.2316}, {-137.517, -102.122, -5.70552}, {-126.15, 25.9071, 
    52.3414}, {-30.6834, -168.363, -71.6934}, {113.942, 
    18.7412, -27.009}, {56.0263, 208.391, 
    82.5159}, {-49.268, -281.806, -120.947}, {-263.281, -173.04, \
-0.60953}, {-223.013, 79.8862, 108.997}, {254.97, 297.35, 
    62.2959}, {205.274, -173.609, -149.313}, {-248.077, -272.695, 
    48.8263}, {-300.89, -190.253, -104.98}, {291.761, -184.815, \
-78.5787}, {237.879, -112.119, -237.437}, {171.899, -274.899, \
-184.392}, {-15.1845, 309.7, 153.483}, {189.341, 211.812, 
    41.9319}, {228.613, 99.6844, -24.403}, {-16.8703, 404.366, 
    93.0109}, {35.3532, 329.791, 251.777}, {-120.745, 275.376, 
    172.03}}}
```

This showed the format the next function expects:

```
In[23]:= ImportExport`MoleculePlot3D[data]

Out[23]= --Graphics--
```

To get more hints about the available rendering options, check the XYZ format documentation and take a look at the option definition for `` Graphics`MoleculePlotDump`iMoleculePlot3D ``:

```
Options[iMoleculePlot3D] :=
 Flatten[{"Rendering" -> Automatic, "AtomScaling" -> Automatic, 
  ColorRules -> Automatic, "DrawBonds" -> Automatic, 
  "DrawAtoms" -> Automatic, "InferBonds" -> Automatic, 
  "InferBondsMinDistance" -> 40, "InferBondsTolerance" -> 25, 
  "AtomSizeRules" -> Automatic, "BondSize" -> Automatic, 
  "WireframeBonds" -> Automatic, "ImageSizeScaled" -> False, 
  Boxed -> False, ViewPoint -> Automatic, ColorFunction -> Automatic, 
  Lighting -> "Neutral", Sequence @@ Options["Graphics3D"]}]
```

If you want to do more spelunking, take a look at the [Spelunking package](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/15948/12).

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working with Version 10. Any ideas?

Comment: @paw Sorry, not right away, and I'll be away from this site for a while starting today ... Try using `Information` or `Names` to see if those symbols changed context in v10.

Comment: Ok, I'll try my best and add an answer if I find a solution.

Answer (score 4):

To add a little to [Szabolcs's](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/12/szabolcs) answer, one can get the bonds with

```
Graphics`MoleculePlotDump`ElementsToBonds
```

Example:

```
mol = Import["ExampleData/Caffeine.xyz", "Rules"]; 
Graphics`MoleculePlotDump`ElementsToBonds[mol]
(*
  {1 -> 10, 2 -> 7, 2 -> 6, 2 -> 13, 3 -> 8, 3 -> 7, 3 -> 5, 4 -> 5,  4 -> 6,
   4 -> 10, 5 -> 11, 6 -> 9, 7 -> 21, 8 -> 20, 8 -> 19,  10 -> 15, 10 -> 14,
   12 -> 20, 13 -> 18, 13 -> 16, 13 -> 17, 19 -> 23, 19 -> 22, 19 -> 24, 20 -> 21}
*)
```

We can turn it into a `Graph`:

```
g = Graph[
   Range @ Length["VertexTypes" /. mol],
   UndirectedEdge @@@ Graphics`MoleculePlotDump`ElementsToBonds[mol]
   ];
```

We can construct a 3D plot of the molecule with `GraphPlot3D`:

```
With[{types = "VertexTypes" /. mol},
 GraphPlot3D[
  g,
  VertexCoordinateRules -> 
   MapThread[Rule, {Range@Length@#, #} &["VertexCoordinates" /. mol]],
   VertexRenderingFunction -> ({Specularity[GrayLevel[1], 100], 
      ColorData["Atoms"]@types[[#2]], Sphere[#1, Scaled[0.025]]} &),
  EdgeRenderingFunction -> ({Specularity[GrayLevel[1], 100], 
      EdgeForm[], ColorData["Atoms"]@types[[First@#2]], 
      Cylinder[{First[#1], Mean[#1]}, Scaled[0.015]], 
      ColorData["Atoms"]@types[[Last@#2]], 
      Cylinder[{Last[#1], Mean[#1]}, Scaled[0.015]]} &)
  ]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]