# MoleculePlot3D - how to replace spheres?

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, chemistry

How to replace the spheres in the plot with other 3d figures, say "N" with a Cylinder, "O" with a Cuboid, and "H" with a sphere.

```
MoleculePlot3D[Molecule["Serine"], ColorRules -> {"H" -> Red, "O" -> Blue, "N" -> Green}]
```

Comment: I have been thinking that an option to do this would be useful, something equivalent to the [`VertexShapeFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VertexShapeFunction.html) used by `Graph`, but for atoms.  If this is something you would find useful also you could submit feedback to that effect (in product go to Help->Give feedback).

Answer (score 13):

> How to replace the spheres in the plot with other 3d figures, say "N" with a Cylinder, "O" with a Cuboid, and "H" with a sphere.

This answer takes points from the `GraphicsComplex` object generated by `MoleculePlot3D` and makes related graphics objects replacements.

The colors are used to identify the atoms. (That is probably a weak way to identify, but it works...)

```
gr = MoleculePlot3D[Molecule["Serine"], 
   ColorRules -> {"H" -> Red, "O" -> Blue, "N" -> Green}];
gr
```

[image]

```
{grPoints, grSpec} =  Cases[gr[[1]], GraphicsComplex[p_, s___] :> {p, s}][[1]];
```

Define the replacement functions:

```
Clear[SphereToCuboid];
SphereToCuboid[s_Sphere] := 
  Map[Cuboid[# - {1, 1, 1}*s[[2]], # + {1, 1, 1}*s[[2]]] &, s[[1]]];
SphereToCuboid[{col_RGBColor, s_Sphere}] := 
  Map[{col, #} &, Flatten@List@SphereToCuboid[s]];

Clear[SphereToCylinder]
SphereToCylinder[s_Sphere, factor_ : 1.2] := 
  Map[Cylinder[{# - {0, 0, 1}*s[[2]], # + {0, 0, 1}*s[[2]]}, 
     factor*s[[2]]] &, s[[1]]];
SphereToCylinder[{col_RGBColor, s_Sphere}, factor_ : 1.2] := 
  Map[{col, #} &, Flatten@List@SphereToCylinder[s, factor]];

Clear[SphereToSphere]
SphereToSphere[s_Sphere, factor_ : 1.6] := 
  Map[Sphere[#, factor*s[[2]]] &, s[[1]]];
SphereToSphere[{col_RGBColor, s_Sphere}, factor_ : 1.6] := 
  Map[{col, #} &, Flatten@List@SphereToSphere[s, factor]];

Clear[SphereToPolyhedron]
SphereToPolyhedron[s_Sphere, pspec_, factor_ : 1.2] := 
  Map[Scale[
     GeometricTransformation[PolyhedronData[pspec, "GraphicsComplex"],
       TranslationTransform[#]], factor*s[[2]]] &, s[[1]]];
SphereToPolyhedron[{col_RGBColor, s_Sphere}, pspec_, factor : 1.2] := 
  Map[{col, #} &, Flatten@List@SphereToPolyhedron[s, pspec, factor]];
```

(`SphereToSphere` was defined for completeness.)

Make the replacement (using `Pink` for "N" instead of `Red`):

```
Graphics3D[gr[[1]] /. {
   (x : {Blue, Sphere[ps : {_?IntegerQ ..}, args___]}) :> {Blue, 
     SphereToCuboid[Sphere[grPoints[[ps]], args]]},
   (x : {Green, Sphere[ps : {_?IntegerQ ..}, args___]}) :> {Green, 
     SphereToCylinder[Sphere[grPoints[[ps]], args]]},
   (x : {Red, Sphere[ps : {_?IntegerQ ..}, args___]}) :> {Pink, 
     SphereToSphere[Sphere[grPoints[[ps]], args]]}
   }]
```

[image]

---

> How could I replace not with a cylinder, but like something more complex like this: `Graphics3D[{Red, Lighting -> "Neutral", Opacity[.9], PolyhedronData["SnubDodecahedron", "GraphicsComplex"]}, Boxed -> False]`

```
Graphics3D[gr[[1]] /. {
   (x : {Blue, Sphere[ps : {_?IntegerQ ..}, args___]}) :> {Blue, 
     SphereToCuboid[Sphere[grPoints[[ps]], args]]},
   (x : {Green, Sphere[ps : {_?IntegerQ ..}, args___]}) :> {Green, 
     SphereToCylinder[Sphere[grPoints[[ps]], args]]},
   (x : {Red, Sphere[ps : {_?IntegerQ ..}, args___]}) :> {Pink, 
     SphereToPolyhedron[Sphere[grPoints[[ps]], args], 
      "SnubDodecahedron", 1]}
   }]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, quite complicated. How could I replace not with a cylinder, but like something more complex like this: Graphics3D[{Red, Lighting -> "Neutral", Opacity[.9], 
  PolyhedronData["SnubDodecahedron", "GraphicsComplex"]}, 
 Boxed -> False]

Comment: +1 for beating @jason-b to a `MoleculePlot` question!

Comment: @bobthechemist Thanks! (This reminds me that I should be doing more Chemistry with WL...)

Comment: @Mikayel See my update -- I am only using polyhedron specifications, though. (Maybe with `Inset` certain `Graphics3D` objects with special lighting and color settings can be used, but I do not plan to investigate that...)

Answer (score 4):

```
m = Molecule["Serine"];

atoms = m["AtomList"][[All, 1]];

atomCoords = m["AtomCoordinates"]["Magnitudes"];
```

Specify desired colors and primitives for the attoms:

```
colorRules = {"H" -> Red, "O" -> Blue, "N" -> Green, _ -> RGBColor[.4, .4, .4]};

newPrimsRules = {"H" -> Cuboid[-{1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}], "N" -> Cylinder[], 
      "O" -> PolyhedronData["Dodecahedron"][[1]], _ -> Sphere[]};
```

First, plot `m` without the atoms using the option `PlotTheme -> "Tubes"`

```
mp1 = MoleculePlot3D[m, ColorRules -> colorRules , PlotTheme -> "Tubes"]
```

[image]

or using the option `Method -> {"DrawAtoms" -> False}`:

```
mp1 = MoleculePlot3D[m, ColorRules -> colorRules , Method -> {"DrawAtoms" -> False}]
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

Then use `Graphics3D` or `Graph3D` or `BubbleChart3D` to render the atoms and show the result with `mp1`:

### Graphics3D

```
shapes = MapThread[{#, Translate[Scale[#2, 1/3], #3 ]} &, 
    {Replace[atoms, colorRules, 1], Replace[atoms, newPrimsRules, 1], atomCoords}]; 

Show[mp1, Graphics3D[shapes]]
```

[image]

### Graph3D

```
vshapes = Replace[atoms, newPrimsRules, 1];

g3d = Graph3D[Range @ m["AtomCount"], {}, 
   VertexCoordinates -> atomCoords, 
   VertexStyle -> {v_ :> (atoms[[v]] /. colorRules)}, 
   VertexSize -> .5,
   VertexShapeFunction -> (Translate[Scale[vshapes[[#2]], #3], # ] &)];

Show[mp1, g3d]
```

[image]

### BubbleChart3D

```
 bcdata = Append[#, 1] -> #2 & @@@ Transpose[{atomCoords, vshapes}];
 
 bc3d = BubbleChart3D[bcdata, 
    ChartStyle -> Replace[atoms, colorRules, 1],
    ChartElementFunction -> (Translate[Scale[#3[[1]], 1/4], Most @ #2] &)];

 Show[mp1, bc3d]
```

[image]

Using built-in `ChartElementFunction`s:

```
bcdatab = Append[#, 1] -> #2 & @@@ Transpose[{atomCoords, atoms}];

cElementRules = {"H" -> "MarkerBubble3D", "O" -> "SquareWaveCube",
    "N" -> "TriangleWaveCube", _ -> "ProfileCube"};

 bc3db = BubbleChart3D[bcdatab, 
    ChartStyle -> Replace[atoms, colorRules, 1],
    BubbleSizes -> {.075, .075},
    ChartElementFunction -> (ChartElementData[#3[[1]] /. cElementRules ][##] &)];

 Show[mp1, bc3db]
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice, especially using `BubbleChart3D`!

Answer (score 2):

This is duplicate to [how can i access the internal function that plots a molecule from a formatted xy](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/24045/how-can-i-access-the-internal-function-that-plots-a-molecule-from-a-formatted-xy/24047#24047). This is unfortunately outdated.

```
mole = Import["ExampleData/Caffeine.xyz", "Rules"]
```

[image]

This is a list of 4 component. First is the Graphics3D with which [@anton-antonov](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/34008/anton-antonov) deals so nicely.

I present this solution:

```
Quiet[With[{types = "VertexTypes" /. mole}, 
  GraphPlot3D[g, 
   VertexCoordinates -> 
    MapThread[
      Rule, {Range@Length@#, #} &["VertexCoordinates" /. mole]][[All, 
      2, 1, 1]], 
   VertexShapeFunction -> ({Specularity[GrayLevel[1], 100], 
       ColorData["Atoms"]@types[[#2]], Cube[#1, 0.25]} &), 
   EdgeRenderingFunction -> ({Specularity[GrayLevel[1], 100], 
       EdgeForm[], ColorData["Atoms"]@types[[First@#2]], 
       Cylinder[{First[#1], Mean[#1]}, Scaled[0.015]], 
       ColorData["Atoms"]@types[[Last@#2]], 
       Cylinder[{Last[#1], Mean[#1]}, Scaled[0.015]]} &)]]]
```

[image: Cube as a primitives from a generic approaches]

This is better in performance because is does not do things twice and an expensive replace. OK. These are Cube all over.

So my solution is straightforward and as flexible as the other one:

```
g = MoleculeGraph[ mole[[2, 2]]]

Quiet[With[{types = "VertexTypes" /. mole}, 
  GraphPlot3D[g, 
   VertexCoordinates -> 
    MapThread[
      Rule, {Range@Length@#, #} &["VertexCoordinates" /. mole]][[All, 
      2, 1, 1]], 
   VertexShapeFunction -> ({Specularity[GrayLevel[1], 100], 
       ColorData["Atoms"]@types[[#2]], 
       Which[types[[#2]] === "N", 
        Cylinder[{#1, #1 + {0, 0, 1}}, 0.15], types[[#2]] === "H", 
        Sphere[#1, Scaled[0.025]], types[[#2]] === "O", 
        Cube[#1, 0.35], Not[MemberQ[types[[#2]], {"N", "H", "O"}]], 
        Sphere[#1, Scaled[0.025]]]} &), 
   EdgeRenderingFunction -> ({Specularity[GrayLevel[1], 100], 
       EdgeForm[], ColorData["Atoms"]@types[[First@#2]], 
       Cylinder[{First[#1], Mean[#1]}, Scaled[0.015]], 
       ColorData["Atoms"]@types[[Last@#2]], 
       Cylinder[{Last[#1], Mean[#1]}, Scaled[0.015]]} &)]]]
```

[image: "N" with a Cylinder, "O" with a Cuboid, and "H" with a sphere.]

This is a solution matched to the present day version of Mathematica, I use V12.0.0, and how it treats [`Molecules`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Molecule.html) and the knowledge built-in about chemistry molecules. This is experimental as the documentation page states. I make use of the triple structure and of [GraphPlot3D](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GraphPlot3D.html) which is updated in V12.0.0.

The step ahead from the referenced solution is [`MoleculeGraph`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MoleculeGraph.html). New is V12.0.0 too. So this solution is state-of-the-art in Mathematica and Wolfram Language. Have fun with the brand new soltuion.

Answer (score 0):

Post-process to replace `Sphere`s with desired primitives:

```
ClearAll[coordsAssoc, postProcess]

coordsAssoc[mol_] := GroupBy[Transpose[{mol["AtomList"][[All, 1]], 
   mol["AtomCoordinates"]["Magnitudes"]}], First -> Last];

postProcess[mol_, newprimitives_] := ReplaceAll[
  Flatten[newprimitives /. HoldPattern[a_ -> p_] :>
  (Sphere[#, _] :> Translate[Scale[p, 1/3], #] & /@ coordsAssoc[mol][a])]][Normal@#]&
```

***Examples:***

```
m = Molecule["Serine"];

primitives = {"H" -> Cuboid[-{1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}], "N" -> Cylinder[], 
         "O" -> PolyhedronData["Dodecahedron"][[1]]};
      
postProcess[m, primitives]@
 MoleculePlot3D[m, ColorRules -> {"H" -> Red, "O" -> Blue, "N" -> Green}]
```

[image]

```
m2 = Molecule["Caffeine"];

postProcess[m2, primitives]@
 MoleculePlot3D[m2, ColorRules -> {"H" -> Red, "O" -> Blue, "N" -> Green}]
```

[image]

We can use any 3D primitive (centered at the origin):

```
primitives2 = {"H" -> ChartElementData["MarkerBubble3D"][##], 
  "O" -> ChartElementData["SquareWaveCube", "RadialAmplitude" -> .4][##],
  "N" -> ChartElementData["PolyhedronBubble3D", 
     "Polyhedron" -> "Dodecahedron"][##]} &[{{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, {0, 0, 0}];

postProcess[m2, primitives2]@
 MoleculePlot3D[m2, ColorRules -> {"H" -> Red, "O" -> Blue, "N" -> Green}]
```

[image]