# DownValues for Built-in Functions

Tags: functional-style, downvalues

N.B. I have bitten the bullet, and I am going through Leonid Shifrin's "Mathematica Programming: An Advanced Introduction." (Which needs no introduction in this forum)

One question I have: could one establish that a symbol has a built-in rules, based on DownValues or related functions?

For example:

```
Unprotect[Sin]
Sin[x_Integer] := Sin[N[x]]
Protect[Sin]

Sin[1]
(* 0.841471 *)
DownValues[Sin]
(* HoldPattern[Sin[x_Integer]] :> Sin[N[x]] *)
```

Hey, where are the built-in rules for Sin?

Comment: Built-in rules for system functions may indeed have `DownValues`, `SubValues` etc, but they are not seen and not accessible from the top level. You may indirectly interact with them (and possibly change their behavior) using `Block`, and you can also see them in action sometimes when tracing evaluation with `TraceInternal -> True`, but this seems to be as much as one can say about them from the top-level. Some functions also do have some number of top-level rules - those usually have the `ReadProtected` attribute set. You can see those rules if you remove the attribute.

Comment: @Leonid So the fact that no DownValues (or other definitions) are visible does not necessarily mean that the function is not fully implemented in Mathematica then?  I was never sure about this point.  (Not that it makes much practical difference for me.)

Comment: @Szabolcs I believe this is true. In general, built-in functions may have both lower-level (inaccessible) and top-level definitions.

Comment: Is that acceptable duplicate? http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1742/5478