# Why doesn't FrameTicks work with Histogram?

Tags: version-9, histograms, ticks

An example:

```
Histogram[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], 1000],
 PlotRangePadding -> 0,
 Frame -> True,
 FrameTicks -> {{{0, 0}}, {}}]
```

I expected this to produce a histogram without ticks. However:

[image: Histogram with incorrect ticks]

Meanwhile, if I use the same tick specification with `Plot`:

```
Plot[PDF[NormalDistribution[], x], {x, -\[Pi], \[Pi]},
 PlotRangePadding -> 0,
 Frame -> True,
 FrameTicks -> {{{0, 0}}, {}}]
```

[image: Plot with correct ticks]

Comment: Is `FrameTicks->None` what you want?

Comment: @ssch Thanks, but this was just an illustration that it's not working as I expected it to. I do actually want to provide my own ticks!

Comment: When you specify the `FrameTicks`, as opposed to empty lists, does it work? If not, could you post your tick specification?

Comment: I've updated my example to make it less ambiguous. The tick specification works with `Plot` (and `ListPlot`, and all their variants), but not with `Histogram`.

Comment: I think you're tick specification is incorrect. There is some ambiguity there from older forms of `FrameTicks` when `Histogram` wasn't yet present. So, it only got the newer form. According to the [docs](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FrameTicks.html), `FrameTicks` accepts specifications of the form `{{left, right}, {bottom, top}}`, so you're looking for `FrameTicks -> {{{},{}}, {{},{}}}`.

Comment: @rcollyer that looks to be the case. [Spelunking](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1742/what-is-the-most-convenient-way-to-read-definitions-of-in-memory-symbols-when-we) `Histogram` shows this row, where `frameticks` is the option value: `If[! MatchQ[frameticks, {{_, _}, {_, _}}], 
  frameticks = ({{#1, #1}, {#1, #1}} &)[frameticks]];` And since original specification doesn't match it gets turned into some ungodly `{{{{}, {}}, {{}, {}}}, {{{}, {}}, {{}, {}}}}` which gets thrown out later and replaced with Automatic ticks because it is not Visualization\`Utilities\`FrameTicksQ

Comment: @rcollyer You're quite right! I should've read the documentation more carefully. If you post it as an answer, I'll accept it :-)

Comment: @WillVousden under most circumstances, I'd vote to close this as it was a mis-reading of the documentation. However, as both forms are still allowed for some plots, I can see where others would be confused.

Comment: FYI: your code as shown produces no tick marks in Version 7 on Windows, but produces an error (pink box).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The [`FrameTicks`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FrameTicks.html) specification changed in v6. Previously, the form

```
{right, bottom, left, top}
```

was used, but in v6, it was changed to

```
{{left, right}, {bottom, top}}
```

To maintain compatibility between the versions, the older form is still allowed for the older plots. But, quite a few plots were added since that point (e.g. [`Histogram`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Histogram.html) was added in v7), and they only use the newer form. To achieve what your looking for without setting

```
FrameTicks -> None
```

you need to use this

```
FrameTicks -> {{{(*left*)}, {(*right*)}}, {{(*bottom*)}, {(*top*)}}}
```