# ListPolarPlot not showing full plot range even with PlotRange -> All

Tags: plotting, bugs, version-8

**Bug introduced in 8.0 and fixed in 9.0**

---

I have a list of data `dpdOt` (given below) with associated angular coordinates `thetaplot`, which when plotted using

```
    thetaplot = Table[tt,{tt,0,2*Pi,2*Pi/300}]
    ListPlot[Transpose[{thetaplot/Pi 180, dpdOt}], Joined -> True, PlotRange -> All]
```

looks like this:

[image: ListPlot]

However, I'd rather see this plotted as a `ListPolarPlot`, but I am having trouble with `PlotRange`. For example, when I use the command

```
    ListPolarPlot[Transpose[{thetaplot, dpdOt}], 
      Joined -> True, PolarAxes -> True, 
      PolarTicks -> {"Degrees", Automatic}, 
      PolarGridLines -> True, PlotRange -> All]
```

I get the following plot:

[image: ListPolarPlot]

which is obviously not plotting the full data range. If I try and manually set  `PlotRange -> 1.5`, *Mathematica* merely gives me a zoomed out version of the same polar plot:

[image]

Does anybody have any idea how I can get *Mathematica* to show the full dataset on my polar plot?

The dataset is:

```
    dpdOt = {0.`, 0.009554081538201524`, 0.03657921246993372`,  0.07645719594918586`, 0.1224134613324866`, 0.16671965853831489`,  0.2020509236272155`, 0.22274769290832974`, 0.22575257105691635`,  0.21105662334588893`, 0.18158393497377667`, 0.14254991938921568`,   0.10042704400882534`, 0.06172261938230206`, 0.03180381202988293`,   0.013989865520678359`, 0.009074375607003422`, 0.015353199348562318`,   0.029133703291304467`, 0.045608259290746044`,  0.059907143344449666`, 0.06811602801815318`, 0.06805619079404875`,   0.05967798355792369`, 0.044998917623994925`, 0.027610426330823622`,   0.011863439428043385`, 0.001905442213411619`,  0.0007687312281260307`, 0.009696350336090554`,   0.027841942524898654`, 0.05240297090682485`, 0.07915899837109333`,   0.10330545634013048`, 0.12041455169350666`, 0.1273300195707255`,   0.12281593359315725`, 0.10782877955797118`, 0.08535664034364425`,   0.0598548826381265`, 0.0363874297112553`, 0.01964103546890816`,   0.013005632519217386`, 0.017901837073488084`, 0.03348933529492066`,   0.05681622331866217`, 0.08338356368455244`, 0.10801797869739073`,   0.1258838157458027`, 0.13343735028386552`, 0.12913464839968958`,   0.11375083606637912`, 0.09024321729842082`, 0.0631798709645865`,   0.03784184580594409`, 0.01917378839552386`, 0.010791123900980252`,   0.014244303123378875`, 0.028692550180028028`, 0.051059513247240756`,   0.07664648824951373`, 0.10008465443777814`, 0.11643545518106532`,   0.12221354284042615`, 0.11611806246510771`, 0.09931464269298441`,   0.07520186774030126`, 0.048703952993848255`, 0.025233271631061455`,   0.009540102126567822`, 0.004695564232203329`, 0.011429494446618007`,   0.027971655343629113`, 0.050436902199565224`, 0.07367569127391489`,   0.0924069287274574`, 0.10238447666431386`, 0.1013374846275298`,   0.08947198471813812`, 0.06941749674225801`, 0.04562682130072883`,   0.02336179577963223`, 0.007493854962987605`, 0.00139302722259097`,   0.006161200150237524`, 0.020388179378757983`, 0.04048931173627752`,   0.06154859929889949`, 0.078472675688499`, 0.08718681535608698`,   0.08559234035384577`, 0.07405894111973076`, 0.05533354561614883`,   0.03388451541925968`, 0.014833968423679648`, 0.0027301058954676103`,   0.00045163413523262254`, 0.008507481364097463`,   0.024903075095984252`, 0.0456105809967408`, 0.06553606471258362`,   0.0797558049558498`, 0.08472607856766433`, 0.0791726455592892`,   0.06443855291626575`, 0.04419570077716716`, 0.023577636442966548`,   0.007932512944609768`, 0.001492113602352463`, 0.006281152280129452`,   0.021542228899509474`, 0.04383535778027103`, 0.06781257671823812`,   0.08750405559279266`, 0.0978210472734063`, 0.09591516988165438`,   0.08205096374581881`, 0.05974878090823095`, 0.03511799119091121`,   0.015491056611719418`, 0.007644208098589879`, 0.016008842898051462`,   0.041308975498834125`, 0.0799920698716276`, 0.12466309845912157`,   0.16551502191459355`, 0.19251813998620537`, 0.1979365219231554`,   0.1786272840234142`, 0.1375777607510681`, 0.08425397825386047`,   0.0335534665496219`, 0.0034359646772461074`, 0.011591552251972725`,  0.07173765420231708`, 0.19026282194703806`, 0.3639239411625669`,   0.5791488923696507`, 0.813221884473814`, 1.037282176743776`,   1.2207136698253551`, 1.3362119128823164`, 1.3646459208863824`,   1.2988226517976427`, 1.1454201179472137`, 0.9246567650991964`,   0.6676574849266789`, 0.4118891574170705`, 0.19539424083596366`,   0.050782165477450084`, 0.`, 0.050782165477450084`,   0.19539424083596366`, 0.4118891574170705`, 0.6676574849266789`,   0.9246567650992072`, 1.1454201179472137`, 1.2988226517976427`,   1.3646459208863868`, 1.33621191288231`, 1.2207136698253502`,   1.0372821767437717`, 0.813221884473814`, 0.5791488923696507`,   0.36392394116255933`, 0.19026282194703142`, 0.07173765420231298`,   0.011591552251971629`, 0.0034359646772465858`,   0.033553466549622345`, 0.08425397825386129`, 0.13757776075106873`,   0.17862728402341452`, 0.1979365219231553`, 0.19251813998620523`,   0.16551502191459352`, 0.12466309845912063`, 0.07999206987162717`,   0.04130897549883387`, 0.016008842898051108`, 0.00764420809858988`,   0.015491056611719966`, 0.0351179911909119`, 0.05974878090823171`,   0.08205096374581904`, 0.0959151698816545`, 0.0978210472734063`,   0.08750405559279249`, 0.06781257671823812`, 0.04383535778027089`,   0.02154222889950937`, 0.006281152280129231`, 0.001492113602352463`,   0.0079325129446096`, 0.023577636442966645`, 0.044195700777166905`,   0.06443855291626631`, 0.0791726455592894`, 0.08472607856766434`,   0.07975580495584968`, 0.06553606471258311`, 0.045610580996740674`,   0.0249030750959836`, 0.008507481364097328`, 0.00045163413523252865`,   0.0027301058954676857`, 0.014833968423680205`,   0.033884515419259915`, 0.05533354561614951`, 0.07405894111973105`,  0.08559234035384577`, 0.08718681535608702`, 0.078472675688499`,   0.061548599298899026`, 0.04048931173627754`, 0.020388179378757657`,   0.006161200150237425`, 0.0013930272225909912`,   0.007493854962987713`, 0.023361795779632825`, 0.04562682130072909`,   0.06941749674225874`, 0.08947198471813836`, 0.10133748462752992`,   0.10238447666431386`, 0.0924069287274574`, 0.07367569127391442`,   0.05043690219956524`, 0.027971655343628703`, 0.011429494446618017`,   0.0046955642322033106`, 0.009540102126567813`,   0.025233271631062083`, .04870395299384845`, 0.07520186774030205`,   0.09931464269298464`, 0.11611806246510807`, 0.12221354284042608`,   0.11643545518106499`, 0.10008465443777788`, 0.07664648824951395`,   0.05105951324724025`, 0.028692550180028028`, 0.014244303123378665`,   0.010791123900980252`, 0.01917378839552417`, 0.03784184580594409`,   0.06317987096458702`, 0.09024321729842102`, 0.11375083606637972`,   0.1291346483996897`, 0.13343735028386566`, 0.1258838157458027`,   0.1080179786973901`, 0.08338356368455223`, 0.05681622331866127`,   0.03348933529492036`, 0.017901837073488223`, 0.013005632519217408`,   0.01964103546890816`, 0.03638742971125556`, 0.059854882638126314`,   0.0853566403436447`, 0.10782877955797118`, 0.12281593359315748`,   0.1273300195707255`, 0.12041455169350626`, 0.10330545634013014`,   0.07915899837109269`, 0.052402970906824456`, 0.027841942524897894`,   0.009696350336090289`, 0.0007687312281258732`,   0.0019054422134117427`, 0.011863439428043385`, 0.02761042633082383`,   0.044998917623994925`, 0.0596779835579238`, 0.06805619079404875`,   0.06811602801815296`, 0.05990714334444941`, 0.04560825929074557`,   0.029133703291304193`, 0.015353199348562014`, 0.009074375607003374`,   0.013989865520678902`, 0.031803812029883506`, 0.06172261938230317`,   0.10042704400882617`, 0.14254991938921568`, 0.18158393497377667`,   0.21105662334588893`, 0.22575257105691635`, 0.22274769290832974`,   0.2020509236272155`, 0.16671965853831489`, 0.1224134613324866`,   0.07645719594918586`, 0.03657921246993372`, 0.009554081538201524`,   0.`}
```

Comment: I think you should show us some minimal data sample which reproduces this issue because I have no problem with my data. Also, which verion are you workin on?

Comment: Try `PlotRangePadding -> 0` and/or `ImagePadding -> 0` as well... please also include some sample data as well. I can't seem to reproduce it in some test data I created, but I do often encounter this annoyance with LPP

Comment: @rm-rf Neither PlotRangePadding or ImagePadding helps at all unfortunately. I've appended the dataset to the original post. Thanks again.

Comment: @Kuba I'm working with version 8.

Comment: There is not problem with `dpdOt` on V9 on WinXP. But does it also produce an error like `Transpose[{thetaplot, dpdOt}]` do?

Comment: @Kuba Maybe (frustratingly) it's a v8 glitch then (I'm on OsX 10.8). I don't get any errors output though.

Comment: Can't reproduce on v9, Mac OS X 10.8... [screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/P569b.png)

Comment: I would label this a v8 bug. Reproduced on mma8 win7 and not mm9 win7. Btw your code snippets are not full working (`thethaplot` is not defined and `pi` should be `Pi`)

Comment: If you are interested in fixing this problem, and if the code for `ListPolarPlot` is still top-level, you could include its definition in your question for those with dedication to debug.  Please use [the Spelunk package](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/15948/121) to extract these definitions in a readable form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is somewhat marginal but I decided to try this in Presentations. I'm fairly certain it would work in V7 or V8 because the drawing of the polar grid is completely separate from the drawing of the curves. So here is what it looks like.

```
<< Presentations`
```

I hid sample data in the notebook but it's the same as dpdOt above.

```
sampleData = <<Sample polar data>>;
```

The following first draws the polar grid and then the curve on top of it. The limits of the polar grid, and the spacings, are given by ComplexPolar expressions, which are just radius and angle.

```
Draw2D[
 {DrawPolarGrid[{ComplexPolar[0, -\[Pi]], ComplexPolar[1.5, \[Pi]], 
    ComplexPolar[0.25, \[Pi]/4], {2, 4}}, PGLabelAxis -> \[Pi]/8,
   PGAngleNumberFunction -> (phrase[Round[#/Degree // N], Spacer[2], 
       "\[Degree]"] &)],
  ListPolarDraw[sampleData, Joined -> True, PlotStyle -> Red]},
 PlotRangePadding -> 0.25,
 ImageSize -> 300]
```

[image]

The following gives a close-up of the inner portion of the curve.

```
Draw2D[
 {DrawPolarGrid[{ComplexPolar[0, -\[Pi]], ComplexPolar[0.25, \[Pi]], 
    ComplexPolar[0.05, \[Pi]/4], {2, 4}}, PGLabelAxis -> \[Pi]/8,
   PGAngleNumberFunction -> (phrase[Round[#/Degree // N], Spacer[2], 
       "\[Degree]"] &)],
  ListPolarDraw[Clip[#, {0, 0.25}] & /@ sampleData, Joined -> True, 
   PlotStyle -> Red, PlotRange -> 0.25]},
 PlotRangePadding -> 0.01,
 ImageSize -> 300]
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

So I agree with everyone. It seems to be a bug in version 8. I have managed to do a (rather ugly) work around, but it does the job. Basically I define an interpolation function based on the data:

```
    thetaplot = Table[tt,{tt,0,2*Pi,2*Pi/300}]
    interpfunc = Interpolation[Transpose[{thetaplot,dpdOt}]];
```

And then plot using the interpolation function.

```
    PolarPlot[interpfunc[tt], {tt, 0, 2*Pi}, PolarAxes -> True, PolarTicks -> {"Degrees",Automatic}, PolarGridLines -> True,  PlotRange -> All]
```

which gives me the full data range as desired:

[image]

Thanks everyone for your help. Much appreciated.

Comment: +1 for providing your own work-around.  If you are interested in a true bug-fix please see my comment above.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thanks for the fix. Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work for me in v8. I tried it on a friend's version of Mathematica (v7) and it worked fine though. :)

Comment: Pardon, what doesn't work?  I did not provide a fix (yet) but merely an illustration.  Do you mean that the `Spelunk` function (from the package linked in the comment) fails to read the definition of `ListPolarPlot`?  If that is the case make sure you have first used the function to plot something as this will pre-load the definitions from stubs.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Sorry for the confusion...I merely meant that I could reproduce your plot in v7, but not in v8. I have not tried the Spelunk function yet.

Answer (score 6):

This appears to be a bug of sorts.  Mathematica 7 produces this output for the given input:

```
ListPolarPlot[dpdOt, Joined -> True, PolarAxes -> True, 
 PolarTicks -> {"Degrees", Automatic}, PolarGridLines -> True, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

There's some clipping of the degree labels but the full range of data appears to be correctly plotted.  In whatever version you are using `All` is apparently not handled correctly for this option.

Borrowing Mike's example we can see that in v7 the behavior is more logical:

```
Pane @ ListPolarPlot[dpdOt, Joined -> True, PolarAxes -> True, 
 PolarTicks -> {"Degrees", Automatic}, PolarGridLines -> True, PlotRange -> #, 
 Frame -> True] & /@ {0.6, 3} // Column
```

[image]

[image]

One can see that the restricted range is handled correctly, and the extended range while perhaps not ideal (IMHO it should extend the grid lines as well) at least doesn't break anything.

Comment: thats interesting. The stuff I just removed was done with V8 on mac.