# Radial range in polar plot

Tags: plotting

I'm trying to make a polar plot. 
The radial range (radius of the circle) is automatically set at 1.2. I want to change this to 1. My code is:

```
PolarPlot[Abs[1/2 (E^(I t) + 1)]^2, {t, 0, 2 π}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Darker[Blue], Thick},
 PolarAxes -> True,
 BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Arial", FontSize -> 12},
 PolarTicks -> {{0, Pi/4, Pi/2, (3 Pi)/4, Pi, (5 Pi)/4, (3 Pi)/2, 
  (7 Pi)/4}, {0, .2, .4, .6, .8, 1}},
 PolarGridLines -> {{0, Pi/2, Pi, 3 Pi/2}, {0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1}}]
```

[image]

On the internet I found the command `PlotRange -> 1`, but this makes it even worse.

```
PolarPlot[Abs[1/2 (E^(I t) + 1)]^2, {t, 0, 2 π}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Darker[Blue], Thick},
 PlotRange -> 1,
 PolarAxes -> True,
 BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Arial", FontSize -> 12},
 PolarTicks -> {{0, Pi/4, Pi/2, (3 Pi)/4, Pi, (5 Pi)/4, (3 Pi)/2, 
  (7 Pi)/4}, {0, .2, .4, .6, .8, 1}},
 PolarGridLines -> {{0, Pi/2, Pi, 3 Pi/2}, {0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1}}]
```

[image]

Does anyone know how to do this?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ListPolarPlot not showing full plot range even with PlotRange -> All](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/30001/listpolarplot-not-showing-full-plot-range-even-with-plotrange-all)

Comment: Greetings Linde! To make the most of Mma.SE please **take the [tour] now**. **Help us to help you**, write an [excellent question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). [Edit](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) if improvable, show due diligence, give brief context, include **minimum** working examples of **code and data in [formatted form](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help)**. As you receive **give back**, vote and answer questions, keep the site useful, be kind, correct mistakes and share what you have learned.

Comment: This is definitely ***not*** a duplicate of [the question shrx picks](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/30001/3066) it to be a duplicate of and there is no answer for this question there.

Answer (score 10):

Use [`PolarAxesOrigin`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PolarAxesOrigin.html) like this: `PolarAxesOrigin -> {0, 1}`

```
PolarPlot[
 Abs[1/2 (E^(I t) + 1)]^2, {t, 0, 2 π}
 , PlotStyle -> {Darker[Blue], Thick}
 , PlotRange -> 1.2
 , PolarAxesOrigin -> {0, 1}
 , PolarAxes -> True
 , BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Arial", FontSize -> 12}
 , PolarTicks -> {{0, Pi/4, Pi/2, (3 Pi)/4, 
    Pi, (5 Pi)/4, (3 Pi)/2, (7 Pi)/4}, {0, .2, .4, .6, .8, 1}}
 , PolarGridLines -> {{0, Pi/2, Pi, 3 Pi/2}, {0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1}}
 ]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Or for a better fit

```
PolarPlot[
 Abs[1/2 (E^(I t) + 1)]^2, {t, 0, 2 π}
 , PlotStyle -> {Darker[Blue], Thick}
 , PlotRange -> 1.2
 , PolarAxesOrigin -> {0, 1}
 , PolarAxes -> True
 , BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Arial", FontSize -> 12}
 , PolarTicks -> {{0, Pi/4, Pi/2, (3 Pi)/4, 
    Pi, (5 Pi)/4, (3 Pi)/2, (7 Pi)/4}, {0, .2, .4, .6, .8, 1}}
 , PolarGridLines -> {{0, Pi/2, Pi, 3 Pi/2}, {0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1}}
 ]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks! That's just what I needed :)