# Import audio in uLaw format?

Tags: import, sound

How do I import a [uLaw-format audio file](http://www.fileinfo.com/extension/ulaw) into *Mathematica*? Here's an example:

- [hello-world.ulaw](http://www.ge.tt/32si9ur/v/0)

For reference, here's the same file in [wav](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAV) format:

- [hello-world.wav](http://www.ge.tt/9ppq9ur/v/0)

As I understand it, the uLaw format contains raw [µ-law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%9C-law_algorithm) audio data. In this respect, it should be very similar (or identical) to [AU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Au_file_format), which [*Mathematica* supports](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/format/AU.html), except there is no header.

I have tried:

```
Import["hello-world.ulaw", "AU"]
```

but *Mathematica* returns:

```
Import::fmterr: Cannot import data as AU/SND format.
```

From the documentation, it looks like there is probably some combination of parameters and options that will work, but the `Import`/`Export` documentation doesn't go into much detail on how to actually use the various available options. (Or at least, not in a way that makes sense to me!)

Comment: You can import the data in the file with `BinaryReadList["hello-world.uLaw"]`. This gives a long list of values (between 2 and 255). Normally one would turn these into sound with `SampledSoundList` but it does not lead to an intelligible sound in this case, so the data must be encoded in some way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the quickest, simplest solution I would convert the μlaw file to wav using an external tool, then import the result into Mathematica.

[Here's an article](http://www.prophecy2006.com/node/52) I found about how to do this.  [sox](http://sox.sourceforge.net/) is available for all three common platforms.

Comment: I am familiar with sox, but I'm looking for a way to import uLaw into _Mathematica_ directly, without first needing to convert to a different format. It looks like _Mathematica_ has all of the necessary pieces built in (in particular, support for µ-law compression). Surely there is a way to get it to parse this format.

Comment: @SWB You can run sox from within Mathematica, and even read through a pipe.  `Import["!sox ...", "WAV"]` will read whatever sox writes to stdout.  This is going to give you a seamless and practical, but maybe not "beautiful" solution.  If you need to see how Mma reads AU, your can do spelunking, starting with the `SystemFiles/Formats` folder, figure out how it works, and re-use the bits to read your files.  I expect it to be doable with a few hours of work, but personally I don't think it's worth the effort when there's already a convenient solution.

Comment: @SWB To give some more guidance, start with importing some AU file to trigger loading all relevant functions.  Then take a look ``?System`Convert`AudioDump`*``.  It looks like there are some useful pieces there (mentions of μlaw).  [These spelunking tools](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/15948/12) will come handy.

Comment: Thanks, @Szabolcs! It hadn't occurred to me to use sox as an importer for _Mathematica_, _and_ I didn't know until now how to efficiently study _Mathematica_'s internal implementation. After a few minutes with `Spelunk`, I've found that importing an AU file results in a call to ``System`Convert`AudioDump`ImportAudioFile``, which finally calls `$InstallationDirectory\SystemFiles\Converters\Binaries\Windows-x86-64\Audio.exe` over a MathLink connection to perform the import. Therefore, it looks like the only solution will be to use an external helper like sox.