# Handling of non-file URI

Tags: notebooks, hyperlink

According to the manual, [Hyperlink](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Hyperlink.html?q=Hyperlink&lang=en) “represents a hyperlink that jumps to the specified URI when clicked”. OneNote produces hyperlinks that begin with onenote://. In Mathematica, creating a hyperlink to a OneNote page does not work. It returns a message: “The file that you tried to open was not found…”

According to the manual again,  “non-file URI open in a web browser”. When I paste the onenote URI in my web browser, it opens the target.

1) Can you confirm this bug in Mathematica?

2) Does anyone know of a workaround?

---

Steps:

1) In OneNote right click on a page label and select Copy Link to Page. The clipboard contains something like:

> onenote:///XXXX#Compound%20expressions,%20Get%20and%20Goto&page-id={7D74D7D4- 
>   E640-4217-9575-877E08975BED}&end

2) Create a text cell, put some text, select and press `Ctrl+Shift+H`. Paste the OneNote hyperlink.

3) Click in the hyperlink.

---

**Update**

Following [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/33090/8803), running

```
Hyperlink["test", MathLink`CallFrontEnd[ FrontEnd`SystemOpen[
 "onenote:///\\\\myComputer\\The%20Notebook&page-id={7D74D7D4E640-4217-9575-877E08975BED}&end"]]]
```

creates a hyperlink that jumps correctly when it is created. If one clicks on the hyperlink, then nothing happens. On the other hand, running

```
Button["test", MathLink`CallFrontEnd[ FrontEnd`SystemOpen[
 "onenote:///\\\\myComputer\\The%20Notebook&page-id={7D74D7D4E640-4217-9575-877E08975BED}&end"]]]
```

creates a button with that works correctly.

I will report this as a bug to Wolfram (in the no so near future).

---

**My workaround**

For the sake of …, I'll post this workaround. It produces a hyperlink-looking button.

```
Button[Style["test","Hyperlink"], MathLink`CallFrontEnd[ FrontEnd`SystemOpen[
  "onenote:///\\\\myComputer\\The%20Notebook&page-id={7D74D7D4E640-4217-9575-877E08975BED}&end"]]
  , Appearance -> None]
```

Comment: I see the problem with `skype:` URIs on Mac.  I assume you're using Windows, and the workaround (`Run["open URI"]`) I used on Mac won't work the same way there.  Try this:  `Run["start \"\" \"URI\""]` where you substitute the correct URI, and let me know if it worked.

Comment: You can also try `SystemOpen["URI"]`, but if `Hyperlink` didn't work, `SystemOpen` isn't likely to work either.

Comment: Actually, looking at the source of SystemOpen, here's something that *does* work on Mac: ``MathLink`CallFrontEnd[FrontEnd`SystemOpen["URI"]]``.  It turns out that ``System`SystemOpen[target]`` auto-prepends `"file://"` to `target`, which destroys the custom URI.  So please try this as well, and see if it works on Windows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can reproduce the problem both on OS X and one Windows, but *only* with URIs of the form `foo:something`.  URIs of the form `foo://something` do work correctly, both with `Hyperlink` and with `SystemOpen`.  Your URI is of the `://` form, so I am not sure why it doesn't work.

First, let's find out why some URIs don't work with `SystemOpen`.  Looking at the source of `SystemOpen`, it performs the following test to see if the string that was passed to it is a proper URI:

```
uriQ[s_String]:=Which[StringMatchQ[s,"mailto:*"],True,
                      StringMatchQ[s,"file:*"],True,
                      StringMatchQ[s,"paclet:*"],True,
                      StringMatchQ[s,"*://*"],True,True,False]
```

If the `uriQ` test returns `False`, it will auto-prepend `file://` to the URI, which explains the error message you see.

The workaround is to pass the URI to the Front End for opening directly, without doing the `uriQ` test first:

```
openURI[uri_String] := MathLink`CallFrontEnd[FrontEnd`SystemOpen[uri]]
```

This works for any URI for me, both on Windows and Mac.

A replacement for `Hyperlink` is this:

```
URIlink[name_, uri_] := 
 Button[name, openURI[uri], BaseStyle -> "Hyperlink", Appearance -> "Frameless"]
```

---

Another workaround that is not cross-platform is this:

- On OS X, `Run["open URI"]`
- On Windows, `Run["start \"\" \"URI\""]`

Comment: OneNote URI's have an extra `/`: "onenote:///".

Comment: "Looking at the source" … you work at Wolfram?

Comment: @Hector They're still of the form `*://*`

Comment: @Hector No, I just used `Information`.

Comment: `Information[SystemOpen]` gives me `Attributes[SystemOpen]={Protected,ReadProtected}` ?!

Comment: @Hector You need to remove the ReadProtected attribute to be able to read the source.

Comment: @Hector I usually use [this package](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/15948/12) to look at definitions.  It is much more convenient than manually removing ReadProtected and trying to make sense of the unformatted mess printed by `Information`.