# DifferentialEvolution scaling factor randomization

Tags: programming, mathematical-optimization, options

Using `NMinimize` for finding global minima, one can choose the `DifferentialEvolution` method. You can find a (not so) detailed description in the link [Constrained Optimization](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/ConstrainedOptimizationGlobalNumerical.html#24713453).

That being said, I would like to know if there is a simple way to implement the randomization of the value attributed to the option `ScalingFactor`. Such a feature should enhance the method:

> It has been found recently that selecting F from the interval [0.5,
>   1.0] randomly for each generation or for each difference vector, a technique called dither, improves convergence behaviour significantly
>   ([Differential Evolution Homepage](http://www1.icsi.berkeley.edu/~storn/code.html))

where the `F` mentioned in the quote corresponds to the value of `ScalingFactor` in *Mathematica*.

Probably, this is my lack of knowledge on the details of *Mathematica* showing up, but I don't know how to tell that in each step of `NMinimize` it should put  `RandomReal[{0.5,1.}]` in the option `ScalingFactor`.

Comment: I tried `"ScalingFactor" :> RandomReal[{0.5, 1}]` which appeared to fail. So did setting the option to a list of factors.  So I gave up as it probably being impossible.

Comment: Maybe I am talking nonsense, but is there any way to control each step of the process of the function `NMinimize`, so we can sort this random value for `"ScalingFactor"`each time?

Comment: @MichaelE2 , could you give some references or hints on how to control the steps of `NMinimize` and similar functions? Maybe I can't implement this specific problem that I proposed, but I feel I could learn a lot with this.

Comment: You can read about diff. evol. in [`tutorial/ConstrainedOptimizationGlobalNumerical`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/ConstrainedOptimizationGlobalNumerical.html) -- you probably already have.  That's about all I know about how to use it in *Mma*.  What I tried were random guesses based on the description of the implementation in the tutorial.  Occasionally I've gotten lucky and found an undocumented feature.  Sorry I can't help further.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Yes, I've read the documentation. Thank you a lot for the time spent on this subject.

Answer (score 11):

What follows is, of course, a terrible hack... since `NMinimize` is implemented entirely in top-level *Mathematica*, its code allows inspection by [spelunking](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1742) tools. The relevant function is

```
NMinimize[1, x]; (* force autoloading *)

Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]

PrintDefinitions[Optimization`NMinimizeDump`CoreDE]
```

and the desired behavior can be achieved by replacing `scale` in

```
mutateout[j, vecs, Length[vars], crossprob, scale]
```

with `RandomReal[{0.5, 1}]` and reevaluating the definition.

This change will only be in effect for the current kernel session and until the `NMinimize` definitions are read-in again. For a more persistent patch, one could load `NMinimize` and set `` DownValues[Optimization`NMinimizeDump`CoreDE] `` in an `init.m` file.

Comment: Nice adjustment. I think it would be good if the DE implementation could be updated with some other mutators in the future. The classical rand/1 is not bad, but the best choice is, as always, problem-specific. Empirically, I found that MDE5 is a very good default choice for many problems. Dither also does not seem to improve rand/1/bin as dramatically as it does some other mutators.