# How can I create an empty JSON object?

Tags: export, conversion, json-format

For creating non-empty object, I use following syntax

```
ExportString[{"key" -> "value"}, "JSON"]
(*{"key" : "value"}*)
```

But how can I create an empty object? When I run

```
ExportString[{}, "JSON"]
(*[]*)
```

it produces an empty array

PS: the empty object in JSON is `{}`

Comment: I think your question is answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8104573)

Comment: If you're having trouble, you could use `If` and export `{}` as a string `{}`. Just mentioning it because I think it's fairly common to have to treat special cases like this yourself in MMA.

Comment: Here MMA assumes `{}` means a list of something (= `[]`) unless it finds `Rule`s in it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can define your own object and tell Mathematica to interpret it as JSON object.

Dummy export to load relevant contexts:

```
In[1]:= ExportString["", "JSON"];
```

Tell Mathematica to interpret `JSONObject` symbol as possible head of JSON objects:

```
In[2]:= ClearAll[JSONObject]
         System`Convert`JSONDump`$JSONObjectHead = JSONObject;
```

Now you can use `JSONObject` anywhere in exported expression:

```
In[4]:= ExportString[JSONObject[], "JSON"]
Out[4]= {}

In[5]:= ExportString[{"a" -> JSONObject[]}, "JSON"]
Out[5]= {"a" : {}}

In[6]:= ExportString[JSONObject["a" -> JSONObject["b" -> Null]], "JSON"]
Out[6]= {"a" : {"b" : null}}
```

### How it works

Internally export to JSON is handled by `` System`Convert`JSONDump`exportJSON `` function which is just a wrapper for `` System`Convert`JSONDump`iexportJSON ``. The latter calls `` System`Convert`JSONDump`toString `` which does the real conversion and, among others, includes following definitions (`` System`Convert`JSONDump` `` context removed from symbol names):

```
toString[x_?($JSONObjectHead =!= List && MatchQ[#1, $JSONObjectHead[]]&), `t_Integer] := {}

toString[x_?($JSONObjectHead =!= List && Head[#1] === $JSONObjectHead && Length[#1] =!= 0&), t_Integer] := toString[List @@ x, t]
```

that use `$JSONObjectHead`.

### How to find out, how exporting works

You can start by tracing evaluation of export expression:

```
TracePrint[
    ExportString["mySpecialString", "JSON"],
    _[___, "mySpecialString", ___]
]
```

You'll find that `` System`Convert`JSONDump` `` context looks interesting. For fast overview of it's symbols you can look at:

```
Names["System`Convert`JSONDump`*"] // TableForm
```

Real fun will start if you use this [great spelunking tool](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1742/what-is-the-most-convenient-way-to-read-definitions-of-in-memory-symbols-when-we/15948#15948):

```
Get["https://raw.githubusercontent.com/szhorvat/Spelunking/master/Spelunking.m"]
```

Pick a function, from printed trace that looks promising:

```
Spelunk["System`Convert`JSONDump`exportJSON"]
```

and dig deeper by clicking on links to functions that you see in the trace.

About spelunking tool I learned from [one of halirutans answers](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/47364/texform-and-large-brackets-biggl-etc/48062#answer-47560).

Comment: nice, good answer. Thank you.

Comment: were you found information about ``System`Convert`JSONDump`*`` function and variables?

Comment: @molekyla777 I've expanded my answer.

Answer (score 7):

For newer versions exporting an empty `Association` does what you want:

```
ExportString[<||>, "JSON"]
```

Newer Versions means >= 10.1, 10.0.x versions did export empty `Associations` to empty lists, of course the new behavior is a much better match for the distinction of JavaScript empty lists and objects in Mathematica...

As mentioned by Kuba in a comment the export format "JSON" has some deficiancies which are overcome by the export format "RawJSON" which seem to work better than "JSON" in many respects, especially when working with Associations...

Kubas example where "JSON" gives an error while "RawJSON" works as intendes was:

```
ExportString[<|"test" -> <||>|>, "RawJSON"]
```