# Special notation using round brackets and avoiding commas (for $\LaTeX$ input)?

Tags: latex, custom-notation

Internally, when I work with mathematica I use a notation like `br[1,2,3,4]` to denote some quantities. Then I would like to export the results in `TeX` form and for this I need a special notation. I need to make the whole expression appear as follows:

`br[1,2,3,4]`$\rightarrow (1~ 2~ 3~ 4)$

So there should be small spaces but no commas between the numbers, and the whole thing should be in round brackets (which acquire a special meaning as an abbreviation for a mathematical object). I was thinking of using the `Needs["Notation"]` environment, but unfortunately it does not allow round brackets and does not get rid of commas. Can this be done in some other way?

**EDIT**

Desired $\LaTeX$ syntax example:

`br[1,2,3,4]/br[2,3,4,1]+br[2,3,4,1]/br[1,2,3,4]`$\rightarrow\frac{(1~2~3~4)}{(2~3~4~1)}+\frac{(2~3~4~1)}{(1~2~3~4)}$

where the latex part above is explicitly:

```
\frac{(1~2~3~4)}{(2~3~4~1)}+\frac{(2~3~4~1)}{(1~2~3~4)}
```

Comment: Ultimately, the output should be in $\LaTeX$ format so that I can copy it over directly into a latex file and compile. If a function converts it to a string first and then to latex, it makes no difference.

Comment: Oh, it kind of works with a single `br[...]`, but the whole problem is that expressions will appear as functions of several `br[...]`'s. Using the above conversion to string gives the `//TeXForm` as `\text{(1 2 3 4)}`. And I would like to directly paste the output into a math environment in latex without `\text{ }` wrappers around each bracket.

Comment: Can you show an example of the desired latex syntax?

Comment: I will edit the question to show desired latex syntax.

Comment: If I understood the question correctly, may be you will find [regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) useful to solve this problem. Mathematica [has](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/RegularExpressions.html) some functions using regular expressions too, but I'm not familiar with them.

Comment: Yes, this indeed completely solves my problem. Thank you! I wish I understood the *Mathematica* syntax you used, too. Maybe you can explain the bits and pieces in detail if you choose to write the answer later? I will definitely vote up and accept.

Comment: Related: [TeXForm and large brackets (\Biggl[ etc)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/47364/14303), [Format and TeXForm does not work as expected](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/47417/14303)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution that automatically formats any instance of `br[...]` in the format that you want and that will be copy-and-pastable into `LaTeX` after converting to `TexForm`.

```
Format[br[a__]] := DisplayForm@RowBox[Riffle[ToString /@ {a}, "\[ThinSpace]"]~Prepend~"("~Append~")"]
```

`\[ThinSpace]` can be replaced alternatively by `\[VeryThinSpace]` or `\[MediumSpace]`, depending on how much space you want. These can be entered using <kbd>Esc</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>, <kbd>Esc</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>, or <kbd>Esc</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>, respectively.

Then, note that

```
br[1, 2, 3]
(* (1 2 3) *)
```

So that

```
br[1, 2, 3, 4]/br[2, 3, 4, 1] + br[2, 3, 4, 5]/br[1, 2, 3, 4]
% // TeXForm
```

returns

[image]

---

**Brief (and perhaps incomplete) explanation**

When expression are displayed as outputs in *Mathematica*, they are formatted using `Box`es. `RowBox` in particular accepts a list of expressions for us in displaying them in a row. To convert to the display style, you apply `DisplayForm`.

To have `br` display as this output, we use `Format`. In the call to `Format`, we have used the pattern `br[a__]`, so anything matching this form will be formatted according to the right-hand-side.

As for the rest, it's all for the purpose of getting the correct list of objects to display in a row. What we want is a list of the inputs of `br` separated by spaces (of some sort) and bracketed by parentheses. `Riffle` inserts its second argument in between the elements of the list in its first argument, so

```
Riffle[ToString /@ {1, 2, 3}, " "]
(* {"1", " ", "2", " ", "3"} *)
```

where `ToString /@ {1, 2, 3}` turns all the elements in the list to strings. We then need to `Append` and `Prepend` "(" and ")", respectively, to the list, and we have done this using `Infix` notation. I could just as easily done something like

```
Join[{"("}, Riffle[ToString /@ {a}, " "], {")"}]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`TeXDelimited`](http://jkuczm.github.io/MathematicaTeXUtilities/reference/ref/TeXDelimited.html) function from my [TeXUtilities](https://github.com/jkuczm/MathematicaTeXUtilities) package, that was created precisely for this kind of tasks.

```
Import["https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jkuczm/MathematicaTeXUtilities/master/NoInstall.m"]

ClearAll[br]
Format[br[x__], TeXForm] :=
    TeXDelimited["(", x, ")", {"BodySeparator" -> "~", "DelimSeparator" -> ""}]

br[1, 2, 3, 4]/br[2, 3, 4, 1] + br[2, 3, 4, 5]/br[1, 2, 3, 4]
(* br[1, 2, 3, 4]/br[2, 3, 4, 1] + br[2, 3, 4, 5]/br[1, 2, 3, 4] *)
% // TeXForm
(* \frac{(1~2~3~4)}{(2~3~4~1)}+\frac{(2~3~4~5)}{(1~2~3~4)} *)
```

[image: TeXDelimited usage example]

Answer (score 2):

```
StringReplace[StringDrop[ToString[TeXForm[br[1, 2, 3, 4]]], 9], 
 "," -> " "]
```

$\text{(1 2 3 4)}$

Comment: The output is `\text{(1,2,3,4)}`, which still has the `\text{ }` wrapper and still contains commas. See the answer by march in the commets to the question for a working solution.

Answer (score 2):

```
StringReplace[
   ToString@TeXForm@#, 
       Shortest["\\text{br}(" ~~ s : __ ~~ ")"] :> 
          "(" <> StringReplace[s, "," -> "~"] <> ")"] &@
      (br[1, 2, 3, 4] br[2, 3, 4, 1] + br[2, 3, 4, 1]/br[1, 2, 3, 4])
```

> "\frac{(1~2~3~4)}{(2~3~4~1)}+\frac{(2~3~4~1)}{(1~2~3~4)}"

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to use `RuleDelayed`.

```
br[2, 3, 4, 1] /. 
 br[w_Integer, x_Integer, y_Integer, z_Integer] :> 
  "(" <> Riffle[Map[ToString[#] &, {w, y, y, z}], " "] <> ")"
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The inner part produces a list of strings

```
br[2, 3, 4, 1] /. 
 br[w_Integer, x_Integer, y_Integer, z_Integer] :> 
  Map[ToString[#] &, {w, y, y, z}]
```

{"2", "4", "4", "1"}

Then `Riffle` is used to interleave spaces and `StringJoin` (i.e., `<>`) is used to add parenthesis.

```
br[1, 2, 3, 4]/br[2, 3, 4, 1] + br[2, 3, 4, 5]/br[1, 2, 3, 4] /. 
 br[w_Integer, x_Integer, y_Integer, z_Integer] :> 
  "(" <> Riffle[Map[ToString[#] &, {w, y, y, z}], " "] <> ")"
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Applying `TeXForm` to this output produces

```
\frac{\text{(1 3 3 4)}}{\text{(2 4 4 1)}}+\frac{\text{(2 4 4 5)}}
{\text{(1 3 3 4)}}
```