# Is it possible to change/customize some conversions done by TeXForm?

Tags: special-functions, output-formatting, customization, latex, conversion

I use `TeXForm` to convert output of some computation to Latex. I'd like to ask if there is a way to override/change/customize some of these conversions, related to *just* the name *Mathematica* assigns to some special functions in its Latex output, since it is not clear what they are in the Latex after the conversion.

Here is an example. `FresnelC` function is changed to `C` in Latex. So someone reading the latex PDF, will not really know what `C` is and I like to keep the name as `FresnelC`.  I suppose I could add note saying that `C` is `FresnelC`, but this is all automated, and I do not know beforehand that the solution being generated even has `FresnelC` in it to make the note. I just look at the final Latex output.

MWE

```
sol = y[t] /. First@DSolve[y'[t] + y[t] Sqrt[t] Sin[t] == 0, y[t], t]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But the Latex output is

```
TeXForm[sol]
(*  c_1 e^{\sqrt{t} \cos (t)-\sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}} 
       C\left(\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }} \sqrt{t}\right)} *)
```

Which is rendered as

$$c_1 e^{\sqrt{t} \cos (t)-\sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}} C\left(\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }} \sqrt{t}\right)}$$

I'd like it to still show as the full name `FresnelC`

$$c_1 e^{\sqrt{t} \cos (t)-\sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}} \text{FresnelC}\left(\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }} \sqrt{t}\right)}$$

So it is more clear. This is how Maple does it also:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This does not only affect the above function, but others as well. For example

```
 TeXForm[CosIntegral[x]]
```

gives

$$\text{Ci}(x)$$ and I'd like to keep the same in the Latex as the name in the Mathematica command.

$$\text{CosIntegral}(x)$$

Since it is more clear.

Question is: Is there a way to customize some of these conversions?

Comment: If it's possible you can dig it up from ``Convert`TeX`BoxesToTeX``

Comment: Related: [Format and TeXForm does not work as expected](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/47417/14303), [TeXForm and large brackets (\Biggl[ etc)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/47364/14303), [Special notation using round brackets and avoiding commas (for LATEX
input)?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/95852/14303).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could use my [TeXUtilities package](https://github.com/jkuczm/MathematicaTeXUtilities):

```
Import@"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jkuczm/MathematicaTeXUtilities/master/NoInstall.m"

Unprotect[FresnelC, CosIntegral];
Format[FresnelC@x_, TeXForm] := TeXVerbatim["\\operatorname{FresnelC}"]@x
Format[CosIntegral@x_, TeXForm] := TeXVerbatim["\\operatorname{CosIntegral}"]@x
(* Move TeXForm format to begining of FormatValues so they take precedence over existing ones. *)
(FormatValues@# = Join[#@False, #@True]&@GroupBy[FormatValues@#, FreeQ@TeXForm]) & /@ {FresnelC, CosIntegral};
Protect[FresnelC, CosIntegral];
```

Now use `TeXForm` as usual:

```
y[t] /. First@DSolve[y'[t] + y[t] Sqrt[t] Sin[t] == 0, y[t], t] // TeXForm
(* c_1 e^{\sqrt{t} \cos (t)-\sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}} \operatorname{FresnelC}\left(\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }} \sqrt{t}\right)} *)
```

> $c_1 e^{\sqrt{t} \cos (t)-\sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}} \operatorname{FresnelC}\left(\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }} \sqrt{t}\right)}$

```
CosIntegral[x] // TeXForm
(* \operatorname{CosIntegral}(x) *)
```

> $\operatorname{CosIntegral}(x)$

Comment: fyi, for some reason, the above no longer works in 11.3. I was going to post question, but thought to check if you also see the same thing. I run the same code above, but the Latex remains as before, and did not get modify as shown above.

Comment: @Nasser Thanks for noticing this. Original answer was using version 1.0.0 of TeXUtilities, which was completely ignoring `TraditionalForm` format, when converting to TeX, symbols that had any `TeXForm` formatting set. This was considered a bug, and was fixed in version 1.0.1 of package. Now some extra care needs to be taken to make sure that newly set formatting takes precedence over built-in formatting. I've updated the answer.

Comment: fyi, when trying to install your package on 13.1, it gives an error. `Import["https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jkuczm/MathematicaTeXUtilities/master/BootstrapInstall.m"]`  gives error `ProjectInstall::noprjpckg: The project has no package in the top-level directory with the name mathcing the name of the project specified in project's descriptor file (project.m)`.  I will try the manual installation instructions next.

Answer (score 10):

I will assume that you want the normal [`TraditionalForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TraditionalForm) typesetting in a notebook to be unaffected, and only want to see the [`TeXForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TeXForm) of [`FresnelC`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FresnelC), [`CosIntegral`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CosIntegral) and other targeted functions changed. Also, I assume you don't want to have to use a new function, like `myTeXForm`, but would rather just use [`TeXForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TeXForm) as you usually do.

TeXForm works by first converting an expression into [`TraditionalForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TraditionalForm) boxes, and then converting those boxes into a TeX string. So, one possibility is to do as @QuantumDot suggests, and modify the functions that convert the boxes to a TeX string. However, I prefer avoiding the creation of the wrong boxes. Another possibility is to do as @b3m2a1 suggests, but then both the [`TeXForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TeXForm) and normal [`TraditionalForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TraditionalForm) typesetting will be affected.

Instead, I would modify the expression to boxes internal function so that it creates the desired boxes. This can be done by having this function set a global variable, say `$TeX`, to [`True`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/True). Then, when the expression is converted to boxes, a conditioned FormatValue can be used to create the [`TraditionalForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TraditionalForm) boxes you want.

**Initial**

It will be convenient to make use of the function `Initial` from my [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/153885/45431) to [How can one manually change the rule ordering](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/106068/45431):

```
Initial /: Verbatim[TagSetDelayed][Initial[sym_], lhs_, rhs_] := With[
    {
    new = Block[{sym},
        TagSetDelayed[sym, lhs, rhs];
        First @ Language`ExtendedDefinition[sym, "ExcludedContexts" -> {}]
    ],
    protect=Unprotect[sym]
    },

    sym;
    Replace[new,
        Rule[values_, n:Except[{}]] :> (values[sym] = Prepend[values[sym],n]),
        {2}
    ];
    Protect@protect;
]
```

This function creates a new *Value, and prepends it to the existing *Values. It also forces autoloading of any necessary packages (.mx) files that will populate the *Values of the function before the new *Value is added.

**Convert`TeX`ExpressionToTeX**

The internal function I will modify is `` Convert`TeX`ExpressionToTeX ``:

```
Initial[Convert`TeX`ExpressionToTeX] /: 
    Convert`TeX`ExpressionToTeX[e__] /; !TrueQ@$TeX := Block[
        {$TeX = True},
        Convert`TeX`ExpressionToTeX[e]
    ]
```

Note that when `$TeX` is not True, the above DownValue will set `$TeX` to True, and then use the old DownValue.

**FormatValues**

The new TraditionalForm FormatValues are:

```
Initial[FresnelC] /: MakeBoxes[FresnelC[a_], TraditionalForm] /; $TeX :=
    MakeBoxes[Defer[FresnelC][a], TraditionalForm]
Initial[CosIntegral] /: MakeBoxes[CosIntegral[a_], TraditionalForm] /; $TeX :=
    MakeBoxes[Defer[CosIntegral][a], TraditionalForm]
```

Note the use of the `$TeX` condition. Also, note the use of `Defer[FresnelC]` on the RHS so that no recursion errors occur. Finally, I like using `Defer[FresnelC]` instead of something like `HoldForm[FresnelC]` because the boxes that are produced are simpler. Compare:

```
MakeBoxes[Defer[FresnelC], TraditionalForm]
MakeBoxes[HoldForm[FresnelC], TraditionalForm]
```

> "FresnelC"

> TagBox["FresnelC", HoldForm]

**Results**

Here we see the new [`TeXForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TeXForm) formatting in action:

```
ToString[{FresnelC[a], CosIntegral[b]}, TeXForm]
```

> "\{\text{FresnelC}(a),\text{CosIntegral}(b)\}"

And here we see the normal [`TraditionalForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TraditionalForm) typesetting is still in place:

```
{FresnelC[a], CosIntegral[b]} //TraditionalForm
```

> {C(a),Ci(b)}

**Update**

To address the question in the comments, defining:

```
System`Convert`TeXFormDump`maketex[s_String] /; !StringMatchQ[s, "\""~~___~~"\""] && SyntaxQ[s, TeXForm] := Replace[
    s,
    {
        n_ /; StringMatchQ[n, NumberString] :> n,
        w_?wordQ :> "\\operatorname{"<>w<>"}"
    }
]

wordQ[s_String] := Length @ StringSplit[s, WordBoundary] == 1
```

should make operators use \operatorname instead of \text.

Comment: In `Initial` definition you're assigning to global `protect` symbol. Is that intentional?

Comment: @jkuczm No, that was just an oversight. Thanks.

Comment: Is it possible to make it generate `\operatorname{Fresnel}` instead of `\text{FresnelC}`? I tried to change your code but did not know how to. Thanks.

Comment: @Nasser Please see my [(answer)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/170224/45431) to question [(47417)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/47417/45431), specifically the change to the DownValues for the symbol ``System`Convert`TeXFormDump`maketex``.

Comment: Thank you. I did look at it your new post, but your code is too advanced for me and I do not know what I need to change to make it emit `\operatorname{Fresnel}` instead of `text{Fresnel}`.

Comment: @Nasser See update.

Comment: Thanks Carl That works great! I used your Latex conversion functions above for naming part, in my new CAS integration test report for 11.3.

Comment: hi Carl. I found a bug in the above change to replace `\text` with `\operatorname` So I will just keep using `text{}` for now. Here is an example.  `result=Integrate[(1-x^4+x^8)^(-1),x]` and now using `TeXForm` on the result, when adding your rules, not all `text` are converted. so the resulting Latex gives error when compiled. Here is screen shot ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/nSS7S.png)  It might not be worth fixing it. I'll just go back to leaving `text` as is. Just wanted to let you know. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Another option is to just reset the `TraditionalForm` format of `CosIntegral` (or whatever symbol you want to mess with):

```
Unprotect[CosIntegral];
Format[CosIntegral[b_], TraditionalForm] := 
  RawBoxes@RowBox[{"CosIntegral", "(", MakeBoxes[b, TraditionalForm], 
     ")"}];
FormatValues[CosIntegral] = RotateRight@FormatValues[CosIntegral];
Protect[CosIntegral];
CosIntegral // FormatValues

{HoldPattern[MakeBoxes[CosIntegral[b_], TraditionalForm]] :> \!\(\*
TagBox[
FormBox[
RowBox[{"CosIntegral", "(", "b", ")"}],
TraditionalForm],
Format[#, TraditionalForm]& ]\), 
 HoldPattern[
   MakeBoxes[CosIntegral[BoxForm`a$_], TraditionalForm] /; 
    BoxForm`sufficientVersionQ[6.1]] :> 
  TemplateBox[{MakeBoxes[BoxForm`a$, TraditionalForm]}, 
   "CosIntegral"]}
```

Then:

```
CosIntegral[x] // TraditionalForm // ToBoxes // FE`makePlainText
CosIntegral[x] // TeXForm // ToBoxes // FE`makePlainText

"CosIntegral(x)"

"\\text{CosIntegral}(x)"
```