# why changing the order of `Format` causes error?

Tags: latex, format

I am trying the solution given in [is-it-possible-to-change-customize-some-conversions-done-by-texform](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/153876/is-it-possible-to-change-customize-some-conversions-done-by-texform) which works very well except changing the order of the `Format` command causes an error on *some* symbols.

I do not know if this is Mathematica own issue with the command `Format` or if it is related to the package I am using.

First I installed the nice package `MathematicaTeXUtilities` using the command

```
 Get["https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jkuczm/MathematicaTeXUtilities/master/BootstrapInstall.m"]
```

Here is MWE. Using the following order, with *fresh* kernel, show **no error**

```
Needs["TeXUtilities`"]
Unprotect[Hypergeometric1F1,HypergeometricU];
Format[ Hypergeometric1F1, TeXForm] = TeXVerbatim@"\\operatorname{Hypergeometric1F1}";
Format[ HypergeometricU, TeXForm] = TeXVerbatim@"\\operatorname{HypergeometricU}";
Protect[Hypergeometric1F1,HypergeometricU];
```

Now, changed the order of `Format` command, and using *fresh* kernel (must restart the kernel to see the error), an error message shows up

```
Needs["TeXUtilities`"]
Unprotect[Hypergeometric1F1,HypergeometricU];
Format[ HypergeometricU, TeXForm] = TeXVerbatim@"\\operatorname{HypergeometricU}";
Format[ Hypergeometric1F1, TeXForm] = TeXVerbatim@"\\operatorname{Hypergeometric1F1}";
Protect[Hypergeometric1F1,HypergeometricU];
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I thought at first that the order of symbols in `Protect` has to match the order of `Format` commands. But this does not make sense. And I found by trial and error a case where the errors show up even when the order or `Protect` match order of `Format`. Here it is (fresh kernel)

```
Needs["TeXUtilities`"]
Unprotect[HypergeometricU,LaguerreL,HermiteH,Hypergeometric1F1,Erf,Erfc];
Format[ HypergeometricU, TeXForm] = TeXVerbatim@"\\operatorname{HypergeometricU}"
Format[ LaguerreL, TeXForm] = TeXVerbatim@"\\operatorname{LaguerreL}"
Format[ HermiteH, TeXForm] = TeXVerbatim@"\\operatorname{HermiteH}"
Format[ Hypergeometric1F1, TeXForm] = TeXVerbatim@"\\operatorname{Hypergeometric1F1}"
Format[ Erfc, TeXForm] = TeXVerbatim@"\\operatorname{Erfc}"
Format[ Erf, TeXForm] = TeXVerbatim@"\\operatorname{Erf}"
Protect[HypergeometricU,LaguerreL,HermiteH,Hypergeometric1F1,Erf,Erfc];
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So I am not sure what is going on now. Any ideas?

As a workaround, now I `Format` them one by one, instead of the batch mode and error went away

```
Needs["TeXUtilities`"]

Unprotect[Hypergeometric1F1];
Format[ Hypergeometric1F1, TeXForm] = TeXVerbatim@"\\operatorname{Hypergeometric1F1}";
Protect[Hypergeometric1F1];

Unprotect[HypergeometricU];
Format[ HypergeometricU, TeXForm] = TeXVerbatim@"\\operatorname{HypergeometricU}";
Protect[HypergeometricU];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many `` System` `` symbols autoload when they are used. This is what is happening in your example. For instance, from a fresh kernel:

```
OwnValues @ HypergeometricU
```

> `` {HoldPattern[HypergeometricU] :> 
>     System`Dump`AutoLoad[Hold[HypergeometricU], 
>       Hold[HypergeometricPFQ, HypergeometricPFQRegularized, HypergeometricU], 
>       "SpecialFunctions`HypergeometricPFQ`"] /; System`Dump`TestLoad} ``

This means that when [`HypergeometricU`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HypergeometricU) is evaluated, `` System`Dump`AutoLoad `` is called. Note the second argument, namely `Hold[HypergeometricPFQ, HypergeometricPFQRegularized, HypergeometricU]`. These symbols get protected during autoloading. So, this is what is happening during your example:

```
Unprotect[HypergeometricU,LaguerreL,HermiteH,Hypergeometric1F1,Erf,Erfc];
```

[`HypergeometricU`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HypergeometricU) gets unprotected

```
Format[ HypergeometricU, TeXForm] = TeXVerbatim@"\\operatorname{HypergeometricU}"
```

First, [`HypergeometricU`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HypergeometricU) is evaluated ([`Format`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Format) has no [`Hold`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Hold)* attributes). Then, the [`TeXForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TeXForm) [`Format`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Format) is stored. Since [`HypergeometricU`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HypergeometricU) is evaluated, it autoloads, and during this process, [`HypergeometricPFQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HypergeometricPFQ), [`HypergeometricPFQRegularized`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HypergeometricPFQRegularized), [`HypergeometricU`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HypergeometricU) all get protected.

```
Format[ Hypergeometric1F1, TeXForm] = TeXVerbatim@"\\operatorname{Hypergeometric1F1}"
```

Since [`Hypergeometric1F1`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Hypergeometric1F1) is now [`Protected`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Protected), you get a [`Message`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Message), and no [`Format`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Format) is stored.

Comment: Great answer! So I guess the takeaway is to always make sure system functions are pre-loaded before messing with their attributes.  Now that I knew to look for autoload, found related discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5649618/8424426). (+1)