# Error changing Attribute of ParabolicCylinderD after unprotecting

Tags: attributes

This is related to [why-changing-the-order-of-format-causes-error](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/154054/why-changing-the-order-of-format-causes-error) but it seems to be a new issue so posting a new question.

Of all the symbols that I changed its `Format` by unprotecting it first, then protecting it afterwords, only `ParabolicCylinderD` gives an error.  Why is that? Is there a work around?

MWE, on fresh kernel

```
Unprotect[ParabolicCylinderD]
Format[ParabolicCylinderD, TeXForm] ="\\text{ParabolicCylinderD}"
Protect[ParabolicCylinderD]
```

gives

```
Set::write: Tag ParabolicCylinderD in \text{ParabolicCylinderD} is Protected.
```

The same commands work on all other symbols I've tried so far. No problems. Only `ParabolicCylinderD` gives this error.

Screen shot

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Mathematica 11.1.1 on windows.

Comment: I notice that this only happens on the *first* evaluation on my machine (Win7-64, MMA 11.1.1.0). A second evaluation of the same code completes with no errors. I wonder if this has something to do with some code being loaded only once when that function is first invoked in a fresh kernel.

Comment: In general, due to the autoloading now being done these days, you should "touch" a symbol first before calling `Unprotect[]`, etc. `ParabolicCylinderD; Unprotect[(* stuff *)]; (* etc. *)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The package that [`ParabolicCylinderD`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParabolicCylinderD) autoloads has the [`ParabolicCylinderD`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParabolicCylinderD) symbol protected, while the package that [`HypergeometricU`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HypergeometricU) autoloads does not have the [`HypergeometricU`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HypergeometricU) symbol protected:

```
Unprotect[ParabolicCylinderD];
ParabolicCylinderD; (* autoload *)
Attributes[ParabolicCylinderD]
```

> {Listable, NumericFunction, Protected, ReadProtected}

We see that the [`ParabolicCylinderD`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParabolicCylinderD) symbol is protected after autoloading. The similar code for [`HypergeometricU`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HypergeometricU) does not reprotect the symbol:

```
Unprotect[HypergeometricU];
HypergeometricU; (* autoload *)
Attributes[HypergeometricU]
```

> {Listable, NumericFunction, ReadProtected}

You might consider using the [Initial](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/153885/45431) wrapper from my answer to [How can one manually change the rule ordering](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/106068/45431) *(note that your question caused me to modify the wrapper so that it is not tripped up by autoloading packages that reprotect symbols, and so that [`FormatValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FormatValues) get autoloaded as well).* The relevant code is:

```
Initial /: Verbatim[TagSetDelayed][Initial[sym_], lhs_, rhs_] := With[
    {
    new = Block[{sym},
        TagSetDelayed[sym, lhs, rhs];
        First @ Language`ExtendedDefinition[sym]
    ],
    protect = Unprotect[sym]
    },

    sym;
    Quiet @ MakeBoxes[sym[], TraditionalForm];
    Unprotect[sym];

    Replace[new,
        Rule[values_, n:Except[{}]] :> (
            values[sym] = DeleteDuplicates@Join[n, values[sym]]
        ),
        {2}
    ];
    Protect@protect;
]
```

You would use it as follows (note that I changed [`Set`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Set) to [`SetDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetDelayed) in your definition):

```
Initial[ParabolicCylinderD] /: Format[ParabolicCylinderD, TeXForm] := "\\text{ParabolicCylinderD}"
```

Check:

```
TableForm[FullForm /@ FormatValues[ParabolicCylinderD]]
```

> `` RuleDelayed[HoldPattern[Format[ParabolicCylinderD,TeXForm]],"\\text{ParabolicCylinderD}"]
>   RuleDelayed[HoldPattern[Condition[MakeBoxes[ParabolicCylinderD[Pattern[BoxForm`a$,Blank[]],Pattern[BoxForm`b$,Blank[]]],TraditionalForm],BoxForm`sufficientVersionQ[6.1`]]],TemplateBox[List[MakeBoxes[BoxForm`a$,TraditionalForm],MakeBoxes[BoxForm`b$,TraditionalForm]],"ParabolicCylinderD"]]
>   RuleDelayed[HoldPattern[MakeBoxes[ParabolicCylinderD[Pattern[BoxForm`v,Blank[]],Pattern[BoxForm`z,Blank[]]],TraditionalForm]],RowBox[List[SubscriptBox[TagBox["D",ParabolicCylinderD],BoxForm`ToTrad[BoxForm`v]],"(",BoxForm`ToTrad[BoxForm`z],")"]]] ``

Comment: I believe that part of the difference is due to the fact that `HypergeometricU[]` was an older function, and `ParabolicCylinderD[]` only came about when this autoloading stuff suddenly became the norm for new *Mathematica* symbols.

Answer (score 4):

An extended comment. I notice that this behavior only happens on the *first* evaluation on my machine (Win7-64, MMA 11.1.1.0). A second evaluation of the same code completes with no errors.

I wonder if this has something to do with some code being loaded only once when that function is first invoked in a fresh kernel.

In fact, if you *first* invoke the function independently of the attribute change, e.g. by using one of the examples from the docs, *and then* change the attributes, no errors are generated, even in a fresh kernel. See e.g.

```
Plot[ParabolicCylinderD[5, x], {x, -10, 10}]

Unprotect[ParabolicCylinderD]
Format[ParabolicCylinderD, TeXForm] = "\\text{ParabolicCylinderD}"
Protect[ParabolicCylinderD]
```