# question on using TeXUtilities. Why it needs to be called twice to work

Tags: latex

I find strange behavior of [TeXUtilities](https://github.com/jkuczm/MathematicaTeXUtilities) by @jkuczm which I do not understand how to fix.

I find I have to call `TeXForm` two times for it to start working.  Here is a MWE

This will install the package.

```
Import["https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jkuczm/MathematicaTeXUtilities/master/BootstrapInstall.m"]
```

If you do not want to install it, just use it one time, the command is

```
Import["https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jkuczm/MathematicaTeXUtilities/master/NoInstall.m"]
```

And now

```
 Needs["TeXUtilities`"]

 EllipticF;
 Unprotect[EllipticF];
 Format[EllipticF, TeXForm] = TeXVerbatim@"\\operatorname{EllipticF}";
 Protect[EllipticF];

 result1 = EllipticF[ArcSin[x], (-1)^(1/3)]
 TeXForm[result1]
 (*it does NOT work*)
 TeXForm[result1]
 (*Now it works!*)
```

Here is screen shot

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Notice how the `EllipticF` did not change to `\operatorname{EllipticF}` first time. Only on second call it changed.

I think this might be due to caching. But do not know to work around it.

Can this be made to work on first call, without having to call it 2 times?

Version 11.3 on windows 7.

reference [is-it-possible-to-change-customize-some-conversions-done-by-texform](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/153876/is-it-possible-to-change-customize-some-conversions-done-by-texform)

[why-changing-the-order-of-format-causes-error](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/154054/why-changing-the-order-of-format-causes-error)

### Update April 3, 2018

Adding information requested below. Using screen shot, since much better in this case to show the output. Now I get kernel errors when I added the commands as mentioned in comment. Not sure what it going on. I put the notebook also [here](https://www.12000.org/tmp/040318/)

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I don't have 11.3 to check what precisely is happening in your situation. If you could add `FormatValues@EllipticF` line: between `EllipticF;` and `Unprotect[EllipticF];` lines, between `Protect[EllipticF];` and `result1 = EllipticF[ArcSin[x], (-1)^(1/3)]` lines, and between two `TeXForm` calls, then we could know more about what is happening. I suspect that, as in [linked question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/154054/14303), it's an issue with autoloading, not directly related to TeXUtilities.

Comment: What works for me in version 11.0 is evaluating `EllipticF[x, m] // TeXForm` before any `Format` assignments, so that all relevant `FormatValues` are pre-loaded. Then assigning format with arguments `Format[HoldPattern@EllipticF[a_, b_], TeXForm] := 
 TeXVerbatim["\\operatorname{EllipticF}"][a, b]`. Since formatting works differently than standard evaluation, there is no distinction between format `OwnValues` and `DownValues`. First format value that matches is used, so if there's formatting for whole `EllipticF[x, m]` expression then specialized formatting for `EllipticF` head is not used.

Comment: Thanks @jkuczm for looking at this. I added the command you requested., Now I get kernel error messages. Before, there is no kernel error messages. I also put link to the notebook if you want to look at it. I do not understand any of this myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two problems in code from OP.

First problem is auto-loading of `EllipticF` format values. It seems there are two stages of this auto-loading. First, formatting with `` BoxForm`BoxFormAutoLoad[...] `` as RHS is set, then, when `TraditionalForm` formatting of `EllipticF` is used, `` BoxForm`BoxFormAutoLoad `` loads proper formatting. Both stages should be triggered by forcing `TraditionalForm` formatting of `EllipticF[...]` expression e.g. by evaluating `EllipticF[x, m] // TeXForm`, before assigning any new formatting to `EllipticF`.

Second problem is that, after successful auto-loading, `EllipticF` has defined formatting for `EllipticF[a, b]` expression, which will be used before any attempt of formatting parts of expression, including its head. That's why formatting for whole expression, not only its head, should be defined.

Putting it together:

```
Import@"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jkuczm/MathematicaTeXUtilities/master/NoInstall.m"

EllipticF[x, m] // TeXForm
(* F(x|m) *)

Unprotect[EllipticF];
Format[HoldPattern@EllipticF[x_, m_], TeXForm] :=
    TeXVerbatim["\\operatorname{EllipticF}"][x, m];
Protect[EllipticF];

result1 = EllipticF[ArcSin[x], (-1)^(1/3)];
result1 // TeXForm
(* \operatorname{EllipticF}\left(\sin ^{-1}(x),\sqrt[3]{-1}\right) *)
```

Comment: Thanks,. The above seems to work. No errors in 11.3. I need to test it on my main build to make sure. You might want to also modify your answer here [is-it-possible-to-change-customize-some-conversions-done-by-texform](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/153876/is-it-possible-to-change-customize-some-conversions-done-by-texform) to make it like the above. As I was using your answer there to show the issue in my question. This way, if someone sees the old answer, they will not have same problem again.