# How to Custominze the Output of TeXForm

Tags: export, output-formatting, latex

When working with complicated expressions I would like to easily export specific expressions to LaTex.

The ideal solution for me is the [TeXForm](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/GeneratingAndImportingTeX.html) command, but many times when using it I would like to customize the output.

For example TeXForm produces 
[image]
There are several things I would like to change about the about output

- removing \text around the variables
- changing \bar to \overline when needed.
- removing \left and \right
- changing \varepsilon to \epsilon

My question is

> Is there a general way that I can parse the output of TeXForm (or any LaTex output method) so that it is format it to my preferences?

Comment: probably it is not possible to do all of these, but for some, you can check this [is-it-possible-to-change-customize-some-conversions-done-by-texform](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/153876/is-it-possible-to-change-customize-some-conversions-done-by-texform)

Comment: @Nasser Is there a general method of parsing strings in Mathematica? e.g. The mathematica equivalent to https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html

Comment: Yes, you can use either [StringPatterns](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/WorkingWithStringPatterns.html) or you can also use standard [RegularExpression](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegularExpression.html) as well.

Comment: `\[Epsilon] // TeXForm` gives `\epsilon`; `\[CurlyEpsilon] // TeXForm` gives `\varepsilon`. You get what you inserted. Moreover, what's wrong with `\left` and `\right`?

Comment: Nothing is wrong with `\left` and `\right` but sometimes I prefer that they are removed as they make very long Tex expressions hard to read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I came up with a work around for my problem, please comment or edit this question if you have suggestions.

For example I starting with the expression:
[image]

I can use the a variety of replacement rules and a function

```
exper // TraditionalForm
repRules = {
   "\\varepsilon" -> "\\epsilon",
   "\\epsilon " -> "\\epsilon",
   "\\delta " -> "\\sigma",
   "\\text{B1}" -> "B_1",
   "\\text{B2}" -> "B_2",
   "\\text{K1}" -> "K_1",
   "\\text{K2}" -> "K_2",
   "\\text{d1}" -> "d_1",
   "\\text{r1}" -> "r_1",
   "\\text{r2}" -> "r_2",
   "\\text{d1}" -> "d_1",
   "\\text{d2}" -> "d_2",
   "\\left" -> "",
   "\\right" -> "",
   "i " -> "I "};
ToTeX[equation_] := 
  StringReplace[repRules][ToString[TeXForm[equation]]];
ToTeX[exper]
```

to get my desired output
[image]

Is there any way to change it so that Mathematica outputs plain text?(this eliminates an extra step)