# Image compose coordinate problem

Tags: image-processing

Am I missing something or this is a bug? Why I get different results by just adding a bracket?

```
g1 = Graphics[{}, ImageSize -> {200, Automatic}, AspectRatio -> 2];
g2 = Graphics[Rectangle[], ImageSize -> {200, Automatic}, AspectRatio -> 1];
g3 = Graphics[Rectangle[], {ImageSize -> {200, Automatic}, AspectRatio -> 1}];

Row[{
ImageCompose[g1, g2, {0, 0}, {0, 0}],
ImageCompose[g1, g3, {0, 0}, {0, 0}],
ImageCompose[g1, Show[g2], {0, 0}, {0, 0}]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The discrepancy arises inside the function `` Image`CompositionOperationsDump`imvQ `` in which the `ImageSize` option value for the graphics is extracted using:

```
rdims = Cases[i, rul_Rule /; First[rul] === ImageSize];
```

Since there is no explicit level specification in the `Cases` it defaults to `{1}` and therefore when the `ImageSize` option is at a deeper level (as in your `g3`) it doesn't get picked up.

It's not clear to me why the code uses `Cases` here, rather than `Options`, so I am not sure if this is a bug or a deliberate choice.

Comment: Thanks! Could you explain a little more about how you dig it out?

Comment: @xslittlegrass, I used my spelunking tool from [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1742/862).