# Why does adding 6.1 seconds display as having added 6.099?

Tags: units

Why does adding 6.1000000 seconds to a DateObject display as having added 6.099?

[image: Mathematica notebook picture]

If I copy the Out[20] element from this picture, it contains the correct value:

```
DateObject[{2014, 11, 7}, TimeObject[{8, 0, 6.1}], CalendarType -> "Gregorian"]
```

...but why does it display as 6.099 instead of 6.100?

More to the point, how can I make it display the correct answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the only 'fix' I could find.

Initialize the following:

```
$DateStringFormat = {"Year", "-", "Month", "-", "Day", "T", "Hour", ":", "Minute", ":", "SecondExact"};

System`DateStringDump`convertDateStringForms[{__, s_}, _, _, "Millisecond"] := 
  ToString[Floor[1000000 Round[FractionalPart[s], .00001]]]
```

Run your command:

```
DateObject[{2014, 11, 7, 8, 0, 0}] + Quantity[6.100000, "Second"]
```

[image]

Comment: Why not define a custom format: `System`DateStringDump`convertDateStringForms[{__, s_}, _, _,  "mysecpart"] :=  ToString[Floor[1000000 Round[FractionalPart[s], .00001]]]` and then `$DateStringFormat = {"Year", "-", "Month", "-", "Day", "T", "Hour", ":", "Minute", ":", "Second", ".", "mysecpart"}`.

Comment: Or do the seconds directly: `System`DateStringDump`convertDateStringForms[{__, s_}, _, _, "mysec"] := StringDrop[ToString@NumberForm[6.1, {8, 6}, NumberPadding -> {"0", "0"}], 1]`.  Not sure why *M* won't pad in the way everybody wants (i.e., `StringDrop` should be unnecessary).

Comment: Chip, I used `$DateStringFormat = {"Year", "-", "Month", "-", "Day", "T", "Hour", 
  ":", "Minute", ":", "SecondExact"}
System`DateStringDump`convertDateStringForms[{__, s_}, _, _, 
  "Millisecond"] := 
 ToString[Floor[1000000 Round[FractionalPart[s], .00001]]]
DateObject[{2014, 11, 7, 8, 0, 0}] + Quantity[6.100000, "Second"]
DateObject[{2014, 11, 7, 8, 0, 0}] + Quantity[6.0000101, "Second"]`, which worked great for the 6.100000 example, but it renders 6.0000101 as 6.10. ??

Comment: I was wrong in my previous comment. It's going to be easier to explain with a picture. What is the appropriate way for me to do that?

Answer (score 1):

This boils down to floating point error.

In binary, `0.1` does not have a finite decimal expansion, so your computer must round.

This is a problem at a hardware level and can only be fixed by setting a precision higher than machine precision.

Here is what the fractional part of your float really looks like:

```
FractionalPart[6.1] // FullForm
(* 0.09999999999999964` *)
```

Here is what the fractional part of a higher precision number looks like:

```
FractionalPart[6.1`20] // FullForm
(* 0.1`18.214670164989236 *)
```

(The number after the ` is the precision)

Comment: Chip, thank you very much. How can I make it render as ".1"; actually, I'd like it to render as ".100000". ...Another problem I have is that all my work is in microseconds.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer that, with @Chip's and @Michael's help, I came to:

```
$DateStringFormat = {"Year", "-", "Month", "-", "Day", " ", "Hour", ":", "Minute", ":", "Second", ".", "Foo"};
System`DateStringDump`convertDateStringForms[{__, s_}, _, _, "Foo"] := Module[{n = 6}, StringTake[ToString[PaddedForm[N[Round[s, 10^-n]], {30, n}]], -n]];
DateObject[{2014, 11, 7, 8, 0, 0}] + Quantity[6.100000, "Second"]
DateObject[{2014, 11, 7, 8, 0, 0}] + Quantity[6.0000107, "Second"]
DateObject[{2014, 11, 7, 8, 0, 0}] + Quantity[6.0000108, "Second"]
DateObject[{2014, 11, 7, 8, 0, 0}] + Quantity[6.12345671, "Second"]
DateObject[{2014, 11, 7, 8, 0, 0}] + Quantity[6.12345672, "Second"]
```

Still, two things bother me: (1) I can't find documentation about "DateStringDump" in the Mathematica documentation, or anywhere on Google! (2) Why does Round[_,10^-6] yield .0000107→.000010 and .0000108→.000011; and why .12345671→.123456 and .12345672→.123457? I see no pattern here. ...Maddening.

Comment: (1) There is a name for those sorts of commands: ["undocumented"](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=undocumented). :) (2) I get 0.0000107 → 0.000011.

Comment: @MichaelE2, understood on point 1, although I'm curious where someone learns of its existence. On point 2, I do too, when I use `PaddedForm[N[Round[{6.0000104, 6.0000105, 6.0000106, 6.0000107}, 10^-6]], {10,6}]` ...but not when I use the code shown above.

Comment: A few ways: ``?*`*key*`` etc., `foo = Trace[expr, TraceInternal -> True];` (loads of output consisting of evaluation chains, which takes some patience and strategy to find the important bit), [LinkSnooper](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=LinkSnooper), and some of the contributors here work at Wolfram and just know things.  There is also guessing, which works sometimes because *Mathematica* has a certain "style."  In fact, I guessed at my comment to Chip Hurst's answer, checked it out, and what do you know, it worked.

Comment: And I forgot this one: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1742/what-is-the-most-convenient-way-to-read-definitions-of-in-memory-symbols-when-we

Comment: @CaryMillsap It looks like there is rounding errors that I alluded to in one of my answers when adding the `DateObject` and the `Quantity`. One way around that is to do `DateObject[{2014, 11, 7, 8, 0, 6.0000107}]`.