# Why is TextString[-0.5] a positive number?

Tags: bugs, string-manipulation

**Bug introduced in 10.0 and fixed in 10.0.2**

---

I want to format numbers in decimal notation and chose `TextString` for this task. But today, when looking at the final result of my 3-weeks measurement, the sign seemed odd. I traced it to the following, unexpected behaviour of `TextString`:

```
TextString[1.0]
(*  1.0  *)

TextString[-1.0]
(* -1.0  *)

TextString[-0.5]
(* 0.5  UNEXPECTED *)
```

Using `Trace` gave a huge string of output that I am unable to interpret. Is `TextString` the wrong tool for this job?

Comment: Looks like a nasty bug, adding tag.  Please report it to WRI, and do mention your measurements and the consequences.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Not much to say here other than this is a nasty bug, but since you seemed to be curious what exactly goes wrong, here's the function that does the formatting:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This function breaks the number into integer and fractional parts, converts both to a string (as integers) and joins them with a decimal point.  The integer part of `-0.5` is `0` which is formatted as `0`, not as `-0`.

Comment: How exactly did you find this? All I could find is http://i.stack.imgur.com/1aHe9.png which is pretty horrible.

Comment: @Öskå Check this out: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/15948/12 (get the github version of the code)

Comment: Beat me to it. +1  Now are you going to fix it? :^)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard No, won't fix it.  I'm really annoyed by the recent decline in quality . When one has spare time, it might be fun digging up problems like this.  But when it affects our work directly, and wastes a lot of time, then it is horrible.  I can imagine that after an experience like Martin's (messing up his experimental results and wasting a lot of time) many people wouldn't touch Mma with a 10 foot pole.  It can't even format a number reliably!

Comment: @Szabolcs this will be fixed in 10.0.2. Very unfortunate bug, I apologize! Personally, most developers and testers I know wanted more time to iron out kinks like these, but we do not set the cadence of our release cycle.

Comment: @Taliesin Is there any constructive channel in which we might support the position of "most developers and testers"?  Will anyone listen?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard you can email tech support and express your opinion there, from time to time people do that.

Answer (score 4):

This has been fixed in Version 10.0.2. On windows:

```
 TextString[-0.5]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]