# Access properties in Mathematica

Tags: properties

This may seem a trivial question but I am coming to Mathematica from object oriented programming languages.

The results of many analyses are composite datatype. I want to access part of the result. For example:

```
dist = MixtureDistribution[{2, 1}, {NormalDistribution[], NormalDistribution[2, 1/2]}];
weights = dist.getWeights() -- result is {2,1}
```

Another example:

```
hmm = HiddenMarkovProcess[{0.5, 0.5}, {{0.7, 0.3}, {0.25, 0.75}}, {{0.2, 0.6, 0.2}, {0.4, 0.2, 0.4}}];
initial = hmm.getInitialProbabilities() -- result is {0.5,0.5}
transition = hmm.getTransitionProbabilities() -- result is {{0.7, 0.3}, {0.25, 0.75}}
```

I searched Mathematica Documentation and could not find a direct answer. In all the examples, the result is passed to other functions for further plotting/processing.

Comment: In the first case, for example, the weights are the first "argument" to the function `MixtureDistribution`, so you extract them by getting the first `Part`: `Part[dist, 1]`, `dist[[1]]` or `First[dist]`.

Comment: in mathematica you can make such defenition `weights /: dist[weights] := dist[[1]]` and now `dist[weights]` will return `{2,1}`

Comment: or even more convinient `dist[] = MixtureDistribution[{2, 1}, {NormalDistribution[], NormalDistribution[2, 1/2]}];` `dist["weights"] := dist[][[1]]`

Comment: If you are coming from OO programing  I would strongly encourage you to get familiar with the paradigm of functional programming for which Mathematica is well suited. Discussions on why OO is not encouraged, you find also on this forum

Comment: thank you all for your comments. I knew there is an easy answer to it. I am still confusing lists {} and "objects" []. Apparently the operator [[]] works for both. I am reading through the Wolfram Language Introduction to Programmers to get more familiar with it. It is available online http://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-programmers

Comment: Remember that the list notation `{1,2,3}` is just shorthand for `List[1,2,3]` so it is really no different from any other `head[args]` expression.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As people have said in the comments, [`Part`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html) is the simplest way to access parts of an expression. For example

```
hmm[[2]]
(* {{0.7, 0.3}, {0.25, 0.75}} *)
```

For accessing properties by name, the [`MarkovProcessProperties`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MarkovProcessProperties.html) function looks like the sort of thing you want, but it doesn't currently work for `HiddenMarkovProcess` - though there is some stuff in the internal code that suggests this will be implemented eventually.

In the meantime, you can access "properties" for `HiddenMarkovProcess` using the undocumented internal function `` RandomProcesses`HiddenMarkovProcessDump`hmmProperty `` - in the code below I assign a shorter symbol name to make it less unwieldy:

```
prop = RandomProcesses`HiddenMarkovProcessDump`hmmProperty;

prop[hmm, "InitialProbabilityVector"]
(* {0.5, 0.5} *)

prop[hmm, "TransitionMatrix"]
(* {{0.7, 0.3}, {0.25, 0.75}} *)
```

The complete list of accessible properties appears to be:

```
"ConditionalTransitionMatrix"
"EffectiveHMM"
"EffectiveTransitionMatrix"
"Emissions"
"InitialProbabilityVector"
"ProcessNParameterQ"
"ProcessParameterQ"
"SilentStates"
"StandardizedEmissions"
"TransitionMatrix"
```

Note that because this is an undocumented internal function, it is liable to change without warning in future versions.

Comment: Thanks. I am curious to know how you get to know about the undocumented function.

Comment: @HaniSafadi, I looked at the definition of `HiddenMarkovProcess` using [this tool](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/15948/862) and found it fairly quickly.