# ? (Definition) versus ?? (Information)

Tags: documentation, symbols, metadata

What is the difference between `?` [`Definition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Definition.html) and `??` [`Information`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Information.html)?

If I define two functions for the same symbol

```
f[x_] := Cos[x]
f[b_, c_] := Sin[b c]
```

I get the same result for `?f` and `??f`

> [image]

I've read the documentation, but it's not giving me a real sense of the difference. Are there different use cases? Can I always use one of these (`?` or `??`) and ignore the other?

ps. Which tags are appropriate for this question?

Comment: try [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/g1R4Q.png)

Comment: `?...` is the same as `Information[..., LongForm -> False]` and different from `Definition`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually, while the input escape `??` is shorthand for `Information`, **`?` is not a shorthand for `Definition`** (though `?` might use [`Definition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Definition.html)). Basically, if there is a usage message defined, `?` returns that, if not, it returns definitions. `Information` and `??` always return everything accessible. Compare:

```
In[25]:= f[x_] := Cos[x]
f[b_, c_] := Sin[b c]
f::usage = "blahblah";

Definition@f
```

> ```
>  f[x_] := Cos[x]
>
>  f[b_, c_] := Sin[b c]
> ```

```
?f (* prints usage message if exists, Definitions[f] otherwise *)
```

> ```
>   blahblah
> ```

```
Information@f (* same as ??f *)
```

> ```
> blahblah
>
> f[x_]:=Cos[x]
>
> f[b_,c_]:=Sin[b c]
> ```

According to the documentation under [**Document Constructs**](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/DocumentationConstructs.html):

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Of course, any definition is only printed if the symbol is not `ReadProtected`. `Information` itself is `ReadProtected`, hence only attributes and options are listed:

```
Definition@Information
```

> ```
> Attributes[Information] = {HoldAll, Protected, ReadProtected}
>
> Options[Information] = {LongForm -> True}
> ```

Compare the above to the extensive output produced by [`PrintDefinitions`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/78898/89), that delves deep into the symbol's definition (large output is omitted):

```
Needs["GeneralUtilities`"];
PrintDefinitions@Information
```

Furthermore, you can abuse the `?` operator to ask about multiple functions:

```
?*Chart
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]