# Custom graph distribution

Tags: graphs-and-networks, random, distributions

I am working with random graphs a lot. It's quite easy to describe random graph using, adjacency matrix or just a list of edges. However I am thinking that I might benefit from describing random graphs with something similar to graph distributions already presented in *Mathematica*.

Here is the question:

- how to implement a custom distribution?
- does it makes sense at all to do such a thing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**tl;dr** Currently, this part of Mathematica is not designed to be extensible.

---

A few months ago I looked into how `GraphPropertyDistribution` and related functions are implemented, and whether they are extensible.  As you may know, [there are some limited ways to read the definition of some built-in symbols](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1742/12).

My goal was to integrate [IGraph/M](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGraphM) with functions such as `RandomGraph`, `GraphPropertyDistribution`, etc.  I expected that at least automated *numerical* computation with graph property distribution may work, and I hoped that I would be able to add symbolic definitions for special cases.

What I found is this:

- There are internal checks on what is a proper graph distribution or graph property. Therefore it is not sufficient to add on extra definitions to top-level symbols.  It would be necessary to "register" new distributions/properties internally.
- Much of the internal implementation of this functionality is not only `ReadProtected`, but also `Locked` (and therefore unmodifiable).

Conclusion: I do not think it is worth bothering (or safe) to *extend* these symbols.

Instead, define your own functions for each sub-functionality that you need.  For example, IGraph/M has functions for *sampling* from certain random graph models (e.g. `IGDegreeSequenceGame`). These do *only sampling* and nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

With regard to custom distribution, see something about [`ProbabilityDistribution`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ProbabilityDistribution.html) in the documentation.

Here is an example of what can be done:

```
pd = ProbabilityDistribution[Sqrt[2]/Pi/(1 + x^4), {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]; 
Plot[PDF[pd, x], {x, -4, 4}, Filling -> Axis]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: The OP is talking about implementing custom distributions on graphs (e.g. `BernoulliGraphDistribution[]` or `PriceGraphDistribution[]`) and not probability distributions proper. I'm not sure why this has upvotes...