# Sow only if different from zero

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching

I am trying to collect elements with Reap and Sow, where I am interested only in non-zero elements, that is I am trying something like that

```
Flatten@Last@Reap@Do[
        Sow[Cases[{preThreeJSymbols[l1,m1,l2,m2,k]},Except[0]]],
        {l1,0,3},{m1,-3,3},{l2,0,3},{m2,-3,3},{k,0,6}]
```

where preThreeJSymbols is given by

```
preThreeJSymbols[l1_, m1_, l2_, m2_, k_] := 
 If[Abs[l1 - l2] <= k <= l1 + l2 && 
    Abs[m1 - m2] <= k && Abs[m1] <= l1 && 
    Abs[m2] <= l2,
    ThreeJSymbol[{l1, 0.}, {k, 0.}, {l2, 0.}]*
    ThreeJSymbol[{l1, -m1}, {k, m1 - m2}, {l2, m2}], 0]
```

I have two issues here:

First, is this the most efficient/natural way of doing it in *Mathematica*, I have the feeling that there will be a solution with pure functions (some condition/pattern matching?)
Secondly, in my case `preThreeJSymbols[l1,m1,l2,m2,k]` seems to return both `0` and `0.`. (I don't know why - I am confused here), which are interpreted differently by `Except[]`, hence not all zeroes are discarded.

Probably, I have to add that I do not want to use `Table`/`ParallelTable`, as in my application the ranges of `l1`, `m1`, `l2`, `m2` and `k` are much larger and the resulting table has more than 100 million elements, which makes it too big for my RAM to store. However, I know that most of the elements will be zero (around 5-6% are non-zero), so I want to go over all the elements and pick only the non-vanishing ones without actually generating a massive table.

Late Update

Created a new [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/86228/memory-usage-optimization-for-a-large-association-sparsearray) as per a suggestion

I have implemented Mr. Wizard's solution as

```
precomputeThreeJTable[Lmax_] := (Clear[precomputedSymbols]; 
precomputedSymbols = 
Reap[Do[preThreeJSymbols[l1, m1, l2, m2, k] // 
   If[# != 0, 
     Sow[{pairFunction[pairFunction[l1 + 1, m1 + Lmax + 1], 
        pairFunction[l2 + 1, pairFunction[m2 + Lmax + 1, k + 1]]],
        N[#]}]] &,
   {l1, 0, Lmax}, {m1, -Lmax, Lmax}, {l2, 0, Lmax}, {m2, Lmax, Lmax},
   {k, 0, 2 Lmax}]][[2, 1]]; 
threeJTable = 
AssociationThread[precomputedSymbols[[All, 1]], precomputedSymbols[[All, 2]]]; 
Export[StringInsert["somewhere", ToString[Lmax], -6], threeJTable, "WDX"];)
```

where `preThreeJSymbols` is as above and `pairFunction` is given by

```
pairFunction[x_, y_] := ((x + y) (x + y + 1))/2 + y
```

And I want to do this for `Lmax` around 45. At the moment I can manage only 30 - the reason being that *Mathematica* eats all my RAM. I have noticed that when I run `precomputeThreeJTable`, at the end of the calculation (when the `Association` is being created I assume) there is a massive spike in RAM usage, but after the command is evaluated the spike is gone and I can go on using `threeJTable` in other calculations with far less RAM being taken. This spike in RAM usage is also seen when I `Import` the exported file (the file is around 200mb). For `Lmax=35` my laptop can't take the memory spike.
My question is whether it is possible to avoid this somehow - maybe create (and later `Import`) the `Association` in pieces or something else?
I also tried using a `SparseArray` instead, replacing the `AssociationThread` code by

```
SparseArray[Table[precomputedSymbols[[i, 1]] -> precomputedSymbols[[i, 2]],
           {i, 1, Length[precomputedSymbols]}]]
```

The spkie is still there. Not only that but another problem comes up, due to `pairFunction`'s nature - it creates very huge integers pretty easily, which means that the dimension of the `SparseArray` will be enormous, so when I try using it in a calculation, even for `Lmax=3`, my *Mathematica* just resets (that is - clears all definitions - like when it runs out of memory). I can show the code for the way it is used, though it is a bit long. Is this expected behaviour or I am probably doing something wrong.

Thank you

Comment: Perhaps add the code for `f`?

Comment: Also, the code doesn't have correct opening/closing `{}` and `[]`. I guess this is correct: `Flatten@Last@Reap@Do[Sow[Cases[{f[x, y, z, w]}, Except[0]]], {x, 0, 5}, {y, 0, 5}, {z, 0, 5}, {w, 0, 5}]`

Comment: It looks to me like all zeroes disappear from your result? Can you explain further what you mean by "both `0` and `0`"?

Comment: Perhaps a simple `With[{el = preThre..}, If[el != 0, Sow[el]]` would be better.

Comment: Yep, that works fine! The zeroes were due to me putting in `0.` as an argument.

Comment: With respect to $3j$, if need be, you could try implementing the method [here](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0021-9991(89)90110-1).

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. Thank you very much for the paper, I will have a look at it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Inexact zeros

> `preThreeJSymbols[l1,m1,l2,m2,k]` seems to return both 0 and 0.

You introduced inexact arithmatic in the expression:

```
ThreeJSymbol[{l1, 0.}, {k, 0.}, {l2, 0.}]
```

You can either add [`Chop`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Chop.html) to your result or make these zeros exact:

```
ThreeJSymbol[{l1, 0}, {k, 0}, {l2, 0}]
```

However if you use `expr != 0` as Pickett recommended you do not need either.

#### Cases

You are using `Cases` on an expression with only one element when it is ostensibly intended to be used on lists of elements therefore other methods are likely to be faster.  Your use also results in sowing an empty list `{}` for every zero which actually takes *more* RAM:

```
ByteCount[0]
ByteCount[{}]
```

> ```
> 16
>
> 40
> ```

Try this instead:

```
Reap[Do[
  preThreeJSymbols[l1, m1, l2, m2, k] // If[# != 0, Sow[#]] &,
  {l1, 0, 3}, {m1, -3, 3}, {l2, 0, 3}, {m2, -3, 3}, {k, 0, 6}
]][[2, 1]]
```

#### Possible optimization

It seems that [`ThreeJSymbol`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ThreeJSymbol.html) is defined in top-level *Mathematica* code.  You may read its definition in version 10.1 with:

```
Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]

PrintDefinitions @ ThreeJSymbol
```

(See [What is the most convenient way to read definitions of in-memory symbols when we don't have the source files? (Spelunking tools)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1742/121) for other versions.)

If you can vectorize this code you may be able produce a significant performance improvement.

Comment: Your answer helped me quite a lot and I have been playing with various things since then and now I have a different issue, but I didn't know whether to create a new question or not, so I just edited my post

Comment: @user1482714 I think it is better to post a late update like this as a new question.  The update is about performance optimization of a specific piece of code rather than a general method, IMO.

Comment: I created a new [question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/86228/memory-usage-optimization-for-a-large-association-sparsearray) and updated this one as well with the link